# A simple TCP server

Tags: code-golf, internet, networking

Write a program or function that listens for incoming TCP traffic on port N. It offers a simple service: it calculates sum of IP address fields of incoming connection and returns.

Program or function reads integer N from arguments or stdin. It listens to incoming TCP connections on port N. When someone connects to that port, the program calculates sum of its IP address fields and sends it back to the client with trailing newline and closes connection.

- Port number N is a valid port, and 2<sup>10</sup> < N < 2<sup>15</sup>
- Trailing newline can be either `\n`or `\r\n`
- You can use either IPv4 or IPv6. Since IPv6 addresses are written in hexadecimal form, you must also provide result in same format, for example `2001:0db8:0000:0042:0000:8a2e:0370:7334 => 12ecd`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Standard rules and loopholes apply.

### Example

You run your server with `./server 1234`. The server is now running and waiting for connections on port 1234. Then a client from `127.0.0.1` connects to your server. Your server performs a simple calculation: `127+0+0+1 => 128` and sends the result to the client (with trailing newline): `128\n`. Then server closes connection and waits for next client.

### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=76379,OVERRIDE_USER=20569;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: Is it allowed to use inetd/xinetd or similar?

Comment: I like this, since it's a golfing challenge that golfing languages are unlikely to be very good at.

Comment: Not only is it amazing that a TCP server is apparently a very easy program to write, I am thoroughly floored at the fact that it's getting golfed for fun. I'll just go back to struggling with FizzBuzz like an imbecile.

Comment: @isaacg It's only time before someone finds the TCP server built-in in Mathematica

Comment: @MonkeyZeus To be fair, you will not see any *good* TCP server here. Making a reliable, scalable TCP server that handles all the intricacies of TCP (and your application protocol) well is a bit harder :D Though it certainly helps that the protocol is exceedingly simple - you don't even need to *read* the stream, something that I've seen broken in too many TCP servers to count :D

Answer (score 57):

## Bash + netcat + ss + …, <s>65</s> 60 characters

```bash
nc -lp$1 -c'ss src :'$1'|awk \$0=\$5|tr .: +#|bc'
exec $0 $1
```

Not a serious solution, was just curious about this possibility.

Thanks to:

- [ninjalj](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/267/ninjalj) for suggesting the `awk` based filtering (-5 characters)

Sample run:

(terminal 1)

```
bash-4.3$ ./ip-reduce.sh 8080
```

(terminal 2)

```
bash-4.3$ nc localhost 8080
128

bash-4.3$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
128
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

On Ubuntu you can get `nc` from [netcat-traditional](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/netcat-traditional) (no, netcat-openbsd is not good) and `ss` from [iproute2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/iproute2).

Comment: Why do you say it isn't a serious solution? As long as it works as expected I see no reason why it shouldn't be considered serious. It's also the shortest by a pretty significant margin at the moment.

Comment: The biggest concern against it appeared during [discussion with @JesseSielaff](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76379/a-simple-tcp-server/76391?noredirect=1#comment186086_76391) when I learned that on systems with configured IPv6, socket related information may be formatted differently. Have no such system to test it. For which I'm thinking whether would be more correct to turn it into CW.

Comment: My understanding of the spec is that you have to support IPv4 *or* IPv6, not both. So as long as it works for IPv4, not supporting IPv6 shouldn't matter, I would think.

Comment: @AlexA. At least I think my question says so. Should I clarify it?

Comment: @HannesKarppila, your question is clear. The possible issue is that my solution may require the operating system to be configured in a particular way to be able to run. So I'm worry because it may fail if IPv6 is configured, regardless whether I handle it or not. Someone who has IPv6 configured could tell it for sure…

Comment: `-c'ss src :'$1'|awk \$0=\$5|tr .: +#|bc'` instead of `-c"ss src :$1|sed -z 's/.* \b//;y/.:/+#/'|bc"` saves a few bytes.

Comment: What is the character cost of using `ss` if it has to be installed for this solution to work?

Comment: Nice way to discard `ss`'s header line, @ninjalj. I also tried `awk`, but with "manual" header discarding, which made it longer. Thank you.

Answer (score 25):

### Linux ELF/x86, 146 bytes

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46 01 00 00 00  5a 0e 00 00 5a 5e eb 10  |.ELF....Z...Z^..|
00000010  02 00 03 00 0c 50 eb 10  0c 50 eb 10 04 00 00 00  |.....P...P......|
00000020  5e 53 43 53 52 89 e1 b0  66 3d 20 00 01 00 cd 80  |^SCSR...f= .....|
00000030  97 55 6b ed 0a 01 c5 ac  2c 30 79 f6 43 0f cd 01  |.Uk.....,0y.C...|
00000040  dd 55 89 e1 6a 10 51 6a  10 51 57 89 e1 b0 66 cd  |.U..j.Qj.QW...f.|
00000050  80 43 43 b0 66 cd 80 01  64 24 08 89 e1 43 b0 66  |.CC.f...d$...C.f|
00000060  cd 80 89 c1 93 8d 74 24  1b 99 fd ac 01 c2 e2 fb  |......t$........|
00000070  89 f7 b0 0a aa 91 92 f6  f1 86 c4 04 30 aa 42 c1  |............0.B.|
00000080  e8 08 75 f3 42 89 f9 41  b0 04 cd 80 b0 06 cd 80  |..u.B..A........|
00000090  eb c9                                             |..|
00000092
```

Includes a 52-byte ELF header, a 32-byte program header, 111 bytes of program code + 3 bytes of code for skipping around inside the headers.

Information on how to create tiny ELF executables can be found at [breadbox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/4201/breadbox)'s *"[A Whirlwind Tutorial on Creating Really Teensy ELF Executables for Linux](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html)"*.

Linux/i386 uses the [`socketcall(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socketcall.2.html) multiplex system call, which takes in `ebx` the specific socket call (the `SYS_*` macros from `/usr/include/linux/net.h`), and in `ecx` a pointer to the argument area of the original library call.

Some things done to keep the executable small:

- It assumes registers are zeroed on entry, which Linux does, but is not required by the ELF standard (the only requirement is that on entry `EDX` points to a finalization funtion (useful for executables loaded by the dynamic linker) or is NULL).
- It assumes on launch (typically by a shell) the only open file descriptors are 0, 1, and 2. Which means that the listening socket will be fd 3, and the accepted socket will be fd 4.
- It assumes there are exactly 2 arguments (including `argv[0]`).
- The same stack space is reused for the calls to `bind(2)`, `listen(2)` and `accept(2)`.
- To skip over the `phentsize` and `phnum` fields, a byte is prepended, turning into a `CMP` operation which takes the `phentsize` and `phnum` fields as an immediate (trick shamelessly stolen from [breadbox's solution to 123 in anarchy golf](http://golf.shinh.org/reveal.rb?123/breadbox_1180162215&out)).
- x86 string operations `LODS` (load into accumulator and increment/decrement source index) and `STOS` (store from accumulator and increment/decrement destination index) are nice for short code.
- `XCHG EAX, reg` is 1-byte, compared to `MOV EAX, reg`, which takes 2 bytes.
- `CDQ/CLTD` (sign-extend `EAX` into `EDX:EAX`) can be used as a 1-byte way to zero the `EDX` register.
- `BSWAP` is useful for implementing `htons()`.

Nasm source:

```
BITS 32                                         ;
                                                ;   ELF HEADER    --   PROGRAM HEADER
; ELF HEADER                                    ; +-------------+
DB 0x7f,'E','L','F'                             ; | magic       |    +--------------------+
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
; PROGRAM HEADERS                               ; |             |    |                    |
DD 1                                            ; |*class   32b | -- | type: PT_LOAD      |
                                                ; |*data   none |    |                    |
                                                ; |*version   0 |    |                    |
                                                ; |*ABI    SysV |    |                    |
DD 0xe5a        ; offset = vaddr & (PAGE_SIZE-1); |*ABI vers    | -- | offset             |
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
entry:  pop     edx     ; edx = 2 (argc)        ; |*PADx7       | -- | vaddr = 0x10eb5e5a |
        pop     esi     ; discard argv[0]       ; |             |    |                    |
        jmp     short skip                      ; |             |    |                    |
DW 2                                            ; | ET_EXEC     | -- |*paddr LO           |
DW 3                                            ; | EM_386      | -- |*paddr HI           |
DD 0x10eb500c                                   ; |*version     | -- | filesz             |
DD 0x10eb500c                                   ; | entry point | -- | memsz              |
DD 4                                            ; | ph offset   | -- | flags: RX          |
                                                ; |             |    |                    |
skip:   pop     esi     ; esi = argv[1]         ; |*sh offset   | -- |*align              |
socket: push    ebx     ; default protocol (0)  ; |             |    |                    |
        inc     ebx                             ; |             |    |                    |
        push    ebx     ; SOCK_STREAM (1)       ; |             |    |                    |
        push    edx     ; AF_INET (2)           ; |*flags       |    +--------------------+
        mov     ecx, esp                        ; |             |
        mov     al, 0x66                        ; |*ehsize      |
DB 0x3d         ; cmp eax,0x10020               ; |             |
DW 32                                           ; | phentsize   |
DW 1                                            ; | phnum       |
                                                ; |             |
        int     0x80    ; socket(2, 1, 0)       ; |*shentsize   |
        xchg    edi, eax; edi = sockfd, eax = 0 ; |*shnum       |
        push    ebp     ; INADDR_ANY            ; |             |
                                                ; |             |
mult:   imul    ebp, 10 ; \_                    ; |*shstrndx    |
        add     ebp, eax; >                     ; |             |
        lodsb           ; >                     ; +-------------+
        sub     al,'0'  ; >
        jns     mult    ; / ebp = atoi(argv[1])                 ;       bind stack frame
                                                                ;    +-----------------------+
endmul: inc     ebx             ; SYS_BIND (2)                  ;    |        INADDR_ANY     |
                                                                ; +->| AF_INET | htons(port) |
        bswap   ebp                                             ; |  +-----------------------+
        add     ebp, ebx        ; AF_INET (2), htons(port)      ; |  |           16          |
        push    ebp                                             ; |  +-----------------------+
                                                                ; |  |         dummy         |
        mov     ecx, esp                                        ; |  +-----------------------+
        push    16              ; addrlen                       ; |  |           16          |
        push    ecx             ; dummy value                   ; |  +-----------------------+
        push    16              ; addrlen                       ; +--|          addr         |
        push    ecx             ; addr                          ;    +-----------------------+
        push    edi             ; sock                          ;    |         sockfd        |
        mov     ecx, esp                                        ;    +-----------------------+
        mov     al, 0x66
        int     0x80            ; bind(sockfd, addr, addrlen)
                                                                ;       accept stack frame
                                                                ;    +-----------------------+
listen: ;mov    byte [esp+8],1                                  ;    |        INADDR_ANY     |
        inc     ebx                                             ; +->| AF_INET | htons(port) |
        inc     ebx             ; SYS_LISTEN (4)                ; |  +-----------------------+
        mov     al, 0x66                                        ; |+>|           16          |
        int     0x80            ; listen(sockfd, backlog)       ; || +-----------------------+
                                                                ; || |         dummy         |
        add     [esp+8], esp                                    ; || +-----------------------+
accept: mov     ecx, esp                                        ; |+-|        &addrlen       |
        inc     ebx             ; SYS_ACCEPT (5)                ; |  +-----------------------+
        mov     al, 0x66                                        ; +--|          addr         |
        int     0x80            ; accept(sockfd, addr, &addrlen);    +-----------------------+
                                                                ;    |         sockfd        |
        mov     ecx, eax        ; ecx = 4                       ;    +-----------------------+
        xchg    ebx, eax        ; ebx = acceptfd, eax = 000000xx

        lea     esi, [esp+27]   ; point to the IP part of struct sockaddr_in
        cdq

        std                     ; reverse direction for string operations
addip:  lodsb                   ; \_
        add     edx, eax        ; > edx = sum of 4 IP bytes
        loop    addip           ; /

        mov     edi, esi        ; reuse struct sockaddr_in as scratch buffer
        mov     al, 10          ; '\n'
        stosb
        xchg    ecx, eax        ; ecx = 10
        xchg    eax, edx        ; edx = 0, eax = sum

divide: div     cl              ; \_
        xchg    al, ah          ; >
        add     al,0x30         ; >
        stosb                   ; > sprintf(scratch, "%d", sum)
        inc     edx             ; >
        shr     eax, 8          ; >
        jnz     divide          ; /

write:  inc     edx             ; ndigits + 1 ('\n')
        mov     ecx, edi
        inc     ecx
        mov     al,4
        int     0x80            ; write(acceptfd, scratch, scratchlen) 
close:  mov     al, 6
        int     0x80            ; close(acceptfd)
        jmp     accept
```

Comment: This answer is way underappreciated.

Answer (score 23):

## C#, <s>284</s> <s>283</s> <s>282</s> <s>278</s> <s>274</s> 254 bytes

```
class A{static int Main(string[]a){var b=new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(int.Parse(a[0]));b.Start();for(;;){var c=b.AcceptTcpClient();var d=c.Client.LocalEndPoint.Serialize();new System.IO.StreamWriter(c.GetStream()).WriteLine(d[4]+d[5]+d[6]+d[7]);}}}
```

Classic example of a basic C# TCP server. Testing:

**Terminal 1:**

```
$ ./Q76379.exe 1029
```

**Terminal 2:**

```
$ telnet localhost 1029
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
128
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**Firefox:**

[image]

Comment: You can save 1 Byte by using `int Main` instead of `void Main`. As the program never returns the compiler doesn't require a `return` statement.

Comment: And no, it doesn't leak. It's actually pretty deterministic about releasing resources as well. Also, the argument to `Start` is optional, saving another character.

Comment: @Luaan Yeah, that was left over from debugging.

Comment: Also, you could use `using` on the `TcpClient`, which will save you three more characters (use the `{}` from the `for`), and doing the same with the `StreamWriter` should save one more.

Comment: @Luaan I need to explicitly `Flush` the `StreamWriter` to make it work properly.

Comment: Actually, you don't if you use `using` - `Dispose` calls `Flush` on a `StreamWriter`. The same goes for `TcpClient` - `Dispose` calls `Close`, among other things.

Comment: @Luaan Have you tested this?

Comment: It works for me, though in cases like this, I usually find the code more reliable since the buffering isn't entirely predictable. Note that it also closes the underlying network stream, so you can actually omit the `using` around the `TcpClient` as well, saving six or seven more characters, if I'm counting right :)

Answer (score 16):

## NodeJS, <s>146</s> <s>134</s> 127 bytes

```
require('http').createServer((q,s)=>s.end(eval(0+q.socket.remoteAddress.replace(/^.*:|\./g,'+'))+'\n')).listen(process.argv[2])
```

I finally get to post a NodeJS answer! IPv4 only right now.

Sample execution: `node script.js 1024`. From another terminal:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:1024
128
```

Comment: I count 127 bytes right now, although you can get it down to 126 by swapping out `'\n'` with a template string containing a literal newline.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail the requirements because your creating a HTTP server , I mean, it's technically a TCP server, but couldn't you just use the TCP module and save yourself a character?

Answer (score 15):

## Tcl, 92

- 1 byte saved thanks to @DonalFellows.

```tcl
proc s {c a p} {puts $c [expr [string map .\ + $a]]
close $c}
socket -server s $argv
vwait f
```

Fairly self-explanatory:

`socket -server s $argv` creates a listening socket on the port specified in the arguments.

Every time a new connection arrives, the `proc s` is called, with channel, source-address and source-port as parameters.  `string map` substitutes `.` for `+` in the source address, and `expr` arithmetically evaluates the result, which is then `puts` back to the connection channel `c`.

`vwait` runs an event loop to catch the incoming connection events.

---

Credit to @DonalFellows for the following:

Here's a version that handles IPv6 (requires Tcl 8.6; most of the extra length is due to producing a hex response):

## Tcl, 109

```tcl
proc s {c a p} {puts $c [format %x [expr 0x[string map :\ +0x0 $a]]]
close $c}
socket -server s $argv
vwait f
```

Comment: Using `apply` doesn't seem to save anything. Nor can you use `tcl::mathop::+ {*}[split $a .]` as that's slightly longer. Nor can you shave anything from option names. But supporting IPv6 is pretty trivial to add, and only costs a few bytes of code more (and then a `regsub`-based approach is just as long).

Comment: ahhh, Tcl / Tcl-DP ... amazing bunch of tools. (in the '90s a professor showed us we could write a network-distributed Excel (with a grid, and including formulas evaluation!) shared among several persons with (iirc) 4 (short) lines for the server and 5 for the clients...

Comment: `proc s {c a p}` do you really need all that whitespace?

Answer (score 12):

## Groovy <strike>133</strike>, <strike>125</strike>, <strike>93</strike>, 89

```
new ServerSocket(args[0]as int).accept{it<<(it.inetAddress.address as int[]).sum()+"\n"}
```

IPv4 only, probably.

Ungolfed:

```
new ServerSocket(args[0]as int).accept{
    it << (it.inetAddress.address as int[]).sum()+"\n"
}
```

Testing:

```
$ telnet localhost 9000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
128
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: `.toInteger()` → `as int` and `s.inetAddress.address*.toInteger()` → `(s.inetAddress.address as int[])`. And there is an extra space after `.with`.

Comment: @manatwork thx! Updated.

Answer (score 10):

## Python 3, <strike>170</strike> <strike>166</strike> 147 bytes

```
from socket import*
s=socket()
s.bind(("",int(input())))
s.listen()
while 1:
 c,a=s.accept()
 c.send(b"%d\n"%eval(a[0].replace(".","+"))),c.close()
```

Takes port on `stdin`, IPv4 only. Works on GNU/Linux (and, I assume, most other unices), which automatically expands "" to "0.0.0.0", not sure about Windows though.

Comment: You could save several bytes. Firstly, spaces in `import *` and `, SOCK_STREAM` are unnecessary. Also, the send line could be written more efficiently as `c.send(b"%d\n"%eval(a[0].replace(".","+")))`.

Comment: @HannesKarppila oh, thanks. forgot about the spaces, the eval hack is pretty cool though.

Comment: AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM are just constants; AF_INET is 2 and SOCK_STREAM is 1. Also, as mentioned, SOCK_STREAM is unnecessary; so you can shorten that by instead using `s=socket(2)`.

Comment: can't you just do socket() and therefore save another byte?

Comment: Although unless i'm missing something, you need to pass something to s.listen()

Comment: @Foon as per `help(socket.listen)`, "If not specified, a default reasonable value is chosen." (for the `backlog` parameter)

Comment: Ahh... python3 changed that behavior; good to know (re: socket.listen)

Comment: You could save another 3 chars by using semicolons to concatenate all the indented statements and slapping them right on the end of `while 1:`.

Comment: You can save 10 characters by using Python 2. Then, `int(input())` becomes `input()` and the send part becomes ```c.send(`eval(a[0].replace(".","+"))`)```

Comment: Do you need the `close()` call?  The challenge didn't say the code had to behave nicely. :)

Answer (score 9):

## Java, <strike>371</strike> <strike>368</strike> <strike>350</strike> <strike>344</strike> <strike>333</strike> <strike>310</strike> <strike>295</strike> 282 bytes

### Golfed

```
import java.net.*;class A{public static void main(String[]n)throws Exception{ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(Integer.decode(n[0]));for(;;){try(Socket a=s.accept()){byte[]c=a.getInetAddress().getAddress();new java.io.PrintStream(a.getOutputStream()).println(c[0]+c[1]+c[2]+c[3]);}}}}
```

#### Ungolfed

```
import java.net.*;

class A {
    public static void main(String[] n) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(Integer.decode(n[0]));
        for (;;) {
            try (Socket a = s.accept()) {
                byte[] c = a.getInetAddress().getAddress();
                new java.io.PrintStream(a.getOutputStream()).println(c[0] + c[1] + c[2] + c[3]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
mallard@steamroller:~$ telnet localhost 8888
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
128
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Comment: Remove the `int k=` and replace the k with all the c things in `Integer.toString(k)`. To save a few bytes.

Comment: You can also drop the space after your square brackets.

Comment: Change `public class A` to `interface A` and change `Main` from `public static void` to `public void` -- it's shorter and does the same thing

Comment: Thanks for the tips. @tac The main method has to be static :-(

Comment: Javas byte pretty sure messes up the return value for 192.168.2.1 or similar adresses with a byte above 127.

Comment: @MatthewSmith oh, then you can change it to `static void` for interface -- I don't know Java, just that `interface` allows dropping a keyword

Comment: Change `interface` to `class` should gain few more byte

Comment: Could also get rid of `Integer.toString` and use cast trick `((int)c[0] + c[1] + c[2] + c[3])`

Comment: Actually it doesn't need a cast at all, it automagically gets turned into a string by the `+'\n'`.

Comment: Use `a.getOutputStream().write((c[0] + c[1] + c[2] + c[3]+"\n").getBytes());` instead of `new DataOutputStream(a.getOutputStream()).writeBytes(c[0] + c[1] + c[2] + c[3] + "\n")`

Comment: I made a new Java solution that account for the byte overflow problem

Comment: `Integer.valueOf` is shorter than `Integer.parseInt`. Or `Integer.decode` for one less byte.

Comment: Isn't `try(Socket a=...){}` shorter than `a.close();`? Requires Java 7, but can gain bytes.

Comment: @ogregoire Yes, it's 5 bytes shorter now.

Comment: Now, after those changes, you can probably remove the braces after the `for`-loop to gain 2 extra bytes.

Comment: Use `new java.io.DataOutputStream` instead of importing it. Also, `writeBytes(0+c[0]...` for correctness.

Comment: Also, if you really want to use a class from `java.io`, use `PrintStream::println`, which is shorter and allows you in turn to remove the `+"\n"`, but that doesn't beat Ortis' suggestion.

Comment: Hurrah, one byte shorter than C# now. Thanks @ogregoire

Comment: Replace `Integer.valueOf` with `Short.valueOf`.

Answer (score 8):

### PowerShell v2+, <s>303</s> <s>268</s> <s>257</s> 227 bytes

```
nal n new-object;($l=n Net.Sockets.TcpListener($args[0])).Start()
for(){($w=n IO.StreamWriter(($c=$l.AcceptTcpClient()).GetStream())).Write((([Net.IPEndPoint]$c.Client.RemoteEndPoint).Address-replace"\.",'+'|iex))
$w.Dispose()}
```

<sub>Saved 35 bytes thanks to [Matt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52023/matt) ... Saved another 11 bytes by aliasing `New-Object` and minor tweaks ... Saved 30 more bytes by implicitly using localhost rather than `any` IP address and corrected to account for continual usage as originally specified and I missed</sub>

Really similar to the [C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76380/42963), since it's .NET underlying both. We save a few bytes here over the C# answer by being able to leverage the returning functionality of PowerShell (surrounding our declaration/assignment in parens, and then immediately calling the . methods), but we lose an awful lot by needing to formulate the summation. The fact that we've got slightly shorter class names/calls is really why this answer is beating C#.

#### Explanation

We first create a `New-Alias` (with the `nal` alias) to save on re-typing `New-Object` later. The rest of the first line is setting up a TCP Listener. We pass the command-line `$args[0]` as the input for creating a new `System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener`, stored as `$l`. That object is encapsulated in parens and immediately called with `.Start()` to have it actively open the socket.

Entering an infinite `for` loop, we then set our listener `$l` to blocking with `AcceptTcpClient()` which will wait for a connection. A reference to that connection (once it's made) is stored in `$c`, encapsulated in parens, and immediately called `GetStream()` to get the datastream. That datastream is passed to a new `System.IO.StreamWriter` constructor, `$w`, so we can manipulate it. That constructor is itself encapsulated in parens and immediately called `Write(...)`.

Inside the `Write(...)` call, we take our client handle `$c` and obtain the client's `RemoteEndPoint` property. This is the only way (that I've found so far) to get the remote IP address. Next we need to re-cast that as a `[System.Net.IPEndPoint]` object so it's formatted correctly, encapsulate that in parens, and pull just the `.Address` property. We then `-replace` the literal periods with plus signs, then pipe it to `Invoke-Expression` (similar to `eval`) to obtain our summation.

After the IO write, we need to call `.Dispose()` to ensure the datastream is flushed to the client and closed. The TCP server drops the client connection without warning, so depending upon the client used it may hang for a while at this point. It then continues through the `for` loop without properly closing connections. This also means that it leaks memory and system handles like crazy, but we don't care about that, right? You may need to use Task Manager to kill the process when you're done running the server, though. :D

Also IPv4 only, as the summation barfs spectacularly trying to handle an IPv6 address, since `:` isn't a valid algebraic operator for `iex` to parse.

Comment: *"Leaks memory and system handles like crazy"* What, do you have to `free()` them after? `delete[]`, maybe? :P

Comment: @tac Yeah, there's a whole slew of `.close()` and `.dispose()` methods we're not calling here that would cause people on Code Review to have a fit.

Comment: Oh, isn't PS GC'd? Or does the GC do refcounting and not scope-analysis?

Comment: @tac Yes, PowerShell does have [garbage collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xy59wtx(v=vs.110).aspx) thanks to the underlying .NET system. But, depending on how you're calling or leveraging this script, you can run into bugs like [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/1599091/event-logging-memory-hoard-when-processing-a-large-number-of-pipeline-objects) leaking memory in the pipeline. The above code also isn't thread-safe, and so can run into GC issues with that, since we're not explicitly closing the socket.

Comment: In testing I could not get this to work, likely due to firewall issues that I don't feel like fixing so I cannot be sure but..... I think you can drop "System" from most if not all the type casts you have there ie: `[Net.ipaddress]::Any` works.

Comment: @Matt Indeed, thanks for that! I keep forgetting that the `System` can be implied.

Comment: @TimmyD, ive given you some competition :)

Comment: haha i love your turning the periods into plus signs and `iex`ing it, maybe that's smaller than my `measure`

Answer (score 7):

## [Go](https://golang.org/), <s>359</s> 311

This is my first program in Go - It allowed to let me discover one thing : This is definitively not a good golfing language!

(Kudos to @steve who did most of the golfing !)

```
package main
import(n"net";t"strings";r"strconv";x"regexp";"os")
func main(){l,_:=n.Listen("tcp",":"+os.Args[1])
for{c,_:=l.Accept();var s int
for _,i:=range t.Split(x.MustCompile(":[0-9]+$").ReplaceAllLiteralString(c.RemoteAddr().String(),""),"."){
n,_:=r.Atoi(i);s=s+n};c.Write([]byte(r.Itoa(s)));c.Close()}}
```

Comment: But it sure is a nice language for making a tcp server!

Comment: Odd, am getting the result 360 when I connect from 192.168.0.67, rather than 427.

Comment: You could name the strings+strconv packages to save a few bytes.  e.g. `"strings"` becomes `s "strings"` so that the later `strings.Split` becomes just `s.Split`.

Comment: Hmm, can you not use ":4444" in net.Listen?

Comment: @Riking why not ?

Comment: @steve I fixed the problem regarding the incorrect sum, thx

Comment: This doesn't take the listening port as input.

Comment: Dont forget to drop the unnecessary `fmt.Println(c.RemoteAddr().String())` line.  And to address the @TimmyD point, and avoid having to include 0.0.0.0, use `l,_:=n.Listen("tcp",":"+os.Args[1])`

Comment: ...and after then combining a few lines should give you http://pastebin.com/tMAYn6Y3     Nice work on your first go golf....

Comment: Few more bytes shaved off http://pastebin.com/HY84sazE - starting to look a bit more "golfed" now

Comment: If you use `import(."pkgname")` all functions will be imported to the current namespace, you can then drop the prefix. eg. `import ."fmt"; Println("foo")`

If you use `Sscanf` from the `fmt` package to parse the address instead of regex it'll save you another few bytes, giving you the nice bonus of having `Fprintln` for returning the total instead of importing `strconv`.

Answer (score 7):

### Common Lisp, 110 bytes

```lisp
(use-package'usocket)(lambda(p)(socket-server"localhost"p(lambda(u)(format u"~D~%"(reduce'+ *remote-host*)))))
```

### Details

```lisp
(use-package 'usocket)

(lambda (port)

  ;; create server with event-loop
  (socket-server "localhost"
                 port

                 ;; tcp-handler
                 (lambda (stream)
                   ;; format to stream to client
                   (format stream
                           "~D~%"
                           ;; add all elements of the host,
                           ;; a vector of 4 integers
                           (reduce #'+ *remote-host*))

                   ;; client connection is closed automatically
                   ;; when exiting this function                     
                 )))
```

Comment: Yay for Common Lithp!

Answer (score 7):

## PHP, 161 (56?)

This is my first post in here. I hope this goes right :)

```
<?php $s=socket_create_listen($argv[1]);while($c=socket_accept($s)){socket_getpeername($c,$r);socket_write($c,array_sum(explode('.',$r))."\n");socket_close($c);}
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
<?php 
    $s = socket_create_listen($argv[1]); //Create socket
    while( $c = socket_accept($s) ) { // Loop accepting new connections
        socket_getpeername($c, $r); // Get IP address in $r
        socket_write($c, array_sum(explode('.', $r))."\n"); //Calculate sum
        socket_close($c); //Close connection and wait for next one
    }
```

**Terminal:**

```
$ php test.php 8080 &
$ telnet localhost 8080
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
128
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This only works for IPV4

**Edit**:
I just noticed that php supports basic server:
I decided stick to original character count unless somebody confirms if following is allowed :)

test2.php: (possible 56-byte solution)

```
<?=array_sum(explode('.',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))."\n";
```

And then start service with:

```
php -S localhost:8080 test2.php
```

**Chrome as client**
[image: screenshot]

**Edit 2: wget as client**

```
$ wget -qO- localhost:8080
128
```

Comment: I know rules say: "Program or function reads integer N from arguments or stdin", but is it ok if program in this case is php itself? Or is using builtin server in php considered loophole?

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! Your 161-byte solution looks great. Is the 56-byte solution you mentioned the one under `test2.php`? If so, I think you'd have to ask the OP whether they'd consider that kind of built-in acceptable for this challenge. It isn't a loophole though.

Comment: I would say, using a builtin _TCP server_ would be acceptable, but in this case we talk about a builtin _HTTP server_. So the 56 byte solution 1) does nothing if the client only connects and sends nothing; 2) sends back only “[Wed Mar 30 10:15:02 2016] 127.0.0.1:47974 Invalid request (Malformed HTTP request)” without running test2.php in case the client sends for example “foo”; 3) sends full set of HTTP response headers before the actual required response in case the client sends valid HTTP request.

Comment: @Alex A. Thank you and yes, 56-byte solution is under test2.php :)

Comment: @manatwork You are correct but I was thinking that client is not clearly specified in this task. So is it ok to use browser or even more simplier something like "wget -qO- localhost:8080" as client?

Comment: @Mikael I think the 56-byte solution `test2.php` fails the basic description: "listens for incoming TCP traffic on port N," and requires an http client (`wget` or similar) not a simple TCP client (`telnet` or similar).

Answer (score 6):

## LiveScript, <s>107</s> 105 bytes

```
(require \http)createServer(->&1.end((.reduce (+))<|it.connection.remoteAddress/\.))listen process.argv.0
```

Nothing much to add, it's just basic NodeJS stuff. Style points for `&1` (second argument), `<|` (F# piping, akin to `$` in Haskell) and biop: `(+)` in LS is like operator sections in Haskell: a curried binary function (that adds its operands).
Also a bit dirty: `/`, if given a *literal* string on its right, will do split.

Answer (score 6):

## q, 88 bytes

```
system raze"p ",1_.z.x;.z.pg:{(string sum"i"$0x0 vs .z.a),"\n"};.z.ph:{.h.hy[`;.z.pg[]]}
```

- `system raze"p ",1_.z.x`: Takes the second command-line argument (the first `"-"` is for telling `q` not to interpret `N` as a script/file) and opens a port (`"p "`) with it.

  - Note: Calling `q -p N` sets the port as `N` automatically, but since the question seems to suggest that `N` should be an argument to the program rather than the executable itself, I've gone the longer way.
- Inside the `.z.pg` function that handles incoming requests, `.z.a` holds the IP address as a 32-bit integer.

  - `"i"$0x0 vs` splits it into its integer 'constituents', and `sum` does the summation.
  - Last, `string` the numeric result and append `"\n"` to it to return to the client.
- `.z.ph` is another function for HTTP GET requests, with extra handling to convert the string output into a valid HTTP response.

Demo - Server:

```
c:\q\w32>q - 1234
KDB+ 3.3 2015.11.03 Copyright (C) 1993-2015 Kx Systems
w32/ 4()core ... NONEXPIRE

Welcome to kdb+ 32bit edition
q)system raze"p ",1_.z.x;.z.pg:{(string sum"i"$0x0 vs .z.a),"\n"};.z.ph:{.h.hy[`;.z.pg[]]}
q)
```

Demo - Client (from another `q` session running on `127.0.0.1`):

```
q)(hopen `::1234)""
"128\n"
```

Demo - Client (from `curl`):

```
$ curl localhost:1234
128

$
```

Answer (score 6):

## 8086 machine code (16-bit DOS), <s>163 156 148 148</s> 142 bytes

```
00000000  31 c0 bb 0a 00 31 c9 be  81 00 bf 80 00 8a 0d 01  |1....1..........|
00000010  cf 46 8a 0c 80 e9 30 f7  e3 00 c8 39 fe 72 f2 89  |.F....0....9.r..|
00000020  c3 89 c1 b8 01 10 ba ff  ff 31 f6 31 ff cd 61 53  |.........1.1..aS|
00000030  b8 00 12 bf 80 00 b9 01  00 ba ff ff cd 61 b8 00  |.............a..|
00000040  14 cd 61 31 c0 bb 0a 00  83 c7 06 8d 4d 04 26 02  |..a1........M.&.|
00000050  05 80 d4 00 47 39 cf 72  f5 bf 84 00 b9 80 00 bb  |....G9.r........|
00000060  0a 00 4f 31 d2 f7 f3 80  c2 30 88 15 39 cf 77 f2  |..O1.....0..9.w.|
00000070  1e 07 b8 0e 13 5b bf 80  00 b9 04 00 ba ff ff cd  |.....[..........|
00000080  61 b8 00 11 ba 01 00 cd  61 b8 00 4c cd 21        |a.......a..L.!|
0000008e
```

Equivalent assembly code:

```
org 0x100
tcp equ 0x61    ; NTCPDRV interrupt

    xor ax,ax
    mov bx,10
    xor cx,cx
    mov si,0x81     ; [ds:81]-[ds:FF] = command line args
    mov di,0x80     ; [ds:80] = strlen(args)
    mov cl,[di]
    add di,cx

@@: inc si
    mov cl,[si]     ; get character
    sub cl,'0'      ; convert char to int
    mul bx          ; ax *= 10
    add al,cl
    cmp si,di
    jb @b
    ; now ax = port number

    mov bx,ax       ; source port (leaving this 0 doesn't work?)
    mov cx,ax       ; dest port
    mov ax,0x1001   ; open TCP socket for listening
    mov dx,-1       ; infinite timeout
    xor si,si       ; any dest IP
    xor di,di
    int tcp
    ; ^ I think this call should block until a connection is established, but apparently it doesn't.

    push bx         ; bx = socket handle, save it for later

    mov ax,0x1200   ; read from socket
    mov di,0x80     ; es:di = buffer (just reuse argument area to save space)
    mov cx,1        ; one byte
    mov dx,-1
    int tcp         ; this will block until a client connects and sends one byte

    mov ax,0x1400   ; get TCP session status, bx=handle
    int tcp
    ; now es:di points to a struct containing the source/dest IP addresses and ports
    ; the docs say it's two dwords for each IP address, then two bytes for "ip_prot" and "active" (whatever that means)
    ; ...but actually each IP address is followed by the port number (one word)

    xor ax,ax
    mov bx,10
    add di,6        ; [es:di+6] = client IP
    lea cx,[di+4]
@@: add al,[es:di]  ; add all bytes together
    adc ah,0
    inc di
    cmp di,cx
    jb @b
    ; now ax contains the IP address sum

    mov di,0x84     ; recycle arguments area again
    mov cx,0x80
    mov bx,10
@@: dec di
    xor dx,dx
    div bx          ; dl = ax mod 10
    add dl,'0'      ; convert int to char
    mov [di],dl
    cmp di,cx
    ja @b
    ; now [ds:80]-[ds:83] contains an ascii representation of the IP address sum

    push ds
    pop es
    mov ax,0x130e   ; send data with newline, wait for ack
    pop bx          ; socket handle
    mov di,0x80     ; es:di = data
    mov cx,4        ; sizeof data
    mov dx,-1
    int tcp

    mov ax,0x1100   ; close TCP socket
    mov dx,1
    int tcp

    mov ax,0x4c00
    int 0x21
```

This assumes [`ntcpdrv`](http://www.pld.ttu.ee/~priidu/library/net/ntcpdrv.zip) is loaded at `INT 0x61` (and any suitable packet driver at `0x60`). Compile with `fasm tcpserv.asm`.

It has some issues though:

- It doesn't check if the argument is a valid port number, or if it's even a number at all.
- The client must send at least one byte, since I can't seem to find any other way to tell if a client has connected.
- It only works once, and hangs on a second attempt. Works again after a reboot.
- The returned value is left-padded with zeroes.
- This is my very first code golf entry, and also my very first 8086 asm program. I'm sure there are ways to improve this further.

Comment: You can just post a hexdump of the compiled output for 148 bytes

Comment: Is that allowed? It would make this entry a bit more competitive...

Comment: If it's an executable program (on some system) that meets the spec, then yes! Binary-format golf is allowed, just not often seen because modern platforms have a lot of boilerplate for executable formats.

Comment: Alright, I've changed the entry to machine code. Also shaved a few more bytes off by using `xor r,r` instead of `mov r,0`.

Comment: Newlines are one byte, unless that code won't compile without `\r\n` newlines?

Comment: I wrote it on a dos machine where newlines are `CR LF`, so I just went with that. Either way it's kinda pointless to count the asm size now, might as well clean it up a bit and add some comments.

Comment: `source port (leaving this 0 doesn't work?)` On UNIX, giving a port of `0` lets the kernel randomly assign a port, then returns the new port number. I guess DOS doesn't have that functionality

Comment: That's supposed to happen here too, and it does work; `int 0x61` returns a random local port in `ax`. But it also changes the listening IP to some garbage number (`4.2.0.0` iirc)

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>141</s> 132 + 1 = 133 bytes

### Golfed

```
$s=new IO::Socket::INET LocalPort=><>,Listen=>5,Reuse=>1;{$c=$s->accept;$_=$c->peerhost;y/./+/;$c->send(eval.$/);shutdown $c,1;redo}
```

### Ungolfed

```
# listen on tcp port obtained from stdin
$s=new IO::Socket::INET(LocalPort=> <>,
                        Listen   => 5,
                        Reuse    => 1);

{
    # accept connection
    $c=$s->accept();
    
    # get the ip address
    $_=$c->peerhost();

    # replace dots with plus
    y/./+/;

    # send the evaluated version back, with a newline
    $c->send(eval . $/);

    # close
    shutdown($c,1);

    redo;
}
```

### Example

```
$ echo 7777|perl -MIO::Socket::INET -e'$s=new IO::Socket::INET LocalPort=><>,Listen=>5,Reuse=>1;{$c=$s->accept;$_=$c->peerhost;y/./+/;$c->send(eval.$/);shutdown $c,1;redo}'

$ telnet 127.0.0.1 7777
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
128
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? I get the sum printed in the server's terminal, not the client's. Anyway, you can remove all parenthesis and change `s/\./+/g` → `y/./+/`.

Comment: Ahh, misread..will revise accordingly and incorporate your good y/ suggestion.

Comment: `while(1){…}` → `{…;redo}` according to [user130144](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17183/user130144)'s great [tip](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/22412). And excepting the `->send()` call, all other parenthesis are unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

## NodeJS (ES6), <s>129</s> <s>118</s> 107 bytes

```js
require('net').createServer(c=>c.end(eval(c.remoteAddress.replace(/\./g,'+'))+`
`)).listen(process.argv[2])
```

Works for IPv4. Run as `node server.js <port>`

Comment: Actually doesn't work if the server's using IPv6 (as, for instance, mine does automatically), since `c.remoteAddress` would then be `::ffff:127.0.0.1`. (I tested on Node v5.9.1).

Comment: Also, you don't have a trailing newline, which should increase your score by 2 bytes.

Comment: @Frxstrem Whoops, forgot that newline. Only adds 1 byte though thanks to template strings. Regarding IP family: `.listen()` used to default to IPv4 first, but it seems either by bug or design that this has changed. The submission will still function properly on newer versions of node when IPv6 is disabled on the host machine.

Answer (score 4):

### PowerShell, <strike>208</strike> <strike>206</strike> <strike>192</strike> 152 bytes

```
($t=[net.sockets.tcplistener]$args[0]).start();for(){($z=$t.acceptsocket()).sen‌d([char[]]"$($z.remoteendpoint.address-replace"\.","+"|iex)");$z.close()}
```

version information:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      4.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.3.9600.17400
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Thanks to TimmyD for saving me 14 bytes!

Massive thanks to TessellatingHeckler for saving me 40 bytes

Comment: @TimmyD ah oops I missed that that was necessary... fixed now

Comment: One of the ways programs are allowed to take input is from stdin. i suppose this particular question doesn't specify that as allowed but it's a general code-golf thing that i think should count for PowerShell. It's unfortunately different from bash in that it doesn't wait for input on stdin if none has been provided.

Comment: fair enough. fixed again

Comment: Alrighty, now for some golfs -- try the following at 192 -- `($t=new-object net.sockets.tcplistener($args[0])).start();for(){($z=$t.acceptsocket()).send(($x=[byte[]][char[]](""+($z.remoteendpoint.address-replace"\.","+"|iex))+32),$x.count,0);$z.close()}`

Comment: damn didnt see that `Send` method with one argument, that changes everything!

Comment: feels like cheating taking your `-replace "\.","+"` but thanks

Comment: Oh wait no I read it wrong, it is just using the fact that assignment operations return their value. I never think to use that.

Comment: I think you can knock this down to 152 - drop new-object and cast directly, skip the byte array conversion and do a string cast differently, don't store $x at all and drop the remaining parameters to send(), and it becomes `($t=[net.sockets.tcplistener]$args[0]).start();for(){($z=$t.acceptsocket()).send([char[]]"$($z.remoteendpoint.address-replace"\.","+"|iex)");$z.close()}` - which I've only tested quickly with netcat connecting, but it seems to work the same - connecting from localhost anyway.

Comment: Well that is interesting... I wonder how that type conversion works, does powershell automatically do that with constructors? I feel like ive tested that in the past and it didnt work. I'll take it though thanks

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 180 bytes

```
from SocketServer import*
TCPServer(('',input()),type('',(BaseRequestHandler,set),{'handle':lambda s:s.request.send(`eval(s.client_address[0].replace('.','+'))`)})).serve_forever()
```

Takes the port over stdin.

Answer (score 4):

### Go, 211 bytes

```
package main
import(."fmt"
."net"
"os")
func main(){s,_:=Listen("tcp4",":"+os.Args[1])
for{c,_:=s.Accept()
var a,b,d,e int
Sscanf(Sprint(c.RemoteAddr()),"%d.%d.%d.%d",&a,&b,&d,&e)
Fprintln(c,a+b+d+e)
c.Close()}}
```

Can probably be golfed further, I'm not entirely satisfied with the way I have to parse the IP adress for instance, it looks like a horrible hack.

Listens on IPv4 on the port given as argument.

Answer (score 4):

### C, 535 bytes

Well, someone had to do this.

I added a single line break so the posted code actually has 536 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int c,char**v){int f,l;char b[99];struct sockaddr_in d,e;f=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);bzero(&d,sizeof(d));d.sin_family=AF_INET;d.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;d.sin_port=htons(atoi(v[1]));bind(f,&d, sizeof(d));listen(f,5);l=sizeof(e);
f=accept(f,&e,&l);bzero(b,99);int p,q,r,s;char g[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];inet_ntop(AF_INET,&(e.sin_addr),g,INET_ADDRSTRLEN);sscanf(g,"%d.%d.%d.%d",&p,&q,&r,&s);sprintf(b,"%d\n",p+q+r+s);write(f,b,strlen(b));return 0;}
```

compile with `gcc [file_name] -o server`

run with `./server [port]`

connect with `telnet localhost [port]`

Comment: Nice answer! [As mentioned before](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/76379/a-simple-tcp-server/76778#comment186103_76383), you could save a few bytes by using actual values for some constants, such as AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM.

Answer (score 3):

## Mumps, <s>114</s> 115 Bytes

Golfed:

```
R P F{S J=0,I="|TCP|1" O I:(:P) U I R K F K=1:1:4{S J=J+$P(##class(%SYSTEM.TCPDevice).PeerAddr(),".",K)} W J,! C I}
```

Ungolfed:

```
R P             ; Read Port # from STDIN ;
  F{            ; Loop over everything;
  S J=0,        ; Initial IP segment total
  I="|TCP|1"    ; TCP device
  O I:(:P)      ; Open the TCP device, port from input {and sticking a tongue out! :-) }
  U I           ; Use the TCP device
  R K           ; Read from STDIN (anything)
  F K=1:1:4{    ; Iterate 1->4 in variable K
    S J=J+      ; Accumulate the following segments of the IP in var. J
    $P(##class(%SYSTEM.TCPDevice).PeerAddr(),".",K) ; Grab each piece of IPv4.
            }   ; close the loop.
  W J,!         ; Write the total w/newline out the TCP port 
  C I           ; close the TCP port to send.
}               ; end final loop
```

This is the InterSystems Caché version of Mumps - if there's a version out there that can acquire the TCP address shorter than `##class(%SYSTEM.TCPDevice).PeerAddr()` *(as it's almost a 1/3 of the entire program)* it might have a better chance against some of the other languages posted already... ;-)

Edit: Thanks to @TimmyD - I missed the reading of the port from STDIN or arguments instead of being hardcoded. Edited; it added 1 byte to the program.

Comment: @TimmyD - Ah, you're correct. Missed that on reading through the requirements. Will edit posthaste.

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 216 bytes

Using the "network-simple" package (`cabal install network-simple`).  Needs a couple of language extensions (`-XOverloadedStrings -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`) to work.

```
import Network.Simple.TCP(serve)
import Network.Socket
import Data.Bits
main=getLine>>= \n->serve"*"n p
p(s,(SockAddrInet _ h))=()<$(send s$(show$sum$w h 24)++"\n")
m=255
w h 0=[h.&.m]
w h n=h`shiftR`n.&.m:(w h$n-8)
```

There are a couple of possible simplifications, including changing the `w` function to return the sum directly rather than a list, and using a function rather than a program so that the port number can be specified as an argument. I don't imagine this would reduce the size very much, though.  20 bytes perhaps?

Comment: Nice! Pretty sure you can still shave a few bytes off by renaming `w` to `#`, so `w h n` becomes `h#n` for a savings of 2 bytes per usage.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <strike>243</strike> 188 bytes (or perhaps <strike>217</strike> 162 bytes)

V2: see below for the explanations.

188 bytes:

```
s;main(g,v)char**v;{short S[8]={2,htons(atoi(v[1]))};char C[g=16];bind(s=socket(2,1,0),&S,g);for(listen(s,8);g=fdopen(accept(s,&C,&g),"w");fclose(g))fprintf(g,"%d\n",C[4]+C[5]+C[6]+C[7]);}
```

Slightly circumspect 162 bytes:

```
s;main(g){short S[8]={2,g};char C[g=16];bind(s=socket(2,1,0),&S,g);for(listen(s,8);g=fdopen(accept(s,&C,&g),"w");fclose(g))fprintf(g,"%d\n",C[4]+C[5]+C[6]+C[7]);}
```

Probably more golfing possible tomorrow morning. I'll tidy this post up after those updates.

---

V1:

This one was really quite fun to golf.

```
#include<netdb.h>
s,c,q;main(g,v)char**v;{struct sockaddr_in S={2,htons(atoi(v[1]))},C;bind(s=socket(2,1,0),&S,g=16);for(listen(s,8);c=accept(s,&C,&g);q=fclose(g)){for(g=4;g;q+=C.sin_addr.s_addr>>8*--g&255);fprintf(g=fdopen(c,"w"),"%d\n",q);}}
```

It works for IPv4. Mostly it's a straightforward implementation. The three main components are

Creating the socket:

```
struct sockaddr_in S={2,htons(atoi(v[1]))},C;bind(s=socket(2,1,0),&S,g=16);
```

We use the various explicit forms of the constants AF_INET etc, and make use of the fact that when a struct is initialised in C in this way the non-specified elements are set to zero.

Listen for clients, accept them, and close their connections:

```
for(listen(s,8);c=accept(s,&C,&g);q=fclose(g))
```

Finally to send each client the data:

```
for(g=4;g;q+=C.sin_addr.s_addr>>8*--g&255);fprintf(g=fdopen(c,"w"),"%d\n",q);
```

The IP is stored in `C.sin_addr.s_addr` as a 32 bit integer where each octet is represented by one of the four bytes. We sum these bytes with the for loop and then print them to the stream using fprintf.

I have a shorter 217 byte solution but I'm not entirely sure it doesn't violate the standard loopholes since it requires that the port is given in unary in network byte order as command line arguments. That is, to run the server on port 12345 one would need to call

```
$ ./tcp 1 1 1 1 ... 1 1 1
```

where the total number of `1`s is 14640. To say the least it's a little... cumbersome. But here it is anyway:

```
#include<netdb.h>
s,c,q;main(g){struct sockaddr_in S={2,g},C;bind(s=socket(2,1,0),&S,g=16);for(listen(s,8);c=accept(s,&C,&g);q=fclose(g)){for(g=4;g;q+=C.sin_addr.s_addr>>8*--g&255);fprintf(g=fdopen(c,"w"),"%d\n",q);}}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>283</s> 275 bytes

**Golfed**

```
import java.net.*;class A{public static void main(String[] n)throws Exception{ServerSocket s=new ServerSocket(Integer.valueOf(n[0]));for(;;)try(Socket a=s.accept()){int v=0;for(byte b:a.getInetAddress().getAddress())v+=b&255;a.getOutputStream().write((v+"\n").getBytes());}}}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
import java.net.*;

class A {
public static void main(String[] n) throws Exception {
    ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(Integer.valueOf(n[0]));
    for (;;)
        try (Socket a = s.accept()) {
            int v = 0;
            for (byte b : a.getInetAddress().getAddress())
                v += b & 255;
            a.getOutputStream().write((v + "\n").getBytes());
        }
}
}
```

**Edit:** Down to 274 thanks to @ogregoire

Comment: Much more elegant than mine.

Comment: Use `255` instead of `0xff`. Otherwise, same remarks as Matthew's answer.

Comment: This isn't C. Java's main method is supposed to return `void`.

Comment: @dorukayhan indeed. Don't why I used `int`. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 210 bytes

Golfed:

```
p->{java.net.ServerSocket x=new java.net.ServerSocket(p);for(;;){try(java.net.Socket s=x.accept()){byte[]b=s.getInetAddress().getAddress();s.getOutputStream().write((0+b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+b[3]+"\n").getBytes());}}};
```

Expanded:

```
@FunctionalInterface interface Consumer { // Define an interface that allows a function that throws an exception.
  void accept(int port) throws Exception;
}

Consumer consumer = (port) -> {
  java.net.ServerSocket serverSocket = new java.net.ServerSocket(port);
    for (;;) {
      try (java.net.Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()) {
        byte[] bytes = socket.getInetAddress().getAddress();
        socket.getOutputStream().write((0 + b[0] + b[1] + b[2] + b[3] + "\n").getBytes());
      }
    }
}
```

This a gathering of all the tips I gave in other Java answers, plus the writing as a function instead of a full program, which gains roughly 70 bytes compared to the program.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, <del>169</del> <del>162</del> <del>160</del> <del>153</del> <del>151</del> <del>148</del> <del>138</del> 129 bytes

**Golfed version**

```
m=require"socket".bind(0,...)::l::c=m:accept()f=0 for n in c:getpeername():gmatch"%d+"do f=f+n end c:send(f.."\n")c:close()goto l
```

It requires Luasocket to be installed and an interpreter that supports labels. I've tested it with Luajit and I can also confirm that the code does not work with Lua 5.1.

**Ungolfed version**

```
m=require"socket".bind(0,...)
::l::
c=m:accept()

f=0
for n in c:getpeername():gmatch"%d+" do
    f=f+n
end
c:send(f.."\n")

c:close()
goto l
```

**Edit 1:**

Changed `i=({c:getpeername()})[1]` to just `i=c:getpeername()`

**Edit 2:**

Removed braces from the require statement.

**Edit 3:**

Removed the braces around the vararg, decreased the byte count a little bit.

**Edit 4:**

Removed the parenthesis around "%d+", shorter by 2 bytes.

**Edit 5:**

Removed the unnecessary variable i.

**Edit 6:**

Changed the ip from "127.0.0.1" to 0. (Thanks to xyzzy on #lua)

**Edit 7:**

Removed the function call to tonumber since strings are cast to numbers automatically (Thanks to Trebuchette for the suggestion, I did not know this)

Comment: Only Lua 5.2 and up support labels, if you're curious

Comment: Also, Lua automatically casts strings to numbers with the `+` operator, so you can take out `tonumber`.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 326 bytes

```
import Data.Bits
import Network.Socket
import System.IO
f n=withSocketsDo$do
 s<-socket AF_INET Stream defaultProtocol
 bind s$SockAddrInet n iNADDR_ANY
 listen s 1
 g s
g s=do
 (z,SockAddrInet _ a)<-accept s
 h<-socketToHandle z WriteMode
 hPutStrLn h$show$b a
 hClose h
 g s
b 0=0
b x=x.&.0xFF+b(x`shiftR`8)
```

Sadly I had to use `Network.Socket` to get access to the remote IP address as an integer rather than a string. It would have saved dozens of characters if I could just do `s <- listenOn (PortNumber n)`, rather than having to explicitly call `socket`, `bind` and `listen` individually. But, sadly, `Network.accept` gives me a host *string*, not an IP address *integer*, so I had to resort to `Network.Socket.accept` and friends.

The function `f` takes a port number as argument, and creates a server socket (`s`) listening on that port. It then calls the function `g` with the server socket. `g` loops forever, accepting connections. The function `b` takes an actual IPv4 address and computes the sum of its digits.

I'm sure somebody somewhere can do this better than me. I wanted to show off just how damned easy socket stuff is in Haskell... but then failed miserably, because I need access to the IP address, which isn't usually easy to get.

Comment: The "network-simple" package provides a much nicer interface which passes the SockAddr to a function you give it, which makes things easier.  See my solution which I'm about to post...

Comment: A few simplifications are apparent: (1) I believe `withSocketsDo` is only necessary on Windows, so if running on Linux it can be ignored; (2) 0xFF is a character longer than 255; (3) converting the socket to a handle and using regular IO is a lot longer than using `Network.Socket.send`.  Yes, `send` is deprecated, but the reason is not relevant to this scenario (it only relates to non-ASCII text or binary data), so it seems reasonable to use it.

Comment: `Network.accept gives me a host string, not an IP address integer` Can't you just split the IP string on the `"."`, `map` Haskell's string-to-number function over the split string and sum the results?

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 185 (+ 19 = 204)? bytes

```
import Network.Simple.TCP(serve)
import Network.Socket
import Data.List.Split
main=getLine>>=flip(serve"*4")(\(a,b)->()<$(send a$(++"\n")$show$sum.map read.take 4.sepByOneOf":."$show b)
```

Takes port number as one line on stdin; requires `network-simple` from Cabal.

As usual with Haskell answers that don't constrain themselves to pure functions, the `imports` take up far too many bytes. The trailing newline is also worth 9 bytes...

Somewhat similar to @Jules's answer, but I use string manipulation instead of byte operations. I <s>stole</s> used the `-XOverloadedStrings` extension as well, which is probably worth 19 bytes extra.

Answer (score 2):

## Factor, <s>155</s> <s>146</s> <s>131</s> <s>206</s> 190 bytes

Well, I just learned a lot about low-level socket programming. I don't think I ever wanna do that again, because my <s>thr</s>head hurts.

```
[ utf8 <threaded-server> readln 10 base> >>insecure [ remote-address get host>> "." split [ 10 base> ] map sum 10 >base print flush ] >>handler [ start-server ] in-thread start-server drop ]
```

Oh yeah, threaded, and doesn't return, right.

Comment: Can you use `10 base>` instead of `string>number`?

Comment: @fedes. Wow, I never knew that existed. I think that will allow me to shorten a lot of my Factor answers!

Comment: And `10 >base` for number>string, also.

Comment: @fedes. Those deserve an answer [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75610/tips-for-golfing-in-factor) :D

Answer (score 2):

## Racket, 265 bytes

```
#lang racket(define l(tcp-listen(string->number(read-line))))(let e()(define-values(i o)(tcp-accept l))(thread(λ()(define-values(a b)(tcp-addresses o))(write(~a(foldl + 0(map string->number(string-split a".")))o))(newline o)(close-output-port o)))(e)))
```

Ungolfed:

```
#lang racket
(define listener (tcp-listen (string->number (read-line))))
(define (mk-server)
  (let echo-server ()
    (define-values (in out) (tcp-accept listener))
    (thread
     (λ()
       (define-values (a b) (tcp-addresses out))
       (write (number->string (foldl + 0(map string->number(string-split a "."))) out))
       (write "\n" out)
       (close-output-port out)))
    (echo-server)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab, <strike>128</strike> 139 Bytes

Listens on port n, Ipv4 only (even if it listens on IPv6 too).

```
function m(n);while 1;t=tcpip('0.0.0.0',n,'NetworkRole','server');fopen(t);fprintf(t,'%d\n',sum(sscanf(t.RemoteHost,'%d.')));fclose(t);end
```

Comment: This doesn't take the listening port as input.

Answer (score 1):

## k (55 characters)

This is essentially a translation of @h.j.k. [solution in q](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/76393/1556) with a couple of modifications.

```
."\\p ",*.z.x
.z.pg:{$+/0x0\:.z.a}
.z.ph:.h.hy[`].z.pg@
```

Usage: `q filename.k PORT`

Answer (score 1):

## [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/), <s>308</s> <s>293</s> <s>281</s> <s>278</s> <s>275</s> <s>274</s> <s>272</s> <s>270</s> 264 bytes

```
Func K($n)
TCPStartup()
$A=TCPListen("127.0.0.1",$n)
Do
$B=TCPAccept($A)
Until $B>0
While 1
$C=TCPRecv($B,$n)
If $C Then
$e=StringInStr($C,"st:")+4
$d=stringsplit(StringMid($C,$e,StringInStr($C,":")-$e),".")
ConsoleWrite($d[1]+$d[2]+$d[3]+$d[4])
EndIf
WEnd
EndFunc
```

[Script-Example.com](http://www.script-example.com/themen/AutoIT-Online-Compiler.php) has an online compiler.

Reusing the port variable ($n) in the [TCPRecv](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/TCPRecv.htm) max-length parameter. Since it is never going to be less than 1024, it's saving me a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 185 bytes

```
use std::{io::*,net::*};|a|while let Ok((mut a,SocketAddr::V6(b)))=TcpListener::bind(("::",a)).unwrap().accept(){write!(a,"{:x}
",b.ip().segments().map(|a|a as _).iter().sum::<u32>());}
```

This is a closure of type `fn(u16)`. It accepts IPv6 connections and formats its output in hexadecimal. Golfing in Rust can be pretty challenging due to the number of transformations allowed by the compiler. Rust 1.55.0 or higher is necessary to compile this program.

Answer (score 0):

## [LispyScript](http://lispyscript.com), 196 bytes

```
(->(require"http")(.createServer(function(q r)(r.end((str(-> (r.socket.remoteAddress)(.split".")(.map parseFloat)(.reduce (function(x y)(+ x y)))))'\n')(.listen(get 2 process.argv)"127.0.0.1"))))
```

If it looks like one of the Node submissions above, that's because it's pretty much just Node with  a prettier face.

Ungolfed:

```
(->
  (require "http")
  (.createServer
    (function (request response)
      (response.writeHead 200 {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
      (response.end
        (str (-> (request.socket.remoteAddress)
             (.split ".")
             (.map parseFloat)
             (.reduce (function (x y) (+ x y)))))
          '\n')
  (.listen (|| (get 2 process.argv) 1337) "127.0.0.1"))))
```

Two functions, two method chains.

Answer (score 0):

## NodeJS, (IPv4 and IPv6) 105 Bytes

```
require("net").createServer(s=>s.end(eval(s.remoteAddress.replace(/[:.]/g,"+"))).listen(process.argv[2])
```

Explanation:

```
require("net")               # TCP library
 .createServer(              # Create the server
   s=>                       # Socket is s
    s.end(                   # Print and end the connection
     eval(                   # Treat the following string like JavaScript
      s.remoteAddress        # The IP address (IPv4 or IPv6, depending on connection)
       .replace(/.|:/g, "+") # Replace all . and : with +
 )))                         # Close server response
 .listen(process.argv[2])    # Listen on the third index of the arg array (["node", "filename.js", "first arg"])
```

Comment: There is a missing parenthesis in the original code (not in the explanation)

Answer (score 0):

### Common LIsp (Lispworks), 564 bytes

```
(require "comm")(defun make-stream-and-talk(handle)(let((stream(make-instance 'comm:socket-stream :socket handle :direction :io :element-type 'base-char)))(mp:process-run-function(format nil "" handle) '() 'f stream)))(defun f(stream)(unwind-protect(progn(multiple-value-bind(address port)(comm:socket-stream-address stream)(declare(ignore port))(format stream "~S"(reduce #'+(mapcar #'parse-integer(split-sequence "."(comm:ip-address-string address)))))(force-output stream))(close stream))))(comm:start-up-server :function 'make-stream-and-talk :service 10246)
```

ungolfed:

```
    (require "comm")
    (defun make-stream-and-talk (handle)
      (let ((stream (make-instance 'comm:socket-stream
                                   :socket handle
                                   :direction :io
                                   :element-type
                                   'base-char)))
        (mp:process-run-function (format nil ""
                                         handle)
                                 '()
                                 'f stream)))

    (defun f (stream)
      (unwind-protect
          (progn
            (multiple-value-bind (address port)
                (comm:socket-stream-address stream)
              (declare (ignore port))
              (format stream "~S" 
                      (reduce #'+
                              (mapcar #'parse-integer
                                      (split-sequence "."
                                                      (comm:ip-address-string address)))))
              (force-output stream))
            (close stream))))

    (comm:start-up-server :function 'make-stream-and-talk
                          :service 10246)
```

Usange:

```
    c:\~]$ telnet 127.0.0.1 10246


    Connecting to 127.0.0.1:10246...
    Connection established.
    To escape to local shell, press 'Ctrl+Alt+]'.
    you sent: 128
    Connection closed by foreign host.

    Disconnected from remote host(127.0.0.1:10246) at 23:42:56.

    Type `help' to learn how to use Xshell prompt.
```

Note:

```
reference Lispworks documents
```

Answer (score 0):

## Object Pascal, <s>342</s> 340 bytes

A small (well the pascal definition of small...) server with the lowest level Sockets library. Listenes to IP4, port no. on the commandline.

```
uses sockets;var s,c,l,i,f:integer;a,b:TInetSockAddr;g:string;begin val(ParamStr(1),f,i);s:=fpSocket(2,1,0);a.sin_family:=2;a.sin_port:=ntobe(f);l:=sizeof(a);fpBind(s,@a,l);repeat fpListen(s,1);c:=fpaccept(s,@b,@l);f:=0;for i:=1to 4do f:=f+b.sin_addr.s_bytes[i];Str(f,g);g:=g+#10;fpsend(c,@g[1],length(g),0);fpshutdown(c,2);until False;end.
```

Ungolfed:

```
uses
  sockets;
var
  s, c, l, i, f: integer;
  a, b: TInetSockAddr;        { a=server, b=client }
  g: string;
begin
  val(ParamStr(1), f, i);     { store port no. in f }
  s := fpSocket(2, 1, 0);     { 2=AF_INET, 1=SOCK_STREAM, 0=PF_UNSPEC }
  a.sin_family := 2;          { 2=AF_INET }
  a.sin_port := ntobe(f);     { port to listen to, address initialized to localhost by default }
  l := sizeof(a);
  fpBind(s, @a, l);           { bind socket to address:port }
  repeat
    fpListen(s ,1);           { listen for one incoming connection }
    c := fpaccept(s, @b, @l); { accept connection, client address in b }
    f := 0;
    for i:=1 to 4 do
      f := f+b.sin_addr.s_bytes[i]; { add 4 bytes of client address }
    Str(f, g);                      { store f in a string }
    g := g+#10;                     { add newline }
    fpsend(c, @g[1], length(g), 0); { send the addition result }
    fpshutdown(c, 2);               { close the connection }
  until False;
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Racket, 174 bytes

```rkt
(do([l(tcp-listen 1234)])(#f)(let*-values([(i o)(tcp-accept l)][(a b)(tcp-addresses i)])(displayln(for/sum([s(string-split b".")])(string->number s))o)(close-output-port o)))
```

### Ungolfed

```
(do ([l (tcp-listen 1234)])
    (#f)
  (let*-values ([(i o) (tcp-accept l)]
                [(a b) (tcp-addresses i)])
    (displayln
     (for/sum ([s (string-split b ".")])
       (string->number s))
     o)
    (close-output-port o)))
```

Shoutout to cat for bringing the Racket competition!