# Shortest code to throw SIGILL

Tags: code-golf

## Background

We already have a challenge [about throwing SIGSEGV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-return-sigsegv), so why not a challenge about throwing SIGILL?

## What is SIGILL?

SIGILL is the signal for an illegal instruction at the processor, which happens very rarely. The default action after receiving SIGILL is terminating the program and writing a core dump. The signal ID of SIGILL is 4. You encounter SIGILL very rarely, and I have absolutely no idea how to generate it in your code except via `sudo kill -s 4 <pid>`.

## Rules

You will have root in your programs, but if you don't want to for any reasons,  you may also use a normal user. I'm on a Linux computer with German locale and I do not know the English text which is displayed after catching SIGILL, but I think it's something like 'Illegal instruction'. The shortest program which throws SIGILL wins.

Comment: You might want to clarify whether the instruction has to be generated by the kernel or not. In particular, do you want to allow the program just generating it directly using the libc call `raise(SIGILL)`?

Comment: It really does say `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

Comment: @ais523 Everything is allowed.

Comment: For any hardware that can raise SIGILL, the answer will be the same as the instruction length. Just put an illegal instruction somewhere and try to execute it. The only interesting thing will be the convoluted toolchain involved.

Comment: @CarstenS Uh. Yes, of course I mean that.

Comment: Now please explain me why I have even more votes then the SIGSEGV question? XD

Comment: *\*people posting old programs they had that didn't work\**

Comment: Sometimes I look for the brainfuck entry, just to marvel at how it lives up to its name.   Honestly I was expecting someone would have come up with a negative-length brainfuck submission, just cos.

Comment: @Criggie where is the brainfuck entry? I don’t see it.

Comment: @BenjaminWang there isn't one here, yet.  That language really does deserve it's name.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

## PDP-11 Assembler (UNIX Sixth Edition), 1 byte

```
9
```

Instruction 9 is not a valid instruction on the PDP-11 (in octal, it would be `000011`, which does not appear on [the list of instructions](http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/%7Eajr/258/pdp11.pdf) (PDF)). The PDP-11 assembler that ships with UNIX Sixth Edition apparently echoes everything it doesn't understand into the file directly; in this case, 9 is a number, so it generates a literal instruction 9. It also has the odd property (unusual in assembly languages nowadays) that files start running from the start, so we don't need any declarations to make the program work.

You can test out the program using [this emulator](http://pdp11.aiju.de/), although you'll have to fight with it somewhat to input the program.

Here's how things end up once you've figured out how to use the filesystem, the editor, the terminal, and similar things that you thought you already knew how to use:

```
% a.out
Illegal instruction -- Core dumped
```

I've confirmed with the documentation that this is a genuine `SIGILL` signal (and it even had the same signal number, 4, all the way back then!)

Comment: It had the same signal number because POSIX and UNIX and the SUS are closely related :)

Comment: Almost all of the signal numbers in V6 still have the same meanings today; the mnemonics have actually been less stable than the numbers.  Compare http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V6/usr/sys/param.h with https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/sys/sys/signal.h — identical semantics for 1 through 13, but  only 1, 2, and 13 have exactly the same names.  (SIGALRM/14 and SIGTERM/15 were only added in V7.)  (The System V lineage has a couple of changes, notably moving SIGBUS from 10 to 7 (replacing the useless SIGEMT) and SIGSYS above 15, to make room for SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2.)

Comment: @cat POSIX and SUS don't actually specify the values of signals - they do specify the meaning of some numbers when passed as arguments to the kill command, but SIGILL is not included.

Comment: @Random832: For the record: [this is where POSIX documents the required name->number mappings for the `kill` command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/kill.html).  Wikipedia copied that into a table at the [end of this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#POSIX_signals).  I'm not sure if anything prevents the `kill` shell command from remapping the numbers itself to make `kill -9` work even if SIGKILL is actually a different number in the C API, but that would be really silly (like Deathstation 9000 kind of behaviour).

Comment: I'm not convinced that a.out has one byte in it.  Therefore this is not a compete assembler program, just one line of an assembler program that achieves the result.  The byte count of your whole program is the byte count of a.out.

Comment: `a.out` has multiple bytes in it, indeed (the `9` instruction compiles to two bytes, and the assembler also adds a header and footer to make the program executable). That's why I wrote the program in assembly language, not in machine code. The assembly language program has only one byte in, and compiles to a program with more bytes in; this is a [tag:code-golf] problem (minimize the size of the source), not a sizecoding problem (minimize the size of the executable), so it's the 1-byte size of the source that matters.

Comment: Very clever abuse of an old but awesome system.

Answer (score 90):

## C (x86_64, [tcc](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/tinycc)), 7 bytes

```c
main=6;
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100540/12012).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9YtSU7@/z83MTPP1sz6/38A)

#### How it works

The generated assembly looks like this.

```asm
    .globl  main
main:
    .long 6
```

Note that TCC doesn't place the defined "function" in a *data* segment.

After compilation, *_start* will point to *main* as usual. When the resulting program is executed, it expects code in *main* and finds the little-endian(!) 32-bit integer **6**, which is encoded as **0x06 0x00 0x00 0x00**. The first byte – **0x06** – is an invalid opcode, so the program terminates with *SIGILL*.

---

## C (x86_64, [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/)), 13 bytes

```c
const main=6;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z85P6@4RCE3MTPP1sz6/38A)

#### How it works

Without the *const* modifier, the generated assembly looks like this.

```asm
    .globl  main
    .data
main:
    .long   6
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

GCC's linker treats the last line as a hint that the generated object does not require an executable stack. Since *main* is explicitly placed in a *data* section, the opcode it contains isn't executable, so the program terminates will *SIGSEGV* (segmentation fault).

Removing either the second or the last line will make the generated executable work as intended. The last line could be ignored with the compiler flag `-zexecstack` ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTPP1sz6//9/yWk5ienF/3WrUitSk4tLEpOzAQ)), but this costs **12 bytes**.

A shorter alternative is to declare *main* with the *const* modifier, resulting in the following assembly.

```asm
        .globl  main
        .section    .rodata
main:
        .long   6
        .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

This works without any compiler flags. Note that `main=6;` would write the defined "function" in *data*, but the *const* modifier makes GCC write it in *rodata* instead, which (at least on my platform) is allowed to contain code.

Comment: Love the complete avoidance of even using a function :) How does this work in C terms, though? Does the compiler see that `main` is a 6 and try to call it (which I guess would make it give up and try the instruction)?

Comment: @JackDobson it's undefined behavior, so it doesn't work in terms of C; you're at the compiler's mercy. Clang even has a warning for this for some reason: "variable named 'main' with external linkage has undefined behavior".

Comment: GCC will complain about `main` not being a function but only if you turn on the warnings (either `-Wall` or `-pedantic` will do it).

Comment: I think it's pretty standard for executables for Unix-like systems to have text/data/bss *segments*.  The linker places the `.rodata` *section* inside the text segment of the executable, and I expect this will be the case on pretty much any platform.  (The kernel's program-loader only cares about segments, not sections).

Comment: Also note that `06` is only an invalid instruction in x86-64.  In 32-bit mode, it's [`PUSH ES`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PUSH.html), so this answer only works with compilers that default to `-m64`.  See http://ref.x86asm.net/coder.html#x06.  The only byte sequence that's guaranteed to decode as an illegal instruction on all future x86 CPUs is the 2 byte [UD2](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/UD2.html): `0F 0B`.  Anything else could be some future prefix or instruction-encoding.  Still, upvoted for a cool way to get a C compiler to stick a `main` label on some bytes!

Comment: Huh, that's weird that `-z execstack` also controls the `.data` section.  I checked with x86-64 gcc7.1.1 on Arch Linux, and you're right that that `@progbits` directive makes the data section non-executable, and that `-z execstack` overrides it, and that the default (with no directive and no option) is an executable `.data` section.  I guess `execstack` is more like executability for non-`text` segments in general.

Answer (score 47):

## Swift, 5 bytes

```
[][0]
```

Access index 0 of an empty array.  This calls `fatalError()`, which prints an error message and crashes with a SIGILL.  [You can try it here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/5831ec1d892718588ddb0ddb).

Comment: This is one of the trickier ones ;)

Comment: ...why on earth does it crash with a SIGILL? Who thought that was an appropriate signal? Bloody hipsters :D

Comment: they don't "choose" that signal, it's probably just that the language is stupid enough to have this possibly cause a SIGILL.

Comment: @Asu No; `fatalError()` intentionally crashes by running `ud2`.  Why they chose to do that I do not know, but maybe they thought the error message "Illegal instruction" made sense because the program did something illegal.

Comment: Brilliant.  I would bet this is also the shortest Swift code to cause a crash.

Comment: @JAL Yeah; I can't think of anything shorter.  I tried `nil!`, but the compiler couldn't infer the result type.  (Also, hi JAL!)

Comment: @NobodyNada then, wow, that *really* doesn't make sense, heh.

Comment: @Muzer @Asu The reason that `fatalError()` causes a SIGILL is because it's meant to be the equivalent of Clang & GCC's `__builtin_trap()` intrinsic which also executes an illegal instruction on most platforms.

Answer (score 28):

## GNU C, 25 bytes

```
main(){__builtin_trap();}
```

GNU C (a specific dialect of C with extensions) contains an instruction to crash the program intentionally. The exact implementation varies from version to version, but often the developers make an attempt to implement the crash as cheaply as possible, which normally involves the use of an illegal instruction.

The specific version I used to test is `gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0`; however, this program causes a SIGILL on a fairly wide range of platfoms, and thus is fairly portable. Additionally, it does it via actually executing an illegal instruction. Here's the assembly code that the above compiles into with default optimization settings:

```
main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    ud2
```

`ud2` is an instruction that Intel guarantees will always remain undefined.

Comment: −6: `main(){asm("ud2");}`

Comment: Also, I don't know how we count bytes for raw assembly, but `00 00 0f 0b` is the machine language for `ud2`…

Comment: @wchargin: that's an x86 + GNU C answer.  This one is portable to all GNU systems.  Also note that [UD2 is only 2 bytes](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/UD2.html).  IDK where you got those `00` bytes; they're not part of the machine code for UD2.  BTW, as [I commented on Dennis's answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/shortest-code-to-throw-sigill#comment244196_100557), there are one-byte illegal instructions in x86-64 for now, but they're not guaranteed to stay that way.

Comment: @wchargin: We count bytes for machine-code functions / programs like you'd expect.  See some of my answers, like [Adler32 in 32 bytes of x86-64 machine code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78896/compute-the-adler-32-checksum/78972#78972), or [GCD in 8 bytes of x86-32 machine code](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77270/greatest-common-divisor/77364#77364).

Comment: @PeterCordes why would `00 00` be illegal in x86-64? It's still, as it was in x86, mere `add [eax],al`, which is perfectly legal.

Comment: @Ruslan: They aren't; `00 00` decodes the same in x86-64 (as `add [rax], al`).  `00 00 0f 0b` would usually SIGSEGV before SIGILL, unless you happened to have a writeable pointer in `rax`.

Comment: @PeterCordes ah, I've misread your comment. You didn't actually claim that `00` is a one-byte illegal instruction as I had read it.

Answer (score 25):

## C (x86_64), 11, 30, 34, or 34+15 = 49 bytes

```
main[]="/";
```

```
c=6;main(){((void(*)())&c)();}
```

```
main(){int c=6;((void(*)())&c)();}
```

I've submitted a couple of solutions that use library functions to throw `SIGILL` via various means, but arguably that's cheating, in that the library function solves the problem. Here's a range of solutions that use no library functions, and make varying assumptions about where the operating system is willing to let you execute non-executable code. (The constants here are chosen for x86_64, but you could change them to get working solutions for most other processors that have illegal instructions.)

`06` is the lowest-numbered byte of machine code that does not correspond to a defined instruction on an x86_64 processor. So all we have to do is execute it. (Alternatively, `2F` is also undefined, and corresponds to a single printable ASCII character.) Neither of these are guaranteed to always be undefined, but they aren't defined as of today.

The first program here executes `2F` from the read-only data segment. Most linkers aren't capable of producing a working jump from `.text` to `.rodata` (or their OS's equivalent) as it's not something that would ever be useful in a correctly segmented program; I haven't found an operating system on which this works yet. You'd also have to allow for the fact that many compilers want the string in question to be a wide string, which would require an additional `L`; I'm assuming that any operating system that this works on has a fairly outdated view of things, and thus is building for a pre-C94 standard by default. It's possible that there's nowhere this program works, but it's also possible that there's somewhere this program works, and thus I'm listing it in this collection of more-dubious-to-less-dubious potential answers. (After I posted this answer, Dennis also mentioned the possibility `main[]={6}` in chat, which is the same length, and which doesn't run into problems with character width, and even hinted at the potential for `main=6`; I can't reasonably claim these answers as mine, as I didn't think of them myself.)

The second program here executes `06` from the read-write data segment. On most operating systems this will cause a segmentation fault, because writable data segments are considered to be a bad design flaw that makes exploits likely. This hasn't always been the case, though, so it probably works on a sufficiently old version of Linux, but I can't easily test it.

The third program executes `06` from the stack. Again, this causes a segmentation fault nowadays, because the stack is normally classified as nonwritable for security reasons. The linker documentation I've seen heavily implies that it used to be legal to execute from the stack (unlike the preceding two cases, doing so is occasionally useful), so although I can't test it, I'm pretty sure there's some version of Linux (and probably other operating systems) on which this works.

Finally, if you give `-Wl,-z,execstack` (15 byte penalty) to `gcc` (if using GNU `ld` as part of the backend), it will explicitly turn off executable stack protection, allowing the third program to work and give an illegal operation signal as expected. I *have* tested and verified this 49-byte version to work. (Dennis mentions in chat that this option apparently works with `main=6`, which would give a score of 6+15. I'm pretty surprised that this works, given that the 6 blatantly isn't on the stack; the link option apparently does more than its name suggests.)

Comment: On x86-64/linux with gcc6 in its default (lenient) mode, `const main=6;` works, as do several variations. This linker (which I suspect is also your linker) *is* capable of generating a jump from `.text` to `.rodata`; the problem you were having is that, without `const`, you're jumping into the *writable* data segment (`.data`), which is not executable on modern hardware.  It would have worked on older x86, where the memory protection hardware could not mark pages as readable-but-not-executable.

Comment: Note that even in C89, `main` is required to be a function (§5.1.2.2.1) -- I don't know why gcc considers declaring `main` as a data object to only deserve a warning, and only with `-pedantic` on the command line. Someone back in the early 1990s perhaps thought that nobody would do that by accident, but it's not like it's a useful thing to do on purpose except for this sort of game.

Comment: ... Rereading again, it seems you expected `main[]="/"` to jump to the read-only data segment, because string literals go in rodata. You've been caught out by the difference between `char *foo = "..."` and `char foo[] = "..."`. `char *foo = "..."` is syntactic sugar for `const char __inaccessible1[] = "..."; char *foo = (char *)&__inaccessible1[0];`, so the string literal does go in rodata, and `foo` is a *separate*, writable global variable that points to it.  With `char foo[] = "..."`, however, the entire array goes in the writable data segment.

Answer (score 22):

### Bash on Raspbian on QEMU, 4 (1?) bytes

Not my work.  I merely report the work of another.  I'm not even in a position to test the claim.  Since a crucial part of this challenge seems to be finding an environment where this signal will be raised and caught, I'm not including the size of QEMU, Raspbian, or bash.

On Feb 27, 2013 8:49 pm, user [emlhalac](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=59462&sid=0e95d50056c1d75daa9a3183a3596b4e) reported "[Getting 'illegal instruction' when trying to chroot](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=298537)" on the Raspberry Pi fora.

```
ping
```

producing

```
qemu: uncaught target signal 4 (Illegal instruction) - core dumped
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I imagine much shorter commands will produce this output, for instance, `tr`.

EDIT:  Based on [@fluffy's comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/shortest-code-to-throw-sigill/100628#comment244372_100628), reduced the conjectured lower bound on input length to "1?".

Comment: I'd think the `[` command would win. :)

Answer (score 22):

## GNU as (x86_64), 3 bytes

```
ud2
```

---

$ xxd sigill.S

```
00000000: 7564 32                                  ud2
```

$ as --64 sigill.S -o sigill.o ; ld -S sigill.o -o sigill

```
sigill.S: Assembler messages:
sigill.S: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400078
```

$ ./sigill

```
Illegal instruction
```

$ objdump -d sigill

```
sigill:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400078 <__bss_start-0x200002>:>
  400078:       0f 0b                   ud2
```

Comment: There must be a way to express that in a two-byte "source"...

Comment: Oh, clever. I was wondering if there was a way to build this which would put the entry point at the start of the file (with no declarations) and which wouldn't incur penalties for an unusual build system configuration. I couldn't find one, but it looks like you did.

Comment: @ais523: yeah, [my usual NASM / YASM build-script (`asm-link`)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861903/assembling-32-bit-binaries-on-a-64-bit-system-gnu-toolchain/36901649#36901649) for single-file toy programs would build an executable from this source the same way, since `ld` defaults the entry point to the start of the text segment or something like that.  I just didn't think of going for asm source size on this one :P

Answer (score 19):

## x86 MS-DOS COM file, 2 bytes

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, DOS itself will not trap the CPU exception and will simply hang (not just the app, the entire OS). Running on a 32-bit NT-based OS such as Windows XP will, indeed, trigger an illegal instruction signal.

```
0F 0B
```

From the [documentation](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_318.html):

> Generates an invalid opcode. This instruction is provided for software testing to explicitly generate an invalid opcode.

Which is pretty self-explanatory. Save as a .com file, and <strike>run in any DOS emulator</strike> DOS emulators will just crash. Run on Windows XP, Vista, or 7 32-bit.

[image: SIGILL on Windows XP]

Comment: Does it really generate anything like exception or signal? One emulator I have access to just hangs; which one did you use?

Comment: It technically does cause the processor to generate an illegal instruction exception. However, DOS has very limited memory protection and exception handling capabilities, and I wouldn't be surprised if it just lead to undefined behavior / OS crash. The OP didn't say the kernel had to catch the error and print "Illegal Instruction" to the console.

Comment: I thought of this solution, but I don't believe it's valid. The question requires an illegal instruction *signal*, not just an illegal instruction *processor trap*, so the aim was to find an operating system which would actually generate a signal in response to the `#UD` trap. (Also, I decided to actually test it, and it appeared to throw my DOS emulator into an infinite loop.)

Comment: I tested this on actual MS-DOS on an AMD K6-II.  Running it just hangs the system, both with and without EMM386 running.  (EMM386 traps some errors and halts the system with a message, so it was worth testing to see if it made a difference.)

Comment: Awesome, some people still have actual MS-DOS systems! I'm stuck with an emulator :( . I do kind of agree with ais523, this is not actually a *signal*, it just triggers an interrupt and passes control to the operating system, which emits the actual signal. If the OS doesn't have a way to handle this situation, it will most likely just crash (which may not count as a solution).

Comment: Try it on Windows 98 or similar?

Comment: Yes, DOS-based windows should be able to really catch the trap and at least crash the app.

Comment: @Asu I can confirm that this works on XP 32-bit, and will probably work on all other 32-bit Windows systems. I agree that this isn't a solution on DOS itself, as it just crashes.

Comment: OK, now you've found an OS where it produces a genuine signal, I'm happy with the answer. I should really have thought of that myself… (Instructions like 6 won't work for a crash in this situation because it's running a different instruction set from the x86_64 solutions, but you might be able to get this down to one byte by finding a single-byte instruction that isn't in the instruction set used for DOS programs.)

Comment: The `lock` prefix (0xF0) generates `#UD` in front of most instructions (that is, everything that isn't an atomic read-modify-write on a memory destination). Given that program memory is loaded in pages, there will be more to read after `lock`, and a 0xF0 byte is almost guaranteed to generate `#UD`. But only almost, so not a solution.
Haven't found anything else yet.

Answer (score 14):

## C (32-bit Windows), 34 bytes

```
f(i){(&i)[-1]-=9;}main(){f(2831);}
```

This only works if compiling without optimizations (else, the illegal code in the `f` function is "optimized out").

Disassembly of the `main` function looks like this:

```
68 0f 0b 00 00    push 0b0f
e8 a1 d3 ff ff    call _f
...
```

We can see that it uses a `push` instruction with a literal value `0b0f` (little-endian, so its bytes are swapped). The `call` instruction pushes a return address (of the `...` instruction), which is situated on the stack near the parameter of the function. By using a `[-1]` displacement, the function overrides the return address so it points 9 bytes earlier, where the bytes `0f 0b` are.

These bytes cause an "undefined instruction" exception, as designed.

Answer (score 13):

## Java, <s>50</s> <s>43</s> 24 bytes

```
a->a.exec("kill -4 $$");
```

This is a `java.util.function.Consumer<Runtime>`<sup>1</sup> whose command is stolen from [fluffy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100678). It works because you *must* call it as `whateverNameYouGiveIt.accept(Runtime.getRuntime())`!

Note that this will create a new process and make it throw a SIGILL rather than throwing a SIGILL itself.

<sup>1 - Technically, it can also be a `java.util.function.Function<Runtime, Process>` because `Runtime#exec(String)` returns a `java.lang.Process` which can be used to control the process you just created by executing a shell command.</sup>

---

For the sake of doing something more impressive in such a verbose language, here's a <s>72</s> <s>60</s> 48-byte bonus:

```
a->for(int b=0;;b++)a.exec("sudo kill -s 4 "+b);
```

This one is another `Consumer<Runtime>` that goes through ALL processes (including itself), making each of them throw a SIGILL. Better brace for a violent crash.

---

And another bonus (a `Consumer<ANYTHING_GOES>`), which at least *pretends* to throw a SIGILL in 20 bytes:

```
a->System.exit(132);
```

Answer (score 11):

## Perl, 9 bytes

```
kill+4,$$
```

Simply calls the appropriate library function for signalling a process, and gets the program to signal itself with `SIGILL`. No actual illegal instructions are involved here, but it produces the appropriate result. (I think this makes the challenge fairly cheap, but if anything's allowed, this is the loophole you'd use…)

Comment: Came here to post the same, with a space instead of the `+`. :)

Comment: When people learn Perl for non-golf programming, they learn it with a `+`. After golfing for a while, they do `+` occasionally to show off. Eventually, they've written enough programs where they needed to avoid whitespace for some reason or other that the `+` becomes habit. (It also parses less ambiguously, because it works around triggering the special case in the parser for parentheses.)

Comment: Using the "0" pid option from another example we can apparently shave off another byte. `perl -E'kill+4,0'`

Answer (score 9):

## ARM Unified Assembler Language (UAL), 3 bytes

```
nop
```

For example:

```
$ as ill.s -o ill.o
$ ld ill.o -o ill
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 00010054
$ ./ill 
Illegal instruction
```

After executing `nop`, the processor interprets the `.ARM.attributes` section as code and encounters an illegal instruction somewhere there:

```
$ objdump -D ill

ill:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00010054 <__bss_end__-0x10004>:
   10054:       e1a00000        nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)

Disassembly of section .ARM.attributes:

00000000 <.ARM.attributes>:
   0:   00001341        andeq   r1, r0, r1, asr #6
   4:   61656100        cmnvs   r5, r0, lsl #2
   8:   01006962        tsteq   r0, r2, ror #18
   c:   00000009        andeq   r0, r0, r9
  10:   01080106        tsteq   r8, r6, lsl #2
```

Tested on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: Somehow this doesn't work on a Pi 2.

Answer (score 8):

## Microsoft C (Visual Studio 2005 onwards), 16 bytes

```
main(){__ud2();}
```

I can't easily test this, but according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983360(v=vs.80).aspx) it should produce an illegal instruction by intentionally trying to execute a kernel-only instruction from a user-mode program. (Note that because the illegal instruction crashes the program, we don't have to try to return from `main`, meaning that this K&R-style `main` function is valid. Visual Studio never having moved on from C89 is normally a bad thing, but it came in useful here.)

Comment: Can you compile for linux with VS2015? Because I do not think SIGILL is defined in Windows, is it?

Answer (score 7):

## Ruby, 13 bytes

```
`kill -4 #$$`
```

I guess it's safe to assume that we are running this from a *nix shell. The backtick literals runs the given shell command. `$$` is the running Ruby process, and the `#` is for string interpolation.

---

Without calling the shell directly:

## Ruby, 17 bytes

```rb
Process.kill 4,$$
```

Answer (score 7):

## ELF + x86 machine code, 45 bytes

This should be the smallest executable program on an Unix machine that throws SIGILL (due to Linux not recognizing the executable if made any smaller).

Compile with `nasm -f bin -o a.out tiny_sigill.asm`, tested on an x64 virtual machine.

Actual 45 bytes binary:

```
0000000 457f 464c 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001

0000020 0002 0003 0020 0001 0020 0001 0004 0000

0000040 0b0f c031 cd40 0080 0034 0020 0001
```

Assembly listing (see source below):

```
;tiny_sigill.asm      
BITS 32


            org     0x00010000

            db      0x7F, "ELF"             ; e_ident
            dd      1                                       ; p_type
            dd      0                                       ; p_offset
            dd      $$                                      ; p_vaddr 
            dw      2                       ; e_type        ; p_paddr
            dw      3                       ; e_machine
            dd      _start                  ; e_version     ; p_filesz
            dd      _start                  ; e_entry       ; p_memsz
            dd      4                       ; e_phoff       ; p_flags


_start:
                ud2                             ; e_shoff       ; p_align
                xor     eax, eax
                inc     eax                     ; e_flags
                int     0x80
                db      0
                dw      0x34                    ; e_ehsize
                dw      0x20                    ; e_phentsize
                db      1                       ; e_phnum
                                                ; e_shentsize
                                                ; e_shnum
                                                ; e_shstrndx

  filesize      equ     $ - $$
```

Disclaimer: code from the following tutorial on writing the smallest assembly program to return a number, but using opcode ud2 instead of mov:
http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html

Comment: I was gonna post a modified executable of that exact tutorial, but you beat me to it. This deserves to win; It's a true minimalist in the system resources sense (It requires no more than 45 bytes both in-file and in-memory, and is exactly the same in both), and no bloated interpreter like the other assembler solutions. It simply is what it is.

Answer (score 6):

## [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com), 93 bytes

Using flatassembler inline assembly:

```
#include<AssembleIt.au3>
Func W()
_("use32")
_("ud2")
_("ret")
EndFunc
_AssembleIt("int","W")
```

When run in SciTE interactive mode, it'll crash immediately. The Windows debugger should popup for a fraction of a second. The console output will be something like this:

```
--> Press Ctrl+Alt+Break to Restart or Ctrl+Break to Stop
0x0F0BC3
!>14:27:09 AutoIt3.exe ended.rc:-1073741795
```

Where `-1073741795` is the undefined error code thrown by the WinAPI. This can be any negative number.

Similar using my own assembler [LASM](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/173946-light-assembler-lasm-and-a-bunch-of-examples/):

```
#include<LASM.au3>
$_=LASM_ASMToMemory("ud2"&@CRLF&"ret 16")
LASM_CallMemory($_,0,0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 6):

## Any shell (sh, bash, csh, etc.), any POSIX (10 bytes)

Trivial answer but I hadn't seen anyone post it.

```
kill -4 $$
```

Just sends SIGILL to the current process. Example output on OSX:

```
bash-3.2$ kill -4 $$
Illegal instruction: 4
```

Comment: You could do `kill -4 1` if the question isn't specific about *which* program throws the SIGILL

Comment: @MarkKCowan Heh, good point, although that assumes root...

Comment: `You will have root in your programs` - knock a byte off your answer and troll the question slightly at the same time :D.  BONUS: You get to kill `init`

Comment: @MarkKCowan: On (modern versions of?) Linux, `init` is actually immune to signals that it hasn't specifically requested to receive, even with root. You could perhaps work around this by using a different POSIX OS, though.

Comment: `kill -4 2` then :D

Comment: @MarkKCowan ah, I missed the 'you will have root' stipulation. That certainly makes it easier!

Comment: @MarkKCowan PID 2 is `kthreadd`, which is a kernel thread and, like, init, can't receive signals unless it has registered for them specifically.

Answer (score 5):

## Python, 32 bytes

```
from os import*;kill(getpid(),4)
```

Comment: Same byte count: `import os;os.kill(os.getpid(),4)`

Answer (score 5):

## NASM, 25 bytes

I don't know how this works, just that it does on my computer specifically (Linux x86_64).

```
global start
start:
jmp 0
```

Compile & run like:

```
$ nasm -f elf64 ill.asm && ld ill.o && ./a.out
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000000400080
Illegal instruction
```

Comment: You can probably shorten it to four bytes, as `ja 0`

Comment: or three as `ud2`

Comment: Probably because it's trying to jump to some data?

Answer (score 5):

## TI-83 Hex Assembly, 2 bytes

```
PROGRAM:I
:AsmPrgmED77
```

Run as `Asm(prgmI)`. Executes the illegal 0xed77 opcode. I count each pair of hex digits as one byte.

Answer (score 4):

## Linux shell, 9 bytes

```
kill -4 0
```

Sends `SIGILL` to the process with PID 0. I don't know what process has PID 0, but it always exists.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/PzszJ0dB10TB4P9/AA)

Comment: From `man kill`: `0      All processes in the current process group are signaled.`

Answer (score 4):

## x86 .COM, 1 byte

```
c
```

`ARPL` causes `#UD` in 16-bit mode

Answer (score 4):

## Rust, 53 bytes

```rs
fn main(){unsafe{std::hint::unreachable_unchecked()}}
```

This piece of code generates no `main` function because main is marked as unreached, hence SIGILL being triggered when run. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBDcAgCADAVfrUFVimoYjBtPIQeBlnp3crzDO7XhOHlrpDDTtv8wYgQx0gdDGS4PPxHUrC9HIr9ZzMHw)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf and Programming Puzzles stack exchange! You have a nice first answer, but is preferable to add a link to [try it online](https://tio.run/##BcHBDcAgCADAVfrUFVimoYjBtPIQeBlnp3crzDO7XhOHlrpDDTtv8wYgQx0gdDGS4PPxHUrC9HIr9ZzMHw "Rust – Try It Online"). Also, your answer is only 53 bytes long.

Answer (score 2):

## GNU C, <s>24</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

<sup>-4 thanks to Dennis

-1 thanks to ceilingcat</sup>

```
main(){goto*&"'";}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7M6Pb8kX0tNSV3Juvb/fwA) This assumes ASCII and x86_64. It attempts to run the machine code `27`, which ... is illegal.

---

## [shortC](//git.io/shortC), <s>10</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
AV"'
```

Equivalent to the GNU C code above. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87ILypJ/v/fMUwpxuz/fwA)

Comment: `L"\6"` is also illegal, assuming x86_64.

Comment: @Dennis What instruction is 0x06? Also, the `L` is not necessary.

Comment: It's unassigned.

Comment: It's unassigned; that's what makes it illegal. Also, `'` is **39 = 0x27**, not **0x39**.

Answer (score 2):

## [MachineCode](//github.com/aaronryank/MachineCode) on x86_64, <s>2</s> 1 bytes

```
7
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y01MzsjMS03OT0n9/9/I/P9/AA)

Simply calls the x86_64 instruction `0x07` (ceilingcat suggested 0x07 instead of 0x27)

Answer (score 1):

## MMIXAL, 13 bytes

`Main RESUME 2`

`RESUME` is legal in all code; `RESUME 1` throws a protection violation in user mode; any other argument throws an illegal instruction violation.