# Shortest code that throws SIGBUS

Tags: code-golf

We've had challenges for [SIGSEGV](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/4399/shortest-code-that-returns-sigsegv/62668#62668) and [SIGILL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/100532/shortest-code-to-throw-sigill) so why not...

Write the shortest code that results in a **[Bus Error (SIGBUS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_error)** in any programming language.

Your program can't call `raise()` or `kill(getpid(),sig)` or `pthread_kill(pthread_self(),sig)`, or any other equivalent.

Comment: @ГригорийПерельман It's not a duplicate, no answer for that challenge can be applied to this one without nontrivial modification.

Comment: @orlp There are Bash, Python, Perl, and C answers that are all essentially `raise(11)`. They can be trivially modified to be `raise(7)` instead for this challenge.

Comment: Are you riding the SIGBUS, or driving it?

Comment: Java/Groovy is also just `System.exit(#);` where you only change the # to throw a different exit code... This is a very trivial difference in many languages.

Comment: @mbomb007 neither. You're throwing it. That seems like the most difficult of the three.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the rule "Your program can't call raise() or kill(getpid(),sig) or pthread_kill(pthread_self(),sig), or any other equivalent." bans those copy-paste answers.

Comment: @pppery While that rule may make this not a duplicate it does make this unclear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## x86_64 bytecode, 15 bytes

```
   0:   c7 04 24 00 00 04 00    movl   $0x40000,(%rsp)
   7:   9d                      popfq  
   8:   8b 04 25 01 00 00 00    mov    0x1,%eax
```

Turns on the misaligned address trap flag and then immediately triggers it.