# It's Hip to be Square

Tags: code-golf, math, number, decision-problem

## Challenge

So, um, it seems that, while we have plenty of challenges that work with square numbers or numbers of other shapes, we don't have one that simply asks:

Given an integer `n` (where `n>=0`) as input return a truthy value if `n` is a perfect square or a falsey value if not.

---

### Rules

- You may take input by any reasonable, convenient means as long as it's permitted by [standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/58974).
- You need not handle inputs greater than what your chosen language can natively handle nor which would lead to floating point inaccuracies.
- Output should be one of two consistent truthy/falsey values (e.g., `true` or `false`, `1` or `0`) - truthy if the input is a perfect square, falsey if it's not.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so lowest byte count wins.

---

### Test Cases

```
Input:  0
Output: true

Input:  1
Output: true

Input:  64
Output: true

Input:  88
Output: false

Input:  2147483647
Output: false
```

Comment: @Neil I realized my mistake. I retract that suggestion, and instead offer `18014398509481982` (`2**54-2`), which *is* representable with a double, and causes answers that use `sqrt` to fail.

Comment: @Mego I'm probably wrong or just misunderstanding what you're saying, but I'm sure `2**54-2` is still larger than a double can safely handle, at least in JavaScript `18014398509481982 > 9007199254740991`

Comment: @Mego I think the limiting value is 9007199515875288. It's not the square of 94906267, because that's not representable in a double, but if you take its square root, then you get that integer as the result.

Comment: @Tom Type `2**54-2` into a JS console, and compare what you get with `18014398509481982` (the exact value). JS outputs the exact value, therefore `2**54-2` is representable with a double. If that still doesn't convince you, take the binary data `0100001101001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`, interpret it as a IEEE-754 double-precision float, and see what value you get.

Comment: [**Extremely relevant SO post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double/1848762#1848762).

Comment: @Mego Numbers larger than 2^53 can be stored accurately as IEEE-754 double precision floats, _"...but we all know they are tiny islands of exactitude in an ocean of near misses"_

Comment: @StewieGriffin Exactly. `2**54-2` is the smallest integer I found that is representable with a double, but is large enough that `(n**.5)**2 != n` due to inaccuracies in the calculations.

Comment: In my opinion, it's over-complicating things if we should start including numbers that high. If it's impossible to [count to a number](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Lb8oN7FEISc/L52rQsFWwSjO1ETXxJoLKK6QmQkUMLQy46rQ1uZKzUv5/x8A) then it should be acceptable that we can't take the square root or do any other mathematical operation on it.

Comment: Sorry, guys, stepped away for lunch and ... well, that escalated! And there I thought this would be a nice, simple challenge! Would adding a rule that you need not handle inputs that lead to floating point inaccuracies in your chosen language cover it?

Comment: @StewieGriffin That's not the current consensus.

Answer (score 29):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 2 bytes

```
q
```

Explanation:

```
q      Push an infinite list of squares
      Is the input in that list?
```

When I say 'infinite' I mean up until we hit the maximum value of longs (2^63-1). However, Neim is (slowly) transitioning to theoretically infinitely large BigIntegers.

[Try it!](http://178.62.56.56:80/neim?code=q%F0%9D%95%9A&input=64)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60233/discussion-on-answer-by-okx-its-hip-to-be-square).

Comment: Interesting. So, does this pre-buffer the list or is it a generator / iterator that continues checking for the existence of input until it terminates?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Can we talk in chat?

Comment: Sure, just ping me on [The Nineteenth Byte](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte). I'm in there occasionally.

Comment: Well, this is ... REALLY FUNCTIONAL

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Æ²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9w26FN////NzMBAA)

Comment: Also works with Ohm.

Answer (score 9):

## dc, 9

```
0?dvd*-^p
```

Outputs 1 for truthy and 0 for falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##RYtBCsIwEADvfcVQlIIQaDW0AUF/ItTslvaSlCb05N@jCOIcZ5jnmOYyxY2sKfsxKUugpaO3OMe5s4N1l94OVyRWfFi3JeSJ@pgwN2oOv/Nb1c/xr3ghHqM0pb3LLifzWEtTSQxa3g).

```
0            # Push zero.  Stack: [ 0 ]
 ?           # Push input.  Stack: [ n, 0 ]
  dv         # duplicate and take integer square root.  Stack: [ ⌊√n⌋, n, 0 ]
    d        # duplicate.  Stack: [ ⌊√n⌋, ⌊√n⌋, n, 0 ]
     *       # multiply.  Stack: [ ⌊√n⌋², n, 0 ]
      -      # take difference. Stack: [ n-⌊√n⌋², 0 ]
       ^     # 0 to power of the result.  Stack: [ 0^(n-⌊√n⌋²) ]
        p    # print.
```

Note `dc`'s `^` exponentiation command gives 0<sup>0</sup>=1 and 0<sup>n</sup>=0, where n>0.

Comment: Beautiful!  +1 for using `dc` in such ingenious fashion.

Answer (score 8):

## C#, 27 bytes

```c#
n=>System.Math.Sqrt(n)%1==0
```

---

A more [correct/accurate way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751593/how-to-determine-if-a-decimal-double-is-an-integer) to do this would be:

```c#
n=>System.Math.Sqrt(n)%1<=double.Epsilon*100
```

Comment: [double.Epsilon is useless for this type of check](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/). tl;dr: When comparing numbers >2, Double.Epsilon is basically the same as zero. Multiplying by 100 will only delay that a bit.

Comment: @RobertFraser I only went by the linked SO post and didn't read to much into it. Either way it isn't useless just not to useful at higher numbers.

Comment: `...<int>==0` is `...!<int>` I think

Comment: @StanStrum Not in C#

Answer (score 8):

## TI-Basic, 4 bytes

```
not(fPart(√(Ans
```

Simply checks if the square root is an integer by looking for a nonzero fractional/decimal part.

Comment: Can you add a TIO (or equivalent)?

Comment: @Shaggy I don't think there are any. TI-Basic is proprietary and will only run on TI's calculators and in emulators running the ROM from a calculator, so you cannot legally use TI-Basic if you don't own a calculator.

Comment: @Shaggy If you have any ROMs you can use an emulator (my preference is jstified) to try this out online.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), 13 bytes

```
n=>!(n**.5%1)
```

Returns true if the square root of n is a whole number.

**Snippet:**

```js
f=
n=>!(n**.5%1)

console.log(f(0));
console.log(f(1));
console.log(f(2));
console.log(f(4));
console.log(f(8));
console.log(f(16));
console.log(f(88));
console.log(f(2147483647));
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 18 bytes

```
.+
$*
(^1?|11\1)+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wX0@bS0WLSyPO0L7G0DDGUFNb5f9/Ay5DLjMTLgsLAA) Shamelessly adapted from @MartinEnder's answer to [Is this number triangular?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122087) but with the base conversion included at a cost of 6 bytes.

Note that Is this number triangular? wasn't for some inexplicable reason required to support zero as a triangular number, so part of the adaption was to add a `?` to make the leading 1 optional, allowing the group to match the empty string, and therefore a zero input. However, having now matched the empty string, the `+` operator stops repeating, to avoid the infinite loop that would happen if it kept greedily matching the empty string (after all, `^1?` would certainly keep matching). This means that it doesn't even try to match the other alternative in the group, thus avoiding the match of 2, 6, 12 etc. As @MartinEnder points out, a simpler way to avoid that while still matching the empty string is to anchor the match at the start while making the group optional for the same byte count: `^(^1|11\1)*$`.

Comment: Looking forward to your explanation why this doesn't match `2`, `6` or other numbers of the form `n^2-n`. ;) (A way to avoid that explanation for the same byte count would be `^(^1|11\1)*$`.)

Comment: @MartinEnder Same reason that you couldn't use `(^|1\1)+$`, I think?

Comment: Yeah that's right. Just thought it would probably be good to mention because most people probably haven't read my comment on the triangular answer (and in this case it's actually relevant to why the solution is correct, as opposed to just why it can't be golfed further).

Comment: For the record, the `+` would also stop looping if there was no longer an empty alternative, e.g. in the case of `((?(1)11\1|1?))+`. Once there was an empty iteration, it won't try any further ones, regardless of whether they may or may not be empty.

Comment: @MartinEnder Indeed, I meant "having now matched" instead of "having immediately matched". Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 14 bytes

13 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$_=sqrt!~/\./
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAv@q8TbFhcWlSjW6cfo6f@3VlCJV9CzVVCKyVP6b8hlZsJlYQEA)

Computes the square root, and looks if it's an integer (more precisely, if it doesn't contain a dot (`/\./`).

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 19 bytes

```python
lambda n:n**.5%1==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcs9C4MwFIXhuf6KW0FIRETpByI4dOncoZt1iHqDoTFKbqT461MpbbfDy3nm1Q2TOXhZPbwWY9sLMKWJ4/QU5VWV@UBOFhQoA4zlyd0uyBN2Pv5WUSRXoQk5L4OdkiCZqrOGw74CVefNFnezVcax8GanVuMIPTrsHPbwUm4Ah@Q6QQgRhdGHbqK1KJ7B1120/r8IZkG0WVq6DonkovWahty/AQ)

Comment: Fails for large inputs, e.g. `4111817668062926054213257208`.

Comment: Fixed in 25 bytes: `lambda n:int(n**.5)**2==n`

Comment: @L3viathan That (along with any solution that involves `sqrt`) fails on values which are outside of the range of a double, like `2**4253-1`.

Comment: @totallyhuman a float after `%1` is definitely `<1`, so your proposal would return true for all inputs. Note that `n**.5` is a float.

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

Thanks to Luis for reducing my one byte longer code by two bytes, making it the shortest one.

```
t:Um
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8QqNPf/f0MTEwA)

**Explanation:**

```
         % Implicit input
t        % Duplicate it
 :       % Range from 1 to input value
  U      % Square the range, to get 1 4 9 ... 
   m     % ismember, Checks if the input is a member of the range of perfect squares
```

---

Old answer:

```
X^1\~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyLOMKbu/38zEwA)

```
        % Implicit input
X^      % Square root of input
  1\    % Modulus 1. All perfect squares will have 0, the rest will have decimal value
     ~  % Negate, so the 0 becomes 1, and the decimal values become 0
```

Comment: @Mego I  disagree. MATL can't even do `mod(2**127-, 1000)`. Unless the [four last digits are 0](https://tio.run/##DcWxAcAgDAOwVzjBxiFOf@nCDhv/02rRnmfdSwDvn8EgS5GIfLpoMcuCzFEVxHB3@wA)....

Comment: You can also use `t:Um`. That works for inputs [up to `2^53`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1848762/2586922), due to floating point limited precision

Comment: I see now that this is similar to your edit, only a little shorter :-)

Comment: Well hidden square command! `U: str2num / string to array / square`. I knew there had to be a square function, but I couldn't find it...

Comment: Heh. It was a late addition, so I overloaded a bit :-)

Comment: Um... your first sentence confuses me

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing that was partially on purpose. I had two solutions, one was 5 bytes, the other one 6 bytes. Luis golfed off two bytes from the one with 6. So I saved two bytes thanks to him, but I only saved a byte on the score...

Answer (score 6):

## C (gcc), 30 bytes

```
f(n){n=sqrt(n)==(int)sqrt(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zOs@2uLCoBMiytdXIzCvRhPKsa/8DeQq5iZl5Gppc1VwKQFBQBBRK01BSTYnJw8RKOgppGgaaINIQTJqZQDhm5ubmRoZmYI6FBZgyMjQxN7EwNjMx19S05qr9/y85LScxvfi/bk4uAA)

## C, 34 bytes

```
f(n){return(int)sqrt(n)==sqrt(n);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NI0@zuii1pLQoTyMzr0SzuLCoBChkawtlWNf@Bwor5CZm5mloclVzKQBBQRFQKE1DSTUlJg8TK@kopGkYaIJIQzBpZgLhmJmbmxsZmoE5FhZgysjQxNzEwtjMxFxT05qr9v@/5LScxPTi/7o5uQA)

## C, 33 bytes

```
#define f(n)(int)sqrt(n)==sqrt(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/185JTUtMy9VIU0jT1MjM69Es7iwqATItrWFMv4DBRVyEzPzNDS5qrkUgKCgCCiUpqGkmhKTh4mVdIBmGWiCSEMwaWYC4ZiZm5sbGZqBORYWYMrI0MTcxMLYzMRcU9Oaq/b/v@S0nMT04v@6ObkA)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 38 bytes

*Thanks to squid for saving 2 bytes!*

```python
lambda n:n in(i*i for i in range(n+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk8hM08jUytTIS2/SCETyFEoSsxLT9XI0zbU1PxfUJSZV6KRmJOjkaaRrQlWkw1SE22gY6hjZhKrqckFUZKXX6KQmFeJrsxIx8ICqOg/AA)

Too slow to return an answer for `2147483647` in a reasonable amount of time.  (But written using a generator to save memory, since it doesn't cost any bytes.)

Works in Python 2 also, though an `OverflowError` is a possibility due to `range` if you try it with huge inputs. (A `MemoryError` would also be likely in Python 2, also due to `range`.)

Answer (score 6):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 1 byte

```
°
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Qhv//DbgMucxMuCwsuIwMTcxNLIzNTMy5jM24jM25zEwB)

I don't think an explanation is needed. I saw the need for an "is perfect square" operator before I saw this challenge, as the language is designed to handle math related golf challenges. Returns 0 or 1, as MathGolf uses integers to represent booleans.

Answer (score 6):

## Regex (<sub><sup>ECMAScript / Python or better</sup></sub>), 50 bytes

```
^((?=(xx+?)\2+$)((?=\2+$)(?=(x+)(\4+$))\5){2})*x?$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9BT8JAFIT/CjYE3qO2FEQPrEtPHrhw0KNosoFH@3TZbnYXqCC/vbYxJt5m5ptkMh/qqPzGsQ2Jt7wlt6/MJ301Tho69Z6peKotwFkuxqPmHSCXUNdxjutp3MfO/ooujhHWs9bg@h4v0yuO6rzfjMZnTEP1EhybAjD1mjcED7fJDFF4mYlTyZoAtHSktpoNAeKNNAet8VJInXqrOcAwGaLgHYCRRarJFKHExfT7m/1KrYClVc7T0gQoXrM3xD9A/4FZTPLJvMMYSledoqU5Ks3bnlOmoHkvirXYVQ4EP0oSHMfYDkZ1lDqypAIwpnsVNiU4xIsfDGx7KUD3YiLsIfjg2oq4XpssuZtl2Q8)

This regex is explained in [Match strings whose length is a fourth power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19262/match-strings-whose-length-is-a-fourth-power/21951#21951). teukon and I arrived at it independently, starting on 2014-02-22, though golfing it down to this point took him 2 days and took me 4 days. It works by dividing away squared prime factors one at a time, thus keeping the number's property of being a square at every step iff it started out being a square. This regex represents a local minimum in length; it's the shortest form that this particular algorithm can be golfed into. It can be modified to match Nth powers by changing the `2` in `{2}` to N.

## Regex (ECMAScript), 28 bytes

```
^(x(x*)|)(?=(\1*)\2+$)\1*$\3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@xbsIwFEV/JY0QeS9pQkIrBlzD1IGFoR2BShY8EreOY9kGUqBrP6Cf2B9JYUDqdqUz3HPexV64tZXGp87IDdm60R/02Vmu6RC8UPncGoAjnwzi7g1aaGM8I0w5LIsYl8Okh5fRWz508eCImW9evZW6BMyckmuC0X36iMgcz9mhkooAFLckNkpqAsQ7rndK4ankKnNGSQ9RGiGTWwDNy0yRLn2Fk@H5LN1czEFyI6yjmfZQLvIV4g3Qf6AnxbQYXzH6yjaHcKb3QslNYIUuaRyEiWLbxgKTT5yYTBK8HNY8bMPMkiHhQWJWC7@uwCKeXL9vLlEerh0FMzvvvAWZRMHv908QJfWiWN1U2ddXl6fFKM//AA)

```
^              # tail = C = input number
(x(x*)|)       # \1 = A = conjectured square root of C; \2 = A-1, or unset if A==0,
               # allowing us to match C==0 using ECMAScript NPCG behavior; tail -= A
(?=
    (\1*)\2+$  # iff A*A==C, the first match here must result in \3==0
)
\1*$\3         # assert A divides tail, and \3==0
```

This ultimate form of this was arrived upon from 2014-03-02 to 2014-03-04 through several rounds of golfing between teukon and me, after we had already independently come up with the coprime moduli method of generalized multiplication (which took him 3 hours and took me almost 2 days). I came up with the idea to do one of the tests as `(\1*)\2+$` followed by testing if `\3`==0 although it didn't improve my regex's overall length at the time, and he came up with the idea to combine the `\3`==0 test and `\1*$` test into one, as `\1*$\3`, thus doing the `\1*$` test at the end instead of the beginning (which sacrifices speed in the name of golf, assuming the regex engine doesn't optimize it). (That is with the group numbering of the fully golfed form mapped onto the snippets.)

I've explained the generalized multiplication algorithm [in this post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/179239/find-a-rocco-number/179420#179420), but since its application to squares is simpler, I'm including an explanation for that here.

To explain why this works, let's rearrange the order of the assertions:

```
(?=
    \1*$       # assert that A divides C-A
)
(?=
    (\1*)\2+$  # iff A*A==C, the first match here must result in \3==0
)
.*$\3          # assert that \3==0
```

We have \$A^2 \stackrel{?}{=} C\$. If this assertion were true, we would have:

\$\begin{aligned}C &= A^2 \\
C-A &= A^2-A \\
&= (A-1)A\end{aligned}\$

This shows that the assertions made by the regex will hold true if \$C=A^2\$:

\$\begin{aligned}C-A &\equiv 0 \pmod A \\
C-A &\equiv 0 \pmod {A-1}\end{aligned}\$

Note that in regex, \$0 \equiv 0 \pmod 0\$, so the algorithm works for \$C=1^2\$ and \$A=1\$ without any need for a special case. It also works for \$C=0\$, matching it using ECMAScript NPCG (unset/non-participating capture group) behavior – every assertion becomes \$0 \equiv 0 \pmod 0\$ and passes.

Assuming \$A>1\$, these can be simplified into:

\$\begin{aligned}C &\equiv 0 \pmod A \\
C &\equiv 1 \pmod {A-1}\end{aligned}\$

We now have two coprime moduli, \$A\$ and \$A-1\$. By the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), there is one and only one integer \$E\$ such that \$0 \le E < A(A-1)\$ and the above moduli are satisfied. That applies to any window of the same length, so we can change it to \$A < E \le A^2\$.

\$A^2-A=(A-1)A\$ shows there is at least one \$E\$ satisfying the moduli: \$E=A^2\$. The Chinese remainder theorem shows that there is exactly one \$E\$ satisfying the moduli within a certain range. Thus, if we restrict our search to the range \$A < E \le A^2\$, the only value matching both moduli will be \$E=A^2\$.

The first thing the regex does is `(x(x*)|)` which subtracts \$A\$ from \$C\$, so instead of directly searching for a matching \$E\$, it is searching for a matching \$E-A\$.

`(\1*)\2+$` will first attempt a match using the largest possible number of repetitions of `\1`. Since we already asserted `\1*$`, this will bring us exactly to `$`. But then there will be no room for `\2+`, which is required to have a positive repetition count due to the `+`. So then it starts trying smaller repetition counts for `\1`, giving `\2+` more space in incremental steps of `\1`, thus resulting in incrementally larger repetition counts for `\2`. Note that `\1`\$=A\$ and `\2`\$=A-1\$. So a successful match of `\2+$` represents a value of \$E-A\$ such that \$E-A \equiv 0 \pmod A\$ and \$E-A \equiv 0 \pmod {A-1}\$.

The regex essentially searches for the smallest \$A-1 \le E-A \le C-A\$ satisfying the moduli, or alternatively stated, the smallest \$2A-1 \le E \le C\$ satisfying the moduli. Thus, even if \$C > A^2\$, the first matching \$E\$ it finds will be \$E=A^2\$. Note that the range only had to be restricted to \$A < E\$ via the Chinese remainder theorem, and the regex restricts it to \$2A-1 \le E\$ which is a subset of that range.

If no match is found, then \$C < A^2\$ and we get a non-match. If a match is found, and if \$E-A=C-A\$, then the `\1` in `(\1*)` will have a repetition count of zero, and `\3` will capture a value of zero. The regex asserts that \$E=C\$ by asserting that `\3` has a value of zero; if this matches, then \$C=A^2\$ and is indeed a perfect square.

Note that in no point in this reasoning did it matter what the value of \$A\$ is. It will only match if \$A^2=C\$. Thus, it doesn't matter whether we search for a matching \$A\$ from smallest to largest or largest to smallest. The regex does the latter, starting at \$A=C\$ and going downward from there in decrements of \$1\$.

## Regex (ECMAScript / Python or better), 30 bytes

```
^(x(x*))(?=(\1*)\2+$)\1*$\3|^$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY@9bsIwFEZfhUYI7k2akFDUAdcwdWBhaMdSJAsuyW2NY9kGUn6ePQ1DpW6fdD7p6Hypo/Ibxzak3vKW3L423/TTOmno1Huj8rWxAGc5G8XtGhpoYkSYS1gVMa7GSR@70V89Xdf9Nh6dMQv1e3BsSsDMa94QPD@mE0ThZS5OFWsC0NKR2mo2BIgP0hy0xkspdeat5gDDdIiCdwBGlpkmU4YKZ@Prlf1SLYGlVc7TwgQoP/JPxD9A/4GZFfNiescYKlefooU5Ks3bnlOmpGkvSrTY1Q4Ev0gSnCTYCaMmyhxZUgEYs70Kmwoc4sUPBrZLCnCvKIQ9BB9cdxG3W5unRT6e/AI) - ECMAScript (SpiderMonkey)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69bsIwFIVfBUVIvpcQK6GdkhqmDiwM7dgUYSWXcCvXSW0DkYBnT0OlSmxH@s7flz5pXznuQmLbmgav0sKpN2pe@w7eg2PbSKfPu2ELPfQzRFgpKLMZlot4iqOYlk/X7XTYSW@4IsjmSYZYOPo5siMQjnRt2JJAWY060NoGcns9Wi9su2PIO9dW5L30oWZ7Q9laEH@JuVHLS6OM9J3hACIRWPAewKpGGrJNOOBycb2y3@gNsOq08/d2aD7ST8R/QI/ALrNVlt8xhoNrz9HanrTheuK0bSifRLEp9q2Dgl8UFRzHOA5GfSQddeN5YJTfOlQHcIiXh@PtMciz40AAfiVKK3IhMGYsvMqK2w2HNMnSxfMv) - ECMAScript (Node.js - fast)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5BasMwEPzKEpZYG9vYcttLZCUOpNeeeqsTkYYYBGriSi64qO7XXcUN5LLMzM7uTHuy5mn8@Aa0Ary5HA8GMBOBynK7ed2sBmgulqGTuShXgjzoJjDyrdXnDmb1eSYGqIx0rdEdi9IocV/vrgsnKkl5wun0eTWt72oedFqiInH95ULiwVamLMhX5o3vZJj5Ttxy9Y2iLuW0DiiOyesGGIv6CHoIJiKQv5Chzcijm8@nclO3UJyL/66oxTAMSj2/bJUa96xn/YKIrSWr@YLqIkYKAOuHnz2OY57yvHj8Aw) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJdb9swDHzvr@CMDpGSVE26PU01im3YgAHrNrSPSQootpyolWlPkhsnXX97RjneR4H4hSJ5PupOvFeP6uw@f9ibsq5cgHvKhanEUML/lSYYe7Tm9Eq31Dmpm6U1GWRWeQ/XyiA8QV/zQQUKj5XJoaQOuw3O4AqUW/nZgkNYu2rj4VOb6TqYiv48AfhsrIYiRb3pjiwRWZVrQf2Eyw9NUWin8xutcu1g2cFeFtmfP/u04Fz2c/04yM068jPm0yVpUPlXg5px/irFxlpuCuaF/tko61lyPhwOE86fXkIPDIyFowRPxBD@MhDBOTEsCfcg/SgdzHEQY5DPh9rzDxWCdggu7U@ktqzjAM8lubGsKqsVwi4tiFFLuM0UIkk3WDcBUohq@xq73fqgS2GQS@h1djCxVv6bbgNds7MYoDfE0t2J4wBCQvQS@/5sAZbaESV8bU1gyRk9AuED4IQ6XzDQGjhRK@c1JczOJgs@BpwebQqrcRXWlxdwBREJ7yhMF8SYrZWbLdpeT5fhdCHhvXNq60VhrGXteNAOOlMAispFbXSNFCcS8DLFKYXRiAReq5CtyaGS2JwoDxnrNhdpwT8S@WFjxMapmvUjsqrefi9uFK40TZqMkfOotABW0njMybv4tjvem1yRYxtngmbxUbncpcE18X3@tWvyMBQsee0TsoTL5/idxK3a37GWtUPO2VXK5tMhn1@MTjkdTudvft2d7uPe7Cdn08nF298) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVPbjtowEH3nK6YULTZJdglUfUjIrlSpP1D1oRWwUdaYxCo4luOIS7u/Xjp2ljSl4IfEnsuZOWdsplSQM3Z6LyTb1CsOs5eyrMyD5jnf3xdKPfYuXXzPuDKilA8rkeUSTYKlQq5Lvc2sucliRaYhVfMlJPCl/2m3@/Eyrb8fDt@@Fh93BTk9kz3ZjyglTwlZhCO6mHgDipvBYvrreXCilxl9H0YqSZUXxp2OBFbXPNs@9oQ0sM2EJBR@9gCXmqNrwyVRNAiXyTiGGmOmk9RAaU82IbebyqyiCGOFzNGoahO7fFbKyoCjHEVODtAcweKzrUK6rIBdkb1loAJALOwxGftw5C14zs1GSE7cgQnpN3VofO7VLpsox6hWZkpBXMA9S7EvQqkPMvRBlRW6G89ayBUZBkMatwAyRK@NeZd0OUWRtManK7jguXgPQgoRFv@L5aY3suUk3zWnuQy9cBnDlm8rbkjlw3A/tI2hIhU6rcRtfiuFSKTVepbIMAbPE13Gdhl9uLA4LdZAusqnFc80Kwjp8KJ3tmoglr4bgY/TofQK1hnvSAGpWypkuJAoHI4pjK@GN3MqawOzGYj/Y157t0/MXQryz@1pXwzcca3pDcLXG7xoxn76EXzWutT9@DoOp7C2SA7GtwC2amxvZIuHli5e3/7fur3@qonDuEG82TVfzU2tJeBleD2Ng3A8@fCbrTdZXp2CjauQupH@AQ) - Boost
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BboMwEEX3nGJksZghgDDpCmrlIECkqHUaV@6Axo5KpN6d4lTdfc3772uWR7zNfNzc1zJLhPAIpdjyM8zcgxhRSm1nXHEtiPBkcNQFje0hpz3k4/HnnG97ZdBdpacenGmy6yzgwXGaqkN8d9xl4I2vw@JdRFUpysBdwVtGT69tB37Qk/FDM2WQZE6yXPjDouOICVD5l/REB037XhoQWwd7kbcbSglqVQU/SUKug0WSQs@D0f3/N/M91t/iosUQBZloayrdtC@/) - Python
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5RS8MwEMff9ylupbCk2pBUnxaDFFfElwnTt3YLyrIuELKSZqyC@NVrMuce7rj73/93d@74@TU6ELBSrRo6YtUJFuV7SZz62N7@ifP5y/PydVU9lW8VBy0oh9NeGwVGtMr3EwC9A1PnbC1E0tiEh4GpKSF5seag7DY4gkL6zmiPZvkMXxBilG39HuGHIjB14AN2RXYHBxa0hSgSf5AaMYoJicZrG3znXSgZksxiED/geBT0NP7ZHX1/3hf/ZqF32nqw/ydijiFltVxIOW7QgIYMY/QoUMMy3BQ3KQ5F2tx9b9JxpDmjxf0v) - Ruby
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH33V4QQaK622nZuQ2LxZRsIYw/b3qyG2qW2LKYhjSA4f3t3K3vaQy7nfpxzbq6tbb9c2doS5khG6IySKbFOHaRTVhel4sFsOl5JWRfay7I92kYrl/McRP4@64KQBPgqLMqDGgaMV8Z3XMqX9euzlBCSBFAShcWoMY3slOfUlk5N90X57R0GqZtj42lI6DxdzBcPj@ninoIYVa3jrMliwXRWoXrHPz6f1m8g4EKaijO96bzTyiCCKNlmGc0NBRzuTnvsYDmMwyiBga/OVrdfitOIhjgukF@2J@MH7jJF0gYFMMZbMSLk5mz@cmaW2a2PaDIBtCb8dqFj4cuaMxei2XAuVXgenIOQGQAgl2HFBlRZt8NeguBXEkGGnDAjrmhz/XdWDqLf8TM/jwH4KuN5MoY8nTBAwPK7nx3r@zhK4nT@Cw) - PCRE (fastest)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RaoQwFER/ReSCiW4WtX3aEHahz/0CdUHs3TWQ3kjMoqzNt1ttKX2bMwzDzGAndGOPxqzgVOXwjnNzOhFO7JKsVzazOeWcnRWri5TXZQZ8E1C/fF1hTS6H@M1@DtrgR8wlPFUub9Zh2/UMTKQpAk3Dw/MFWgVGjIPRPhax1DcG7bGzD/LC@KjcA5mCtsqbsBUwIFVp8s2PI4GEwT8uds4yvuwd7vje@q7HkSVzkgLxX/vJl8lpj6K3ow/brEL@cyTIbveMJoyAQghrLoq8fP0G) - .NET

This is a port of the 28 byte version, dropping the dependence on ECMAScript NPCG behavior. Matching \$0^2\$ is done as a special case, the `^$` alternative at the end.

## Regex (Perl / Java / PCRE / .NET), 12 bytes

```
^(\1xx|^x)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5fa8IwFMW/ykWCzdWWJoI@mMZVcK972tvU4IaFQNQuqRDJsq/exU7w5XLPuX/Orz1aM@9PNyBWQDCXr4MBUookZbVZv69XEZqLpcRJJqqVwAC6SQpDa/W5g9H2PBIRaiNda3RHsyLL3fXTdelE5QXPOR6/70svT5clH5dEobj/cinxYGtTzTDU5oPvZKpsJx65@iGJruQwTt10ikE3QGnmM/CQlhBB/kJJbImBuPF4gBvYEjgX/6xEixijUq9vG6X6Pd1y73/2Hiek71kxmy8Y@wM) - Perl (fastest)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVLLbtswELznK7ZCC5N@MFaPZYSiLVqgQJMWydFxAFqibDrUSiWpWHaab3eXsvoIEF7I3R3Ocoa7VQ9qti3uj6ZqahdgS7EwtRhL@D/TBmNfzDm91h1Vzpp2ZU0OuVXew6UyCI8w5HxQgbaH2hRQUYXdBGdwDcqt/WLJIWxcvfPwuct1E0xNN88AvhirocxQ7/ojS0ReF1pQPeHyY1uW2uniWqtCO1j1sOdJ9ufmEJacy6Gvnwa520R@xny2Ig2q@GZQM85fZdhay03JvNA/W2U9S87H43HC@eNz6ImBsfAiwSMxhL8MRHBODCvC3Us/yUa3OIp7kE@n3NMPFYJ2CC4bTqS2amIDzyW5saprqxXCISuJUUu4yRUiSTfYtAEyiGqHHLvZ@6ArYZBLGHT2MLFR/kp3gZ7ZWwwwGGLp7cRxAiEhBolDfbEES@WIEr6xJrBkRp9A@AA4p8pXDDQGTjTKeU0Bs4v5kk8B0xeLwmpch83FW3gPEQnvaEuXxJhvlFssu0FPH2G6lPDBObX3ojTWsm466ka9KQBl7aI2ekaGcwl4kWFK22RCAi9VyDfkUEVsTlSniPWTizTgn4j8NDFi51TDhhZ53ey/l9cK15o6zafIeVRaAquoPRbkXfzbAx9MrsmxnTNBs/ipXB6y4Nr4P//KDXkYSpa88QlZwuVTXGdxqo537Dbtul93HR@/PsYpOc5n6ZzWbw) - Java
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBda8IwFH33V4QQaKKptqIOicWXbSCMPWx7sxpql9qwmIY0QsHtt3e3sqc95HK/zjk3x9Wu32xd7RDxKEN4htEUOa/O0itnilLRaDYdb6WsCxNk2VycNsrnNGcif5u1EUcRvAqa8qyGBRuUDS2V8nn38iQl4yhlQAnEYqStlq0KFLvSq@mpKL@ChyCNvuiAOcKL@XqxXj3M10vMxKhqPCU6SwQxWQXsLX3/eNy9MsFuSFeUmH0bvFEWMhanhyzDucUMltvrCSbQ5gmPUzbgVedM86kojjGHdQH4srnaMGA3cwDtgQBichAjhO7K9q8mdpPd55BNJgykEb07dClCWVPiOYgNdqki0KiLOLGMMXQbTtRMlXUz3CUQfCUVaKgRseIHZH7@2UqZ6I80T7vu@9ixMen7JJ4vV0nyCw) - PCRE (fast)
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/BasMwEER/RZgFS3EV7B4jBIGe@wWOA8Ld1AJ1ZWQFizj6dtduKZ3bG4ZhZvQzhmlA51YIug34iak7nQhnfi7XK780KT2vSRxgLc8vxZv/Gq3Dj0IoeOha3XxA0w8cHLPEwNJ4j2IBo8HJaXQ2FrJQ9sbBHHt/pyhdZK97oNJg2rrLWwEH0q2l2P04Ckg6/ONm56oSy94Rju8m9gNOvEzlAUj82g@xzMFGlIOfYt5mNeqfmSS/nXGWkAHlnNdaNvWmbw) - .NET

This works by exploiting the fact that \$(N+1)^2-N^2=2N+1\$, i.e. the differences between consecutive squares are consecutive odd numbers. The loop is initialized by subtracting \$1\$ from tail, which then captures `\1`=\$1\$. Every subsequent iteration sets `\1`\$=\$`\1`\$+2\$ and subtracts `\1` from tail. As a result, the cumulative subtraction from tail is at every step a perfect square, and the `$` will only match at the end if the subtraction culminates in tail equaling zero, meaning the initial value of tail before the loop started was a perfect square.

As such, this regex relies on being able to read the last captured value of group 1 from inside group 1 – a nested backreference, which is a feature not supported by the ECMAScript, Python, or Ruby regex engines.

In [this post by primo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19262/match-strings-whose-length-is-a-fourth-power/22084#22084), it is explained how to extend this method to higher powers and polynomials.

An alternative 12 byte form is `(\1xx|^x?)+$`, but this breaks some nice properties of the form shown above. Most notably, it breaks letting the loop iteration count equal the square root of the number being matched. One of the beauties of keeping that property is that we can return the square root, for example using .NET's balanced groups feature (**25 bytes**):

```
^(?=(\1xx|^x)*$)(?<-1>x)*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9RboMwDIavEiFLJGVBsL2VZa20552AUQl1LkRKHRSCQGW87gA74i7CwqZpb/78W5/tzo7o@haNWcGp0mGDU7XfE478GK8nflD8NZ@m99MkdiD44VHmT6Fc4@Nd9GyvnTb4FokCbiorLtZhfW45GKaJgaZu8GKGWoGRfWe0j2RU6AuHOj3bgbw0nt1vA4mCusyqJQg4kCo1@eqnUwBJg3@cb5wkYt4cVwUufan9ucWex1O8AxK/yU3Mo9MeZWt7v4TL8uKfmSQbnjOakEVA7Ovjk0GwpY2zQ9eHnalBanwromVZ1kzmD1n2DQ) - .NET

Or using group-building with a branch reset group (**19 bytes**):

```
^(?|\1(\1x)|^(x))*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU5BTsMwELz3FVZl1V6aNDYSlzpuUqlcOXEjrVVQCpZMGuwgBbnmyAN4Ih9J3YDEHlY7o5mdaWtrbobXD4StQN4cn/YG4UxEKPPN@n69CpPD0VLsJBP5SoBH@hAR@NbqpkPTqpmKgEojXWt0R0lKEvf@6LpoUUnKEw7120VU/LMs8rDECsTll4uJe1ua/Bp8aR74VsbNtiJMEBqT9R@BdS5HQbzmc/DRS0lPeqxBfmbYZuCxm83GXmOt2JmL35pYLwj6@fpGZEExL0zdPHcvmC8ZiBCCUrd3G6WGHS1OFacV7@G0oz3AFR4GlnIW5ww) - Perl
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVHNatwwEL7vUwxC4JlE67WXNGGrNXtpAoGQQ9tbnAjH1camtixkBTYke80D5BHzItvx0l4q0DB/3/fNSL7xh/XGNx5kgALEQkAKPtgnE6zvqtpiskhPNsY0VRdNPfS@7WwosSRdfl@MiYKE75aT5slODS5aF0c05ur65tIYUpATUzKxnrWuNaONKHwdbPpY1b9jYGO6tm@jUCDOlquz1fnFcvVFkJ5th4CyLTItu2LL7CP@@Pnt@pY0vUK7RdndjTF01rFH8/y@KETpBHHz@PzIFU6rTM1zmvB257vhl0UxF4rbNePr4dnFCbteMuiOCdhm93oGcFR2f2Pp1sWxzt7pKbE04PGF@irWDcqgWGx6LltFTHaJko6U7IngdZqyJVs3wzSaBt4m1zDFIF0q4PP9A0SKtvfxBWXPGrTJvv7b6hiT3vNA@/8@AEkfHnDzVuZY5jt6e8Ad0Yk8HLJ5nvH5Aw) - PCRE

## Regex (Python<sup>[`regex`](https://bitbucket.org/mrabarnett/mrab-regex/src/hg/)</sup> / Ruby or better), 22 bytes

```
^((?=(\3xx|^x))(\2))*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BasMwEEX3PsUgsphJbWMlO7siB3EcCK2SqKgjM1KpAr27a7l0Vp95vM@fn@kR@Li4zzlIgviMtdi7zfVHDDyAGFFKLRfEk8HzMeefSybC84Fov1tWNOq@0dMAznTVLQh4cFxa2pjeHfcVeOPbOHuXUDWKKnA38JbR0@uhBz/qyfixmyooMhdZrny36DhhAVT/JT3Ri6a1rxRsC9tor/L2QKlBZbXnDRbqepilWLQ9jB7@B4Wv1H6LSxZjEmSipWt0t94v) - Python <sub><sup>`import regex`</sup></sub>
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7RS8MwEMbf/SvOIiwZNqQV9rAYpLgivkyYvrVbUJZ1gXAracYiiP96Tabu4Q7uu@/33bnjx@foQMJKdzr0DPUJFtVbxZx@397@ivP589PyZVU/Vq@1ACO5gNPeWA1WdtoPVwBmB7bJi7WUWYuZiAvbcMbyci1A4zY6osKG3hpPJvmE/iHMauz8ntD7MjJN5CN2QXYHBwgGIYnMH5QhBaeMJeNljL5zFslCNkUK8hucSIK5Tn/2Rz@c89LfRZydQQ/4fyL1VErVy4VS44aQB0nauxC@NoFS0paUTm/GkeezGec/) - Ruby

In regex flavors with no support for nested backreferences, that feature must be emulated via forward-declared backreferences (which aren't supported either by ECMAScript or Python's built-in `re` module). This is done here by copying back and forth between `\2` and `\3`.

Comment: Incredible answer!!

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
Ln¹å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fJ@/QzsNL//83MwEA)

Comment: Doesn't work for large numbers, for example `4111817668062926054213257208`

Comment: @Emigna Oh because it's considered a long? I thought that 05AB1E uses Python 3.

Comment: [Fails for large inputs](https://tio.run/##BcEBDYBADANAR6T9buuQAwkO8PUiEDbukNfNZ@Y9vj1Dg0G2ohB1LtFitQWZ2R1EevkH) (the given input is `2**127-1`, a Mersenne prime).

Comment: It does use python 3. The problem is that square root gives rounding errors for large numbers.

Comment: @Emigna Oh...I guess I'll have to figure out another way then, shouldn't be hard.

Comment: @Emigna Fixed, at the cost of a byte :(

Comment: Was thinking `Lƶå`, but nope.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
¬v1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//9CaMsP//81MAA)

Seems to work fine for `2**54-2` in the [Japt Interpreter](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=rHYx&input=MTgwMTQzOTg1MDk0ODE5ODI=) but fails on TIO for some reason...

Comment: [Fails for large inputs](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/v1BB1fDQ0pD//w3NDQxNDA0tjE3MDEzMLI2MDc2NDc0szI0NjM0NTS0sTAwNTM2NzAE) (input is `2**127-1`, a Mersenne prime).

Comment: @Mego, isn't the norm that solutions need not handle numbers larger than the language is capable of handling?

Comment: @Shaggy Japt is based on JavaScript, which uses double-precision floats. `2**127-1` is well within the range of a double.

Comment: @Mego Isn't the max safe int for JavaScript `2**53-1`?

Comment: `2**53-1` is the smallest value for which 1 ulp is less than or equal to 1. That's irrelevant here.

Comment: @Mego Should work for everything now, will just take a very long time to run for large numbers

Comment: I think just `¬v1` works (0 for falsy, 1 for truthy)...

Comment: @Luke That's what I was originally going to have, but Mego brought up the issue with large numbers which may or may not be correct.

Comment: @Mego But JavaScript's numbers only have 53 bits of precision, so JS *cannot* exactly represent the value `2**127-1` as a number. The closest it can get is `2**127`.

Answer (score 5):

### [SageMath](https://sagemath.org), 9 bytes

```py
is_square
```

[Try it online](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLLI4vLixNLErVMNLSMjEyNdY11AQASNYF0A==&lang=sage)

The built-in function does exactly what it says on the tin. Since Sage uses symbolic computation, it's free of computational accuracy errors that plague IEEE-754 floats.

Answer (score 5):

### Haskell, <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```
f n=elem n$map(^2)[0..n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclBCoAgEADAr@zBQ8Eiq1mefIkoeFCSdJHq/9Zc50zPlVubswC73HIHFj2NJerVk5QcZk@VwcG4K78g4E8o4AkVHgaVMVHjjhYVkcLNhvkB)

Checks if n is in the list of all squares from `0` to `n`.

Comment: same byte count: `f n=or[i*i==n|i<-[0..n]]` :)

Answer (score 5):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 27 bytes

```
+N:-between(0,N,I),N=:=I*I.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/X9vPSjcptaQ8NTVPw0DHT8dTU8fP1srWU8tTDyipYaipx8UFAA)

### Explanation

Searches through all numbers greater or equal to `0` and less than or equal to `N` and tests whether that number squared is equal to `N`.

Comment: @DLosc [done](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/153160/20059)!

Answer (score 4):

## APL, 5 bytes

```
⊢∊⍳×⍳
```

Explanation:

```
⊢           N
  ∊         in
    ⍳        numbers up to N
      ×     times
        ⍳    numbers up to N
```

Test:

```
      ((⊢∊⍳×⍳) ¨ X) ,[÷2] X←⍳25
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
```

Comment: Can you add a TIO (or equivalent)?

Comment: doesn't work for 0, but you could do `⊢∊0,⍳×⍳` and it's still the shortest APL answer

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 25 bytes

```
Math.sqrt(gets.to_i)%1==0
```

There probably is a shorter way but that's all I found.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P0fBVkHXTkGjQlOhWsE3sSRDr7iwqATIVTW0tTVQqOUqKC0pVsjRS07MydFITy0p1ivJj8/UpKXw//8GXIZcZiZcFhZcRoYm5iYWxmYm5gA)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG :) Could you add a [TIO](https://tio.run/) (or equivalent) to this, please?

Comment: Thanks for adding the TIO however, this doesn't seem to return any output.

Comment: My bad, i updated it.

Comment: Nope, still not working.

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 21 bytes

```
<?=(-1)**$argn**.5<2;
```

If the square root is not an integer number, `(-1)**$argn**.5` is `NAN`.

Comment: How do I run this?

Comment: @Titus With the `-F` flag and pipeline: `echo 144 | php -F script.php`.

Comment: Ah I `f`orgot that letter. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## R, 15

```
scan()^.5%%1==0
```

^.5 is less bytes than sqrt(). %%1, the modulus, will result in 0 if answer is an interger. scan() takes user input.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_r_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMSm1qVktIOUdSSDg

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.unicode`, <s>20</s> 17 bytes

Saved 3 bytes thanks to @chunes!

```
[ √ dup ⌊ = ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcwxCsIwGIbh3VN8JyimhiQqzuLiIk7iUNK/GNQkpn8GEXcRT@DxepEo4vjCw9s1lkMq281qvZzh3PABMRHzNSbnGUdKnk7o6ZLJW@p/ouqyt@yC/2f2zoaWMB/dMIZADYkphILQUBLGoBZSSzNRUuOOssPweKPNEcPriQX25fuJqMoH)

Comment: You can save 3 bytes with `math.unicode`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcwxCsIwGIbh3VN8JyimhiQqzuLiIk7iUNK/GNQkpn8GEXcRT@DxepEo4vjCw9s1lkMq281qvZzh3PABMRHzNSbnGUdKnk7o6ZLJW@p/ouqyt@yC/2f2zoaWMB/dMIZADYkphILQUBLGoBZSSzNRUuOOssPweKPNEcPriQX25fuJqMoH "Factor – Try It Online")

Comment: @chunes Thanks (that'll be a useful vocabulary in the future too)!

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 26 bytes

```php
<?=(0^$q=sqrt($argn))==$q;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJSeZ6tkYqlkzWVvBxS01TCIUym0LS4sKtEAS2pq2tqqFFr///81L183OTE5IxUA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, 20 bytes

```
n->Math.sqrt(n)%1==0
```

Input is an `int`.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##hY7BCoJAEEDvfcVcgt2DkhAhiP2BXjxGh3Hdak1nzR2FCL/d1vIaXQZm3oM3NY4Y2E5TXd1n1aBzkKGh1wbAEOv@gkpDvqwApbWNRgIlPAKSib9OGz8cIxsFORCkMFNwzJBvoXv0LEhuozTdzcnidUPZeG/VR2sqaH1MFNwbup7OgPJbKp6OdRvagcPOI25IUKhEJD/Nn/yw/yPEsVy/nuY3)

Comment: Not debatable: the question explicitly says "Given an integer n (where n>=0)". The shortest answer is the best. Edit: won't +1 until the shortest answer isn't the first :p

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Hmm, that's a good way to look at it. But you still wouldn't know whether it's an `int`, `long`, `short`. And with questions where they ask for an integer but the input format is flexible, I sometimes use a String input to save some bytes. Personally I think using `n->` is fine, and you should just state what the type is, but apparently not everyone agrees with this. On the other hand, coming from a Java 7 answer history, going from `int c(int n){return ...;}` to `(int n)->...` makes more sense than `n->...` (even though I personally prefer the second since shorter of course).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Ok, I've changed it. After reading the discussion in [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12747/52210), I came to the conclusion that stating the input is an integer in Java, is no difference than stating the input is [a list of two Strings in CJam](https://tinyurl.com/y7vl8esz) or [a cell array of strings in MATL](https://tinyurl.com/ya5qwyba).

Comment: nvm, I'm stupid :P

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
AtomQ@Sqrt@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfsSQ/N9AhuLCoxEFZ7X9AUWZeiYJDmoOF4X8A)

Comment: No built in? Odd....

Comment: @TheLethalCoder If there is a built-in, it's probably longer than this.

Comment: You can use `AtomQ` instead of `IntegerQ`.

Comment: Can you add a TIO (or equivalent)?

Comment: of course shaggy...

Comment: You can still use `@*`.

Comment: can you give me an example of input for @*?

Comment: `AtomQ@*Sqrt` is a synonym for `AtomQ@Sqrt@#&`. For example, `AtomQ@*Sqrt@4` returns `True` and `AtomQ@*Sqrt@5` returns `False`. (Because of precedence, `AtomQ@*Sqrt[4]` doesn't work right, returning `AtomQ@*2`.)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 8 bytes

```apl
0=1|*∘.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///v/hR2wQDW8MarUcdM/RMgXwFAwVDBTMTBQsLBSNDE3MTC2MzE3MA)

`0=` [is] zero equal to

`1|` the modulus-1 (i.e. the fractional part) of

`*∘.5` the argument raised to the power of a half

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 8 bytes

```
ri_mQ2#=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/vygzPjfQSNn2/38zIwA)

#### Explanation

Integer square root, square, compare with original number.

Comment: I guess according to [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8493/80675), you don't need the first 2 bytes

Comment: And, alternatively, using the idea of [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125264/80675), you can do `mq1%0=`, which is also 6 bytes

Comment: @Chromium Thanks, but in that case I need `{`...`}` to make the code a function, so same byte count

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit confused whether to add curly braces or not. Cuz if you don't add them, it's actually a program, which is permitted.

Comment: @Chromium A program needs to take its input, so `ri` is required in that case

Answer (score 3):

## [Add++](https://github.com/SatansSon/AddPlusPlus), <s>24</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
+?
S
%1
N
O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/1/bnitOz5RL1ZDLj8v/////RoYm5iYWxmYm5gA)

I removed the clunky function at the top and rewrote it into the body of the question to remove 11 bytes.

As the first section is already explained below, let's only find out how the new part works

```
S   Square root
%1  Modulo by 1. Produced 0 for integers and a decimal for floats
N   Logical NOT
```

### Old version, 24 bytes

```
D,i,@,1@%!
+?
^.5
$i,x
O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ1PHQcfQQVWRS9ueK07PlEslU6eCy/////9GhibmJhbGZibmAA)

The function at the top (`D,i,@,1@%!`) is the main part of the program, so let's go into more detail.

```
D,     Create a function...
  i,   ...called i...
  @,   ...that takes 1 argument (for this example, let's say 3.162 (root 10))
    1  push 1 to the stack; STACK = [1, 3.162]
    @  reverse the stack;   STACK = [3.162, 1]
    %  modulo the stack;    STACK = [0.162]
    !  logical NOT;         STACK = [False]

+?     Add the input to accumulator (x)
^.5    Square root (exponent by 0.5)
$i,x   Apply function i to x
O      Output the result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 27+2 bytes

```
{x=int($0^0.5);$0=x*x==$1}1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jcwxCgJRDATQfk9hsYUKSuYnmeQjewSvIFiKYCW4IJ79m97GcoY3c33dx3ivy@3x3M5ykaPvTrMs635dlhkfjCETJtqUOTVYaHdKVSEwINUoxt7YHUJ0kAwV84S37n86/jhFKJhFNOCZBvFosfmB7s2V8EIh0qmVeh2qScumLCJd01gD1ahVWJ0zG2DOcTh/AQ)

Add `+2` bytes for using the `-M` flag for arbitrary precision.
I originally used string comparison because large number compared equal, even though they weren't, but the `sqrt` was also returning imprecise values. `2^127-2` should not be a perfect square.

Answer (score 3):

## T-SQL, 38 bytes

```
SELECT IIF(SQRT(a)LIKE'%.%',0,1)FROM t
```

Looks for a decimal point in the square root. `IIF` is specific to MS SQL, tested and works in MS SQL Server 2012.

Input is in column **a** of pre-existing table **t**, per [our input rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5341/70172).

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/nickbclifford/Ohm), 2 bytes

```
Æ²
```

Uses `CP-437` encoding.

### Explanation

Implicit Input -> Perfect square built-in -> Implicit Output...

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>28 27</s> 25 bytes

- Thanks to @mdahmoune for 1 byte: compare int of root squared with original
- 2 bytes saved: lambda shortened

```python
lambda x:int(x**.5)**2==x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKjOvRKNCS0vPVFNLy8jWtuJ/QRFIKE3DUFOTC8Y2QmIbI7EtkdWgaDDV1PwPAA)

Comment: what about f=lambda x:int(x**.5)**2==x 27bytes

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 6 bytes

```
;ur♂²c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/9@6tOjRzKZDm5L//zcAAA)

-2 bytes from Erik the Outgolfer

Explanation:

```
;ur♂²c
;ur       range(n+1) ([0, n])
   ♂²     square each element
     c    does the list contain the input?
```

This takes a while for large inputs - TIO will timeout.

Comment: Can't you replace `íub` with `c`?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer You're absolutely right I believe, and I have a lot of answers to update because I didn't think about that.

Comment: I actually tried to outgolf you, but then I thought the algorithm was way too similar to post, so I converted it to a golfing tip instead...

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>66</s> <s>43</s> 42 bytes

```c
f(float n){return!(sqrt(n)-(int)sqrt(n));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PctBCsIwEEDRfU8xVoQZMCKCq4h3CUnTBpKpJtNV6dWNFYLL/@BbNVpbj4FtXNzwKOLCfJme3V@SkekHHn2cjZDuAgskExhphVfey2N/cv0ZPN7uBKQhD7JkhquGrbYPmNbGByzvLMikcJ@pBemt1o/10Yylqpi@)

Thanks to TheLethalCoder for the tip!

@hvd Thanks for saving a byte!

Comment: Can you just do: `bool f(float n){return !sqrt(n)-(int)sqrt(n)>0;}` or similar? Been a while since I've used C.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder yea absolutely man. :) i would have to incluede stdbool.h though, therefore int as return type would be shorter.

Comment: There's no need for a space between `return` and `!`.

Comment: Suggest `f(n)` instead of `f(float n)` and `(n=sqrt(n))` instead of `(int)sqrt(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
{_),2f##)!!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1flPm/Ol5TxyhNWVlTUbH2f91/MxMA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, <s>53</s> <s>50</s> <s>49</s> <s>48</s> <s>49</s> 48 bytes

This should in theory work for an input of any size. Returns `True` if the given number is a square, `False` otherwise.

```python
f=lambda n,x=0:x<=n if~-(x<=n!=x*x)else f(n,x+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcrRCsIgFMbx@57iRDdaC7SJk8iHsU2Z4NxwBnbTq5sS2N35/b@zveO8@j5nI51anpMC3yVJ7ukhPVjzuaJ6HWU6J6zdrsGg8nChOG/B@ohIVwrB@PAjraSNnFVz1oIQNQjRwo2ygYmes6EOf2EMcIKgx1fY7erB2cXGYjXOespf)

#### Explanation:

```python
f=                                                # assign a name so we can call it
  lambda n,x=0:                                   # counter variable x
               x<=n                               # counter bigger than input?
                    if~-(         )               # "negate" inner condition
                         x<=n                     # counter not bigger
                            n!=x*x                # and n not square of x
                                   else f(n,x+1)  # else recurse
```

The condition is just a de-Morgan'd `if x>n or n==x**2`, i.e. we return if the counter is bigger than the input, or we found a proof for squareness.

Saved 1 byte thanks to Gábor Fekete.

Comment: Your outputs are the wrong way 'round ;)

Comment: Technically, my output is "one of two consistent truthy/falsey values". But if you deem this invalid, I can correct it at the cost of one byte.

Comment: I'll edit the question to clarify, I see now that my phrasing in the rules was open to "interpretation", although it was clearer in the intro.

Comment: @Shaggy Well, I knew that isn't what you _intended_. Anyways, I'll edit my answer to adjust.

Comment: Can you add a TIO as well?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, done.

Comment: Use `x*x` instead of `x**2`, saves 1 byte :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript on NodeJS & Chrome, 51 bytes

```
// OLD: t=n=>{i=Number.isSafeInteger;return i(n)&&i(n**.5)}

i=Number.isSafeInteger;t=n=>i(n)&&i(n**.5) 
// TestCases:
let l=console.log;l(`t(1): ${t(1)}; t(64): ${t(64)}; t(88): ${t(88)};`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYhBCsIwEEX3niILKUnBgKBSDHHvxo0XaKxjiYwTSaZuSs4eo3Tz/3vv6T4uDdG/eUPhDqWwJXuavb1MrxtE7dPVPeBMDCNEE4GnSMJLUk1Tt231XuUVAgu0Q6AUEDSG0aDsWW7VUazn32cjWB52i1f4h65bQoVselVK@QI)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. You don't need to include the `t=` in your byte count nor is input validation required for this challenge.

Comment: Also works for Firefox

Comment: @rickhitchcock does have a point - input validation should not be required!
Quote: "You need not handle inputs greater than what your chosen language can natively handle nor which would lead to floating point inaccuracies."

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 26 bytes

```powershell
!([math]::Sqrt("$args")%1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7RCoIwFAbg@z3FaczYwCBrqAhB79BlREgd82KZbpMC89nXMDPw3P3f@Q@c@vFEbUpUyrECdtC5BT/ec1uesuzQaMspy/XNUBFEwvWE7DkBPyFfh8CsblGMOZrlWM4gTT0UuTKTbCKZyHQby@S/EfCGALqhwSrv@KrxYvHqf2PnL2s0rbIelv5lVg1IGR99hc10JLJfm5LefQA)

Answer (score 2):

## MIPS, 112 bytes

```
main:li $v0,7
syscall
sqrt.d $f0,$f0
mfc1 $a0,$f0
li $v0,1
beqz $a0,t
li $a0,0
syscall
b e
t:li $a0,1
syscall
e:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky7IzP3/PzcxM88qJ1NBpcxAx5yruLI4OTEnh6u4sKhEL0VBJc1AB4i5ctOSDRVUEiEcqGJDrqTUwiqwaAlYDMgwgBuQpJDKVWIFFTaEC6da/f9vZPIfAA)

Outputs `1` if the input is square, `0` if not.

### Explanation

```
main:li $v0,7      #Start of program. Load service 7 (read input as float to $f0). 
                   #Input can be an integer, but MIPS will interpret it as a float.
syscall            #Execute.

sqrt.d  $f0,$f0    #Overwrite $f0 with its square root, stored as a double.
mfcl    $a0,$f0    #Move $f0 to $a0.
li      $v0,1      #Load service 1 (print int from $a0).
beqz    $a0,t      #Branch to label 't' if $a0 = 0. Otherwise continue.

#If input is non-square...
li      $a0,0      #Load 0 into $a0.
syscall            #Execute (print $a0).
b e                #Branch to label 'e'.

#If input is square...
t:li    $a0,1      #Start of label 't'. Load 1 into $a0.
syscall            #Execute (print $a0).

e:                 #Start of label 'e'. Used to avoid executing 't' when input isn't square.
```

A double in MIPS is 16 hexes. It shares its address with a float containing its low-order 8 hexes (`$f0` in this case). The high-order hexes are stored in the next register (`$f1`), also as a float.

```
          float             double 
$f0     0000 0000     1111 1111 0000 0000
$f1     1111 1111
```

Taking the square root of a non-square number requires the entire double in order to be stored, meaning the high and low floats are populated. The square root of a square number only needs a few hexes from the double to be stored, and it is stored specifically in its high-order hexes. This means the low float is left at `0`.

If the low float equals `0`, the input is a square number.

Comment: [you have a bit of superfluous whitespace](https://tio.run/##Ky7IzP3/PzcxM88qJ1NBpcxAx5yruLI4OTEnh6u4sKhEL0UlzUAHiLly05INVRIh7JxMkEpDrqTUwiqQWAlIBEgbwPUmKaRylVhBRA3hoqlW//8bmfwHAA)

Comment: [91?](https://tio.run/##Ky7IzP3/PzcxM88qJ1OlzEDHnKu4sjg5MSeHq7iwqEQvRSXNQAeIuXLTkg1VEiHspNTCKhC7hAuoB0gbcpVYVeQXQZgQYwxhxvz/b2T6HwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Whitespace](https://web.archive.org/web/20150618184706/http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/tutorial.php), 95 bytes

```
[S S S N
_Push_0][S N
S _Duplicate_top][T N
T   T   _Read_STDIN_as_integer][N
S S N
_Create_Label_LOOP][S N
S _Duplicate_top][S N
S _Duplicate_top][T S S N
_Multiply_top_two][S S S N
_Push_0][T  T   T   _Retrieve_input][S N
T   _Swap_top_two][T    S S T   _Subtract][S N
S _Duplicate_top][N
T   S S N
_If_0_jump_to_Label_TRUE][N
T   T   T   N
_If_negative_jump_to_Label_FALSE][S S S T   N
_Push_1][T  S S S _Add][N
S N
N
_Jump_to_Label_LOOP][N
S S S N
_Create_Label_TRUE][S S S T N
_Push_1][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer][N
N
N
_Stop_program][N
S S T   N
_Create_Label_FALSE][S S S N
_Push_0][T  N
S T _Print_as_integer]
```

Letters `S` (space), `T` (tab), and `N` (new-line) added as highlighting only.
`[..._some_action]` added as explanation only.

Outputs `1`/`0` for truthy/falsey respectively. A few bytes could be saved if something like `00`/`0` for truthy/falsey is allowed instead.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##JYxRCoBACES/x1N4iOg@EQv1FxR0fHfeijg4b9T/ur/xPsc5qjIzXAopesQhbklIGjiBgoiEA8ZabMKbBdTX9lX7NgE) (with raw spaces, tabs and new-lines only).

**Explanation in pseudo-code:**

```
Read STDIN as integer, and store it in the heap
Integer i = 0
Start LOOP:
  Integer temp = i*i - input from heap
  If(temp == 0):
    Call function TRUE
  If(temp < 0):
    Call function FALSE
  i = i + 1
  Go to next iteration of LOOP

function TRUE:
  Print 1 as integer
  Stop program
function FALSE:
  Print 0 as integer
  (implicitly stop the program with an error)
```

*Here a port of this approach in Java:*

```java
int func(int input){
  for(int i=0; /*infinite loop*/; i++){
    int m = input - i*i;
    if(m==0) return 1;
    if(m<1) return 0;
  }
}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XVBBboMwELznFaOcDCgJRFUVlfKEnnJse3AJVJvCGuF1pKrK2ykYtyU9eOWZ2d0Z7Vlf9OZ8@hiGstHW4kkTf60AK1qoBLGgdlyq6UPcOYkmFahNP3NFmmMXE9fEJBUaY7p4l4OSJHTCL2lRzPPYgGLKf6RatUWRRugrcT0jWwqP2S@fzvx1Nb2xdO6tGeOFlBdDJ7RjcnWUnvj9@RU6uEtlRaVR/geyJbi/W6LD4aZxn93CvYfef2ns1f/3OX5aqdqtcbLtxkjSsPJysn7Ai6yTcNRpIGy9DsM3)

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 55 bytes

First time posting a solution to one of my own challenges, if you'll forgive me the indulgence.

Outputs `1` for truthy or nothing for falsey.

```
listen to N
X's0
while N-X
let X be+1
if X*X is N
say 1
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in)

Comment: For a Rockstar answer, anything can be forgiven.

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 34 bytes

```
C<C-r>=sqrt(<C-r>")
<esc>:s/.\+\.0\n
:s/.\+/1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/39nGWbfIzra4sKhEA8xU0uSySS1OtrMq1teL0Y7RM4jJ44Kw9Q25/v83NPivWwYA)

Returns empty string for a square, `1` for non-square.

### Explanation

```
C<C-r>=sqrt(<C-r>")
C                   cut the input line, enter insert mode
 <C-r>=             evaluate the following math command:
       sqrt(      ) square root of
            <C-r>"  cut input line in register "

<esc>:s/.\+\.0\n/
<esc>               exit insert mode
     :s/.\+\.0\n/   remove instance of <digits>.0 
                    this removes a perfect square root.

:s/.\+/1            replace any other non-newline chars left with
                    a single 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript, 44 bytes

```js
n=>{for(i=0n;i<=n;){if(i++**2n==n)return 1}}
```

Obligatory bigger but BigInt answer.

Returns `1` if a square, or `undefined` when not a square.

+4 bytes if you want to actually get your answer today:

```js
n=>{for(i=0n;i**2n<=n;){if(i++**2n==n)return 1}}
```

Comment: @emanresuA could you elaborate on how the first one would be but not the second? because the only thing I can think of is `i` not fitting in your memory at some point, but that can happen for both

Comment: Ah, never mind, I misread it as not having a condition on the loop. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

## Knight, <s>32</s> <s>33</s> <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
;=i+1=xP;W!>0=i-i 1|-^i 2xQ1Q0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVldU9tKEn22f8XgFLbGlhNJsFW3MDJFciFFLYEEks0D@AYhyzC1suyVZAgL7F/Pdvd8aGSb7Gb38mBZM6d7us/0dPeYuH8Txz9eiSxOF@NktyjHYvb6dti0R1JxXRuKy4d5sgTKRXZTGyrFVGLGyURkCUtTls6yG/pomtHPJ18@ML96Pf98xoLq9W/7Z2y7ej08ecd@q17PvjC/Ah8en1vYky/HFvTLyYf98786BWcOfrTZv/y/cDO7fw7Lysn4NspZl1cCNgpsNSqGQ7ZdzZ0cfMXJDCbJoyeG33d3lzC4DGHQTcCkKUdgDfP29PSYQPixR07uoG@WIWfvJQDkLVvvonSRcH6RjXizSX7ArlyMwrPWwemh82MQip4ffv84@Lox9ELRF8x/6v8hWPD9k//J@8EB1BpIuS4IJtGUhahh0GzCMvMoLxKHs8dmQ2QlE4NmA0ZpSZd1J4sshhESjuG9nM7dYp5dBKPw0XO9Z9DREKCO8PD0cODNG1Qv5uz@VpRJMY/ipNmA72niwDiIO9IMl7Uuy8vscnKZs8fni5HDd161OJnSEBPmGGtD1nnV4Uyq0KMbMHqZwXCvJ0fAzkaSFok98CzNiW@T@O9sMstZtpheJ3mh7GGOKMbiRpRaK6yO7viu8Ug@u8z3WI91leW9Hmd91vE6sARaKjjLk3KRZ0wHiRSjOBks23AX5SK6ThNtBRiRzu6T3IlhPW0Ie3pi2riY3mIi4luHK3rEGtdF6LuwR6EZXrIOj50KT4Bk48XcwS1litM@g7dVg2USKKQ2acZlp1PZ1OrITQNh8MAYxUAJJA34DpbNo6Jk5W0CyqK8BLDagK5mFDc05uiJNtY6Sy8aC58@p41uVGSQ@Ri6pZhlYDZGrDcC02LNSLGYz5FwrqNKj9j02/EHtFtkow4dyvMM4hgSGEauslyy8rljTrkcOMQBTGY7mMTQTB1klP@kqw7ajaZGaTqLnW3P9Tk6iMPGCXIwW6RplD/Yjlb7c2Ztz8eOsYwWVPKLbEmalvBxCZUU1nm6f/D23dWnjePfTy2HbbXXYq3eYFXvRk3x@6PzFzSWSU4qo2zM/rGI9CuqvbOX2FpdQhLwvmO4OFrDBQlv14XrmGdKlfkiwx0aqCTcLWeFo3MlHQAI7VLEjGavF5OLYHuk7JAb3ab0YAwo5nCsyokDUPB/M03HLZ13qAi5qGRZARwKo0CWN7l@DbfL/K26n@g8xuIea5X5ImlBDJpxDEkYn0SQQXCihZHVqkhAP9F3VYeIjm9vZ7MUZq7rDLzoa@XWzxzq/rpHtpnXK2amaGP2p9oIQVvO0tSxTXWZ50KF@B9MzlZMxir8Yf/jiYu1WAYavB5d@J7nQTiBK/Cq3wrxz@RbyfAxsGLU8hYZgDcXPwL63Ap9XdIxw2FVxwd9BvKxBYDDo@ODLptAchw0TGir9TANx9HcTZOMOgCLK90mSc7g3L1ExrIg1iYsbVhwHEG9BNTiXeJiAEVF4KTJG/F0vrQDRJIYVSkEaRIjXKa4F2V863SBmZWuCjhi6i/GOtXZ7@wwXEUCQiQU@zLIwrxNTin1qjOshSwfUBWuENR@ljmWLupAL0b8sQozaKAot8uFz2Dhuu4cMp7D2973Cf5VyI@ABK2So5ukTKF5dNq0l23cISyRY5HxgZg4Du0nNgTxbY62uBCnnMttDr3BWlvhwakNkOsdyPVk54jZQBEy0PYiSSp3Vla@rfyReDPzrppBSZtig7kCDEYDxF84n82TzLEWdlt5i1oFsCqcykoJ8RgG3vZvNK6aC0d2JBMwfYxOQQsHIetifwdw6B3oDdeApXV4OTDIeiG1QnhiAckV3aCH1iKqUUM3ZIHds1Q0Vp58Ak@S79DG4Wlf8XOjtut0R9jATLYCPF4JD1glrfNiwX/v7Kg@cU0gm8ynKlDrhNpiB2sQ10VoONzmVWO5kg616Dk1h85mgYL1w7AqDHRC62OvC5mUtyqonsDykkSZUvtSCVM1y94BlVsUC6cVC3gw5MUHSZP7WaOOtdt0ser3ETqSbe4ltdsNbdbm624B9jjwxpk@arll/qIs9O6bmJC9njSoZwyiPAn5ElMyhpa1PbKbbtR3W95SEQ19P9OxFMg9x/6XDoPcAELhMJ7yUHsZ8PWhGkelfqiu0@9VNHH9HXVx6EZdepYqRyi/@ivRaUU7tup1e6VQt9qdNSwsl@c1PHRXeJD7uo6F6RrXuoQJbSUkADXIoQwZdi7hkoegQb9P@hRRVDKXN1oyWtZO/5ufEvNmPTGbPxXaXC/0B7FZc0heHWgssL0cKNol6yHr@4ZlwgL1Ppyzvg9nzLfBwS@idyE91rBhiFBad0ePeJpyIjoYeorrgFO70g2J/@bygaBJcgXuCJRgscTAd7wy3CZ50ilYNoMeWqSlyNh99AC8sfEM7qRlcpPkIDOfZUlWighvEXCSZ@w@YbfRXQJApQjhJZtG2QLC5@E1jqJ318g4UEFMFIu0xB8NaHGT8DSkb2P0kkuU2XIGsqQe9b2M9F42xMB2ayiP7udRirXxAbzOxmkyZleV2VdGyyN@k42ZtUjlzBCV9fv6nRO8oaBdy/Rnkwd3KViXCh8mvVpeDOtZcY/Zh3/XPgYouqN@f2szCdhjtUaRBl1mZUPU4UlJXXIDWQcQuxFCtbG6oCEcSgyt2Xi2w6bJNJ5jmGVseLX3/7oy/BNcGWpXNtb4EipflCt7L7MvV11jMk7vsRogMIhAF9CNdXZWL8Y9nXlsBca8dpX@0Jd1tWHPllSpxMg//TfyKgdZaoz8oLNjo2tt7jI2rLJuffqXLzK6t61uMohr1G4zJhUSBjWOwpq0lSZRAhG9nhGTJn8F9@SvXnajWfOO2b2LEjuqd@0IteT3gp0ti5b38soQWh1Wzy5Aq3ekTF08XHMWtmoN7bkkeknpYLnkBetK3hY3fUBgpLdp8D80RGgYPnErYtP8m3bI7o0C8BBX7fnYJFGDIONfTtKDED11EmD1cTKJIEmCZ7rDFBlMijH9iBTFJZSpzmbcwZ4TRzh74RaLykwNhG5Q/ZAwjUSGzSqL8pvYJaXdLny/4/hzFd0v8d85jkfW1K9xzz/8fwM)

Takes input from standard in, outputs by error code (1 if input is square, 0 otherwise).

Expanded code:

```
;=i +1 (=x PROMPT)
;WHILE !> 0(=i -i 1)
  | (-(^i 2) x)
    QUIT 1
QUIT 0
```

---

+1 bytes from @Jonah because I somehow didn't notice this failed on input `1`
-2 bytes from @Jonah by using short circuit evaluation of `|` instead of `IF`

Comment: I think `Q?0x` can just be `Q0` because if you get there we know it's not square.

Comment: @Jonah if the input is 0, then the while loop will never run, so it will go straight to the "false" case -- I need to check for that.

Comment: I see.  Looks like current answer fails for 1.

Comment: -2 with `;=i+1=xP;W!>0=i-i 1|-^i 2xQ1Q0`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

```
/^R2h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2F%5ER2h&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=0%0A1%0A64%0A88&debug=0)

Comment: An alternative 5-byte solution that doesn't work for larger numbers (e.g. `2**127 - 1`) would be `sI@Q2`, but I have to admit that I am quite fond of your right map answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), <s>16</s> 18 bytes

```
[:|~b/a=a|_Xq}?b=0
```

*Added two bytes for 0-case*

This runs through `i = 1 ... n` to see if `n / i == i`. Prints `1` if such an `i` is found, prints `-1` for `N=0` and `0` in all other cases. Both `1` and `-1` are considered truthy in QBasic (`-1` being the actual value for true, but `IF (n)` only is false on `n=0`).

Comment: Can you add a TIO (or equivalent)?

Comment: @Shaggy unfortunately not. My attempts to have QBasic / QBIC / DosBox run on a webpage have been unfruitful, to put it mildly... I've considered running it from CGI, but QBasic is just too powerful to do that, that's asking for exploits... I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: I just wanted to check if it returns `true` for `0`.

Comment: @Shaggy it would print 0 for N=0. It never enters the FOR loop and jumps straight to the last statement. I'll fix that

Answer (score 1):

## J, 8 bytes

```
(=~<.)%:
```

Explanation:

- `%:` square root
- `=~` is the argument equal to itself
- `<.` floor of
- `=~<.` a J hook, which modifies the right argument by applying `<.`
- so, "is the floor of the square root equal to itself?"

Note: If we want to save the above to a variable as a verb, we must do, eg:

```
issq=.(=~<.)@%:
```

Comment: Could you add a [TIO](https://tio.run/) (or equivalent) to this, please?

Comment: I tried it, but it's not producing any output.  Not sure if the J interpreter is down or if I'm missing something, but if you paste the following test into jconsole: `(=~<.)%: 1 4 9 16 ,: 2 3 7 21` it will return a table with a row of `1`s on top of a row of `0`s, as expected.  I tried putting the same into the "Code" section of TIO and then hitting run, but I get no output.

Answer (score 1):

## C, 33 bytes

```
#define f(x)sqrt(x)==(int)sqrt(x)
```

Takes an integer `x`. Checks if the square root of `x` is the square root of `x` rounded to an integer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@r5yZl5xTmpKqYJObWJKhl2H3XzklNS0zL1UhTaNCs7iwqARI2dpqZOaVwHj/cxMz8zQ0qwuKgIJpGkqqKUo6aRpmJpqa1rX/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
=MOD(A1^0.5,1)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

## **Python 3,** <s>39</s> 38 Bytes

```
lambda n:n in(i*i for i in range(n+1))
```

@mathmandan I had the same idea, and this implementation is 1 byte shorter. I wanted to comment on your post but do not yet have 50 reputation. I hope you see this!

This is just brute force, and I did not get it to complete  `2147483647` in a 
 reasonable amount of time.

Thanks @DJMcMayhem for suggesting i remove the space after `in`

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk8hM08jUytTIS2/SCETyFEoSsxLT9XI0zbU1PxfUJSZV6KRpgFkc8HYRkhsYyS2JbIaFA2mSBwzEySOhQXQDgA)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Just FYI, you could remove a space after `in`

Comment: Could you add a [TIO](https://tio.run/) or equivalent, please?

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 8 bytes

```
issquare
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmCr8D@zuLiwNLEo9X9afpFGHlDEUEfB0MBAR6GgKDOvRCNPR0FJQddOQUlHIU0jT1NT8z8A)

Answer (score 1):

### Pyke, 3 bytes

```
,$P
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%2C%24P&input=3)

```
,   -   sqrt(input)
 $  -  float(^)
  P - is_int(^)
```

This could be two bytes (and is in older versions) if Pyke didn't helpfully automatically cast the results of sqrt to an integer if it's a square number.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 8 bytes

```
¬﹪ＸＮ·⁵¦¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///Qmvc7V73fs@P9nnWHtj9q3Hpo2aGd//@b/NfN/G/43/K/oel/I4P/uvn/dcHwPwA)

#### Explanation

```
¬           Not
 ﹪      ¦¹ Modulo 1
   Ｘ  ·⁵   To the power of .5
     Ｎ     Next input as number,
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
t.ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/xOXw@kcNuw53/P9vyQUA)

<s>Longer than @Erik's but just wanted to give it a shot.</s>

Now shorter than Erik's but fails for large numbers...

## Explanation

```
t            # square roots the input
 .ï          # checks if number on stack is an int
             # implicit output of result (0 or 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 30 bytes

```
(defun g(x)(=(mod(sqrt x)1)0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JLC74/18jJTWtNE8hXaNCU8NWIzc/RaO4sKhEoULTUNNAU/O/RkFRZl6Jgka6gpkJkAsA)

or, with the same length,

```
(defun g(x)(integerp(sqrt x)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 22+3 = 25 bytes

```
01-\:*=n;
(?!\1+::*{:}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38BQN8ZKyzbPmkvDXjHGUNvKSqvaqvb///@6ZQqGZgA)

Input is expected on the stack at program start, so +3 bytes for the `-v` flag.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 16 bytes

```
->n{n**0.5%1==0}
```

Trivial solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp), 67 bytes

```
(load library
(d S(q((n)(contains?(map(q((x)(* x x)))(c 0(1to n)))n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYo5DoAgEEV7T/HLP1ZYWHsITzAuMSQ4KFLA6VHLt2RvNfjnao0h6obgl6Spdtww8yZNuEbL6u2ZeOr1uyLsUVBEvgjHIUfYB9b@AzOY1I4dDqMTaS8)

Generates a list of numbers from 0 through `n`, maps a lambda function that squares each one, and checks if `n` is in the resulting list of squares. Wildly inefficient, of course.

---

Here's a 77-byte solution that doesn't use the library and runs an order of magnitude faster:

```
(d _(q((x n s)(i(e n s)1(i(l n s)0(_(a x 1)n(a s(a x(a x 1
(d S(q((n)(_ 0 n 0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYuxDYQwEARzqthwLzMBlbgA6xAIWfLfg/0BVO8/INpZaeaX7Sq57b1zQeJBnjA0Yeb6wOhUHgpMVJwYxXzbze8fPI13asKE4HLoLF9dUPJctV4y8KM7IljVttWVKYj0Pw)

This one uses a helper function `_` which tracks a counter `x` and its square `s`. At each level of recursion, we return success if `s` equals `n` and failure if `s` is greater than `n`; otherwise, if `s` is still less than `n`, we recurse, incrementing `x` and calculating the next `s` by the formula `(x+1)^2 = x^2 + x + x + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 12 bytes

```julia
n->√n%1==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@19s@z9P1@5Rx6w8VUNbW4P/BUWZeSU5eRrFehqGVkYGmpr/AQ)

Pretty straightforward, having the Unicode `√` for square-root saves a few bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-¡E`, 2 bytes

```
¬d
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=rGQ=&input=NjQKCgotoUU=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>27</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

saved bytes by simplifying order of operation and comparing roots instead of squared value

```python
lambda n:n**.5//1==n**.5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKk9LS89UX9/Q1hbM@l9QlJlXohGdppGtqZCWX6SQrZCZpxBtoGOoY2aiY6RjYaFjZGhibmJhbGZiHhur@R8A)

Comment: Hello and welcome to PPCG. I think you should specify that you are using Python 3. Furthermore, is `%1==0` not shorter and accomplishes the same?

Comment: @JonathanFrech This works in 2 and 3.  And yes, %1==0 is shorter and wins.  Is there an easy way to filter past answers by language of implementation so I can quickly see what other users have already submitted?

Comment: It only works in some newer Python 2 versions.

Comment: @JonathanFrech Ah.  I don't have access to old versions of python 2.  Any site like TIO that tests all versions?

Comment: Explicit untrue division was [introduced in Python 2.2](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.2.html?highlight=division#pep-238-changing-the-division-operator); no, unfortunately I do not know of any online Python version history interpreter site.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 61 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
T	OUTPUT =EQ(X * X,N) 1
	X =LT(X,N) X + 1	:S(T)
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hCuE0z80BMhQsHUN1IhQ0FKI0PHTVDDk4oxQsPUJ0QDzIhS0FQw5rYI1QjS5XP1c/v@3sAAA)

Increment `X` until either `X ^ 2` is equal to `N` in which case the program outputs `1` or until `X > N` in which case the program outputs nothing.

Answer (score 1):

## k4, <s>12</s> 9 bytes

```
 x=_x:sqrt
```

with num(s) to be checked passed right-side, e.g.

```
 x=_x:sqrt 36 35 25
101b
```

get square root and check if the it is equal to the square root cast to int. if not a square number, the square root will have a decimal place and the cast will cut the decimal off

edit: -3 thanks to ngn :)

---

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 8 bytes

```
x=`i$x:%
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v8I2IVOlwkrV0Oz/fwA)

Same logic but in oK, an implementation of k6 (no online k4 interpreter that i'm aware of). Test like:

```
 x=`i$x:% 16 24 81
1 0 1
```

Comment: Could you add a [TIO](http://tio.run/) (or equivalent)? From your explanation, it sounds like you may have posted this to the wrong challenge.

Comment: @Shaggy, apologies... i did. deleting

Comment: @Shaggy corrected

Comment: Thanks. Could you add a link to somewhere we can test it, though?

Comment: @Shaggy i have added a solution in oK which can be tested at TIO!

Comment: `"i"$` -> `_`­­

Comment: @ngn updated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 42 bytes

```
->>,[[-<<<+>>>]<<++[[-<]<+>>>]<<<[<]>>>]<.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9f185OJzpa18bGRtvOzi4WSGmDuLEwrk20TSyYpff/vwMA)

Outputs the NUL byte for square numbers and SOH for non-squares. Uses the property that square numbers are the cumulative sum of odd numbers, i.e. 1, 1+3, 1+3+5 etc.

There might be a better way of arranging the cells so as to reduce the number of pointer movements and save bytes.

Comment: Just tested this quickly on my phone and it seems to be giving different outputs for inputs of `1` & `64`.

Comment: @Shaggy On TIO it is using input as a character code, so 1 (49) will be square but 64 (54) won't be. `@` and SOH both output the NUL byte for me. You can use an interpreter like [copy.sh](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=LT4-LFtbLTw8PCs-Pj5dPDwrK1tbLTxdPCs-Pj5dPDw8WzxdPj4-XTwu) to test actual numbers more easily

Comment: I'm using the interpreter from [copy.sh](https://copy.sh/brainfuck/?c=LT4-LFtbLTw8PCs-Pj5dPDwrK1tbLTxdPCs-Pj5dPDw8WzxdPj4-XTwu) which does allow input as a number. I could have sworn there was an answer under standard IO that allowed numerical input as byte code, but I can't find it. I guess I'll add it and see if it passes community consensus

Comment: Ah, [here it is](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4719/76162). I wonder why it isn't under standard IO

Comment: Ah-ha! I *vaguely* remembered seeing something about that on Meta, but I was looking for it in the standard I/O question. Looks like a strong enough consensus to me so I'll allow it, even if I don't necessarily agree with it. That goes for your solution, too, @KrzysztofSzewczyk.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 92 bytes

```
(({})){{}([(({}[({})({}())])[(())])](<>)){({}())<>}{}{((<{}>))<>{}}{}<>{}}{}({()(<{}>)}{}<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCoBADEM/xiUZBN1Lf@S4QQdBFAfX0G8/e@pQ0rykXe9lv8btXI42QAZFUVS6zMFQBBsSklKg9LV0mwOyMkmXCvOsfNQ87wSYwrvLJ4pfIPALXsbW5ml@AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 31 bytes

```forth
: f dup s>f fsqrt f>s dup * = ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hU9LDoIwEN33FBOWGoiFplAJnMQNSgdIiGBbzo/TRhY1Jm7mfeblTQYX48Z0QA/7fgWEflvBtghoX8YBtjY4J2igpr3T1jEIVkaYJdC0kBBDmNBLZzadgJ6t9go7ImSO@kmZh6Fxg94s6wFDZ@7doFnN2CWU08JXMB4pKSJZVYcMB1jORSmqQooy9kWuhJJlruRXd8FhtuOEDvj589/fAJGo/HcojUL7Gw)

The input is a positive signed single-cell integer (`0 <= n < 2^63` for 64-bit systems). To support full unsigned integer range, do `0 d>f` instead of `s>f`.

Using floats turns out to be shorter than a loop.

#### How it works

```forth
: f ( n -- f )  \ Takes a positive signed int and gives whether it's a square or not
  dup           \ Duplicate n
  s>f fsqrt f>s \ Move to floating-point stack, take sqrt and move back (truncate)
  dup * =       \ Square the result and compare with n
;
```

gforth's comparison operators give -1 for true, 0 for false.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Å²
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cOuhTf//m5kAAA)

A built-in function that checks if a number is a perfect square.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
∆²
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%88%86%C2%B2&inputs=4&header=&footer=)

Builtin.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 6 bytes

```
Đ0⇹Ř²∈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yASDR@07j844tOlRR8f//4ZmAA)

```
Đ                implicit input; Đuplicate
 0               push 0
  ⇹              swap top two items on stack
   Ř²            Řangify, square
     ∈           is input in list of squares?; implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/), 22 bytes

```
f(x)=0^{mod(x^{.5},1)}
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8nqbfevycz)

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 18 bytes

```arturo
$=>[=floor<=sqrt&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?6BBa9c)

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 5 bytes

```
==^^$-2~@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWK21t4-JUdI3qHCB8qPCC9QZchlxmJlwWFlxGhibmJhBhAA)

```
==^^$-2~@
==        Equals
  ^    ~   square
   ^ -2     square root
    $        input
        @  input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 22 bytes

```powershell
[math]::sqrt($a)%1-eq0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfmvkqhgq2Bm8j86N7EkI9bKqriwqERDJVFT1VA3tdDg/38A)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 33 bytes

```
 g = lambda x: (x**.5).is_integer()
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! There seems to be a bit of unnecessary whitespace in your entry, such as after the colon, and also anonymous lambdas are valid submissions, meaning you can omit the `g=` from the start. Also I believe `%1!=0` is shorter than `.is_integer()`

Comment: @Mayube You probably meant `==0`?

Comment: @MartinEnder I did, yes

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 25 bytes

```python
lambda n:int(n**.5)**2==n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjOvRCNPS0vPVFNLy8jWNu9/QRFQSCFNw0CTC8Y0RDCNEExjJAXIio2QlBuaWSJpMDbW/A8A)

Answer (score 0):

## C++, 43 bytes

```
bool c(int n){int t=sqrt(n);return t*t==n;}
```

New version: https://repl.it/repls/CompatibleJumpyCoordinates

If your number is perfect square then it will return 1, otherwise it will return 0;

Old version: https://repl.it/repls/WateryTroubledProjects (not valid because it is the snippet only by  @Jonathan Frech)

If your number is perfect square then it will be exited with status 1, otherwise it will not exist;

Comment: Note that in its current form, this answer would be regarded as a snippet, which is not allowed. Please fix your answer to be of a valid form, i.e. a full program or function.

Comment: @JonathanFrech, thank you for your comment, can I add only the function like my answer above?

Comment: Yes, in its current form your answer appears to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

## BRASCA, 8 bytes

```
ig:s2^=n
```

[Try it!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=ig%3As2%5E%3Dn&stdin=64)

### Explanation

```
ig          - Turn input into digits, and concatenate
  :s2^      - Dupe original number, sqrt it, then square it
      =n    - Are the original and the modified number the same? Print the result (0 or 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
à▲⌐°
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=851ea9f8&i=0%0A1%0A64%0A88%0A2147483647&m=2)

This is PackedStax, which unpacks to the following 5 bytes:

```
|Q1%!
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%7CQ1%25%21&i=0%0A1%0A64%0A88%0A2147483647&m=2)

```
|Q    # input sqrt
  1%  # modulo 1
    ! # logically negated
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal 3](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal/tree/version-3), 3 bytes

```
√ᵞ⌊
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.github.io/latest.html#WyIiLCIiLCLiiJrhtZ7ijIoiLCIiLCIiLCIzLjQuMiJd)

No built ins, checks if the square root is the same after flooring it.