# Approx how many search results

Tags: code-golf, parsing, internet

When one performs a search query using [Google](https://www.google.com), one of the first things you see is an approximation of how many results were found. Today, you'll be simulating this in as few bytes as possible.

### Input

A short string of length at most 10 with characters from a-z.

### Output

The approx count that Google reports for the number of hits.

### Test Cases

```
query string -> approximate number of results 
fish -> 2340000000
quantock -> 1390000
codegolf -> 891000
google -> 9340000000
e -> 22500000000
bzoea -> 34700
zoea -> 529000
```

### Extra Clarifications

You may use any regional Google you like.

You can either scrape the page resulting from the search query, or interface with Google APIs.

Search queries are usually in the format `https://www.google.com/query?q=<query>`

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Oh no! A downvote :( How come?

Comment: Is the idea of the challenge to actually query Google and return the exact value it gives? Not sure how you could estimate it.

Comment: @xnor Yes. It's a simply query and parse challenge because Google gives you the number explicitly.

Comment: I don't see why this is being close voted, it seems clear enough to me.

Comment: Can we use Google's API or a third party tool rather than directly interacting with google.com?

Comment: @xnor  Yes absolutely.

Comment: I assume we can output the amount in the same format as Google itself (so with dot as thousand separators), or should we output as an unformatted integer?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the same format is fine

Comment: [Very similar challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/25319/64121) that required to compare two result counts. But due to some [changes at Google](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/217898/approx-how-many-search-results#comment508129_217901) most of the answers are now broken.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>158</s> <s>137</s> 131 bytes

Using [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) module and a doctored User-Agent header. Still looking for a shorter functioning UA header.

```python
lambda q:get(f'http://goo.gl/search/{q}',headers={'User-Agent':'Firefox/8'}).text.split('out ')[1].split()[0]
from requests import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZRLj5swEMfP9aew9lCHyuGRF7s0ibSHXWkP7V62p21U8RjAKtjENtukUT57akhQqqoNlTISlj2e8Q/w/Kfa6lzw8SFdfD0UYRklIV4HGehBSnKtq8BxMiHsrHAUhDLOnd16T2gOYQJSLXbkiwI5vM@AaxKQRyYhFRvnluwtW8NG26oqmB4QUWtMrFdvdXJYr@4KpVKUWMK6BqUVZmUlpP5waL01Z1obt12K@PtpC38yc4RMuNx@y3VZ4AXeoXckZSonASbzhL1hlixuJKi60EOlQ61ulvdRAx/RietS9/jgY4SacxHJJR649szFCmLBE2W955GqPs6ddm/umENPI6EGtq5Drs179AI9Ovb/AfNnl2AtJhYJZKJIezG3s@nfISO/F2LuNSug/0tcOvIv/LvppJfUDxl51Btdgri9kOingLAXNJ7Qu6sq4L8o/ti7stBi8caSoXfXj6Le9OrK3iNkJG8EdeoAtSwo7kT@WXAIWvUNGk0vzgq0mz5hYjuZO0bjQ29FMSGWhZCW2wBhYz9yVgB@kTUc141pkKUBMl7Vph@c3V1OZ5VkvGlGuyZhj4dLvEsHzdzak3MabGKoNH7iCWwepBTyj0NCpdAp5uH58beIZufQtBDUSRt14kNHgSBAbWmhduju5Rc)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the challenge. You need to be able to somehow input a string and return a number for starters.

Comment: Well, thanks for that. How do I do those things? I'm still finding my way around here. A string of digits is a number. And how on earth to test it on Try it online since it won't permit outgoing requests? Still figuring that bit out too.

Comment: @Noodle9: I've wrapped it in a function that takes the search term and returns a number. Is that OK with you?

Comment: Sure that's better, but you're returning a string not a number. Also you can put the `import` on the second line and remove the `f=` from your byte count (by having a `f=\\` in the line above so you can still call your function for testing).

Comment: @Noodle9: I don't think that the output type is specified. The challenge just says to output the approx count that Google reports for the number of hits. It doesn't state that the output must be a number. A string of digits can be considered a number for purpose.

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't realise that. You can put your code in TIO like [this](https://tio.run/##Nci7DoIwFADQ3a/odmmCrcbFkBDj4h84oUOFS1sD9HVJMIRvr4tuJ8d/yLjplPv6kQc1vjrFQgUg3s5ORRQaqejBEPlKSu2cHlC0bpQJVWzNJdRr2KA0qDqMqV7hnjDurxonggpuNmLvFnmGjQvChUTyg6UC3EwMeHN8/oI3hz@hBM53dvQuEosYZkyUmEos5vwF). And then use the code-golf link to simply copy/paste it into your answer. Don't think it'll run properly there by it's does the formatting and byte count for you and makes it easier to look at your code.

Comment: @Noodle9 no worries. Thanks for the example. I didn't think of putting the import after the lamda def, that's pretty sneaky. It's going to take a while to adopt poor and bizarre programming practices.

Comment: What's the advantage of putting the import on the second line?

Comment: @Anush:  It means that you can remove the assignment of the lambda expression to a variable name from the code. Instead you add `f=\ ` to the header section on TIO. It seems like cheating to me. but it lets you save a whopping 2 bytes.

Comment: Some saves with the text extraction and import: ```lambda q:get(f'http://google.com/search?q={q}',headers={'User-Agent':'Firefox/8'}).text.split()[2].replace(',','')
from requests import*```. Though it looks like you don't have to do the comma removal based on the challenge comments.

Comment: @xnor: thanks for those hints. I also removed the comma removal as per the challenge comment.

Comment: Google.com is longer than some of the alternatives

Comment: Thanks @Anush I'll try that out.

Comment: `Firefox/8` is no longer a valid User-Agent

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + curl + grep, 61

```bash
curl -LA Firefox/8 goo.gl/search?$1|grep -Po "bout \K[0-9,]*"
```

This will output `curl`'s progress indicator to stderr.  If you want to suppress that, change the `-LA` to `-sLA`.

Comment: Why Google.com and not Google.de for example?

Comment: @Anush yes that helps.  `goo.gl/search?` is even better!

Comment: `Firefox/8` is no longer a valid User-Agent

Answer (score 3):

## Applescript, 389

This is perhaps the most inefficient golfing language, but it is still fun to golf in:

```applescript
open location"http://goo.gl/search?"&(display dialog""default answer"")'s text returned
repeat with l in{"a","c"}
delay 2
tell application"System Events"to keystroke l using command down
end
delay 1
set d to the clipboard
set Applescript's«class txdl»to" "
set c to d's text items
set p to""
repeat with w in c
considering case
if p contains"About"then display alert w
end
set p to w
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>64</s> <s>61</s> <s>56</s> 75 bytes

```powershell
iwr goo.gl/search?$args -User Firefox/8|sls '(?<=">About )[\d,]*'|% M*|% V*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVVrU9pAFP2eX3GHogEbJEQeOgTU2nHGD46t9PHBOp08LiE17IbdjY@iv51uXggdiCAzMMk9u/cc9t57NqQPyPgIg2BWHkIPpjP/gYFH6b4X1DlazBkdly3mcah958jg3Gc4pI/1w2cecFArx2av1D@1aSSgevPL1W731OcduNyTPz/2Zi@K8gEuqXMHQ8pAjBBCKh8s4s4D3y6ulPJYLkH3GnlICUcudZxMFQXkR12WknF9bBqqXKSaPgkl870VRNgr7U4iKrqZmqZR6puufw@@2ysx5FEgalxYgudyGy1Nb@uaridfSJdwk1Cb9aGi77fawNGhxOXVXWLzsGvWE8ysy6x9k4cWmVPBMwxGPhPUd816gqjdVfLXa99Q85GxXnCz9bbgTwmNDvZTrPpz5HlQgwGNiHsW0KhY/NDnoxXK4/Absg2tqRecdFvf4qRjOmRjJIVaJ5FFhGyqVG@SpvBctYPOGnGdwjZYze5QFz0aDDdkP2y3VnMbne255ZsX4Kb/W9eMTtEMNLcXsCm30dAaRhG3vj23/ZeitSH/QVM7ekc3FrBvQd45aLxrFnJ2aazDiDjCpwQuyD29w9pl4qE/0b7GSYRcKNNEY2gxa1wpR8yvJu83XwZnERd0fGX/QUfcnkzhjBKBREjl/xvxTbzv9kVJfLx2TpmDIKhU7eLQJ5gYuB35gfAJWIFvcZC3hzJAUTvN39bJy9IpyklFUbSKuuDsGqjL5qxW4xWL8KsPpljiTRJYcpoUmltBvC@f8xSaz6mEsiFMgWyI4h1LE5KiCbDcvpnCpAMkmPZWGsxjWcllUKnK@2IH0vqU5Wmwp4FgPvE0KONjKKuCblyM3@kVWE6bREZ25RW9uH5dQQeR4yCPr9F8bw0nr7m7cJ1nzPAufH3NGocXSECWf/YP)

The correct solution is `parseHtml` method and `xPath` query `div[@id="result-stats"]` of course. But we are in CodeGolf! So let's look for a shorter code :)

The CodeGolf solution is based on the following:

- the search string contains chars `"` and `>`
- this chars are regular for `regex` and special for `Html`
- any Html document should to escape this chars in `value` attributes and in the inner text - `&quot;` and `&lt;`
- so we can found the string `">About`  only in a Raw content of a Html page.

---

Less golfed:

```powershell
Invoke-WebRequest goo.gl/search?$args -UserAgent Firefox/8|
    Select-String '(?<=">About )[\d,]*'|% Matches|% Value
```

The script assumes the English locale is default.

The script returns a string same format as Google itself, So comma as thousand separators is fine. See comment from author `Anush`.

`iwr` is the alias for [Invoke-WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest). `M*` is shortcut for the `Matches` method and `V*` is shortcut for the `Value` method.

---

- Thanks @MarcMush for the brilliant question!
- Thanks to [mhawke](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/217924/80745) for `Mock for TIO` idea.

Comment: does it still work for the search term `bout` ?

Comment: brilliant question! search term `bout` will be processed correctly. but here's the term `bout 42`! I need time to think. Thanks again!

Comment: `Firefox/8` is no longer a valid User-Agent

Comment: Thanks. Let it be. Let it be. There will be an answer, let it be.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](//golang.org), 260 bytes

Most answers on this page are now wrong, as Google no longer accepts
`Firefox/8` as a valid User-Agent:

```go
package main
import(."io"
."net/http"
."regexp")
func main(){e,_:=NewRequest("GET","http://goo.gl/search?codegolf",nil)
e.Header.Set("User-Agent","Firefox/51")
s,_:=new(Client).Do(e)
b,_:=ReadAll(s.Body)
print(string(MustCompile(`About \S+ results`).Find(b)))}
```

Comment: How is 51 different from 8?

Comment: @Anush Google enforce higher version now

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>25</s> <s>26</s> 29 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
’Š¹.ŒŒ/€±?q=ÿ’žZì.w”€«”¡1è#1è
```

+1 byte as bug-fix if the input is `about`.
+3 bytes, because it apparently doesn't work without the `www.`

Outputs the result in the same format as on the Google page itself (so with dots for thousand separators). If it should be returned as an integer, an additional trailing `þ` can be added to the program.

Builtin `.w` (read data from an URL) is disabled on TIO, so the TIO's are split into two parts:

Creating the Google search URL based on the input:

```
’Š¹.ŒŒ/€±?q=ÿ’žZì
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcPMowsO7dQ7OunoJP1HTWsObbQvtD28HyS8L@rwmv//0zKLMwA)

Get the amount of results from the Google page:

```
”€«”¡1è#1è
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##1TvZcqPIlu/1FTirwwVthEHyCsYOeaty2a7NS7na7fFNyJSEjAQFaLOsiIn5j3mYt4mY@Yo7f3J/pOecBCS02F01MffGTHRbQObJs@VZEyqIqePxP/742z//69/@5T//@h9w/eu/Gf/176/h748/CCGvdpZY4CaDkEuNpOXv7uCv5CW8FbtByG1CxAMC2KSRJKG5uhq7Dd6iWhDVVy84jdzGFx53/CT@ROucSD5t123C26UPZwTQccp2d1o8oZLboFHME5tcXR6Xtkg@GrQT3obRIPLqXptIbdoCUhGv8SjiEdmVNE2TXNuVvHac0LbLg5r08PS01NISHieyq@y5Zpv3pAfZVRuK5SzZ7vKyPA2@59iuKcOP6syggUESOE3uJsS2UUoYdpaXHc3bc7SGrJgXSeS167KjqH5K0FHSVdQJOonptbvU99jrxwM/iDsRfySK6tgpPw7woygq1RogjT1NGUmA6HESddwkiGzbBia1ukmQh3sQPYjMC1rjV5FPlFHEk07UXtJH1kjRXOr7ctLwYsWSa522m3hBW1aGr7o0kmo2Tjw9xdyvWUJzgjZZjcVG7X23a17cWKat0Ir7cVSzq2f89EGvsJvrjyfs@7ej@6T1tbK/fvWg8/vNZO1b9Nk0NgyjUt6ubG5tbW@lS4NO5HLbb7di8Zw4LbvrsXSO2jfipsuZXaaNq9Ojnvd5@1P02ya971Qb1@9K3z@fvvu6fnN4//nzffUqqFaCo4P9q8/7n8Em4pC2JdencWyTd8fbpz5s5HvGYodIcTLw0Qi5V28kwFXYt3oeSxriFpd261ItcDtg8ghXo34M5tj1eM8J@jbRJV0qr8H/ABrSpCExm5wbumRsaOv@RmlNWy@J3@724/m6VNYbxho1JEPSxX9GybhenzyX4Pnd1LNkdKcXSMZjywB8UhkAK1IlQ1MpVa7XtLVqWQNe4C@FXcOnhrGulWcmymWc68KMQcuIDP5SRNkTSLOK4sAFFIC/oMHda4/xIN5ZpTDAvO7uDvzkam2wxCm10KthLR2PwoqSUF8JDZ78wwwnbgTh/9By9t9lllP/x1tO2dAM2B5ta7ta0fSyJH6yrd/StmFvGqV1bcstaVsG2oe2vqVVcNfA3ra2zza18rq0oW1UAMW2ZOja9hYFFBuS@NGz/9a0Stlf1za3JUCF8@uS@JnMarrhb2n6dmlLM1ygUUI620CusgYXpNYVbOjIRwkWICfb8JBOPp6XdaS@te7qklaG5QbY1BoCaptrfqmibYLpwi14RmUDKW6ARGsG/A@I9K30urYt6X6pnCId/1EDRTFyeVItrG0Du0bKbbmkgaFvADEkoFVAUmBAN6oGymjkgoKWdZBfX@/C/OO5sSFtuKB83BQJdFeWynEJr6Uy/pWQeAln0ufF/nEBRheCmRc8JP0tWlHBUaRmjIkqCnyfR2AhX49OLh0cpSL82uR08Inq3PymD9ZcIFkvhUHYCQEgTWfXG1sO47NoPvx2oh9Ooanq6/19Zp58S/YHjoUzjCbUJq3rZrVZs@6t/St93dFJ6tA59uBbP/nMSM53dOJUv7rSnEfTyKMl3gcJGXhYbuZitEFjwbBNICHBIHAIeJ1OkgSQkhMoImANukKR2a/H0Zdjx3rgAxb02mbn22X52iHzsYaxkiPF329uvsy4aSuIeKnLo0R6NGh8wKUL@ulrebHD@l6bl37Sg/stvx2Py5Zer6f1KqJsKeu6jubwp@mhLG3ltpbZWJwZWMHIMiuUyo8tgHNLYsF4Ns5nxyjGGBB@42fgFxvzOahxyoiLtpFbXqbyo178/hF2o3q6z8d6Zl4c@nRgtoM2tx5LYq9NAyo/0MH9t87W6bf3B5sf4pr@0LvpRFG5ftjbxAIuo5kZe87OhIn/3@70fHKUxmb9Q@7zZx6Tp9pQFL0cKsQ41T11aHSfYrkPwoTsXvAkAfqzif3vvNdbxvN7XfD1t3Hjt0c@H3YQs1BY4seZvrJdy4zinLc78XPh6YVIhHtZwmKB/Gm1UO5vb@xX69dH@w9k9zIA0lMOk/4Gfi5KyOLeMVrAauA/V0ElrORK@V1jImYmzU8wV9nPmQvI7gK@JvSRhsNrGDZpGIJ1jC236AffWh8/VWtFuzt4uNnaMm@2Q2Y1w0bZN4P1zruys3A1/40Ous5Ce5k40MFa66GTO5B7UqQVuZ3PG47ZDi/LLUaekyTTZP3yPDlzpFpYamcq9B2yAC6TNvWKouQ4wPsJnYxkfIdB7CFDZsR9mnhdvlDYhne1dTLxmK9H@tX7Wkom9r3W/RStDOjs3fvuAS/Qj0T7W4LmLonJbhX7QqzgN3UN0gz@SSlEvNMOnGhXknV1a1OKOTDCYmW57cShtbMq5p7d/UWWQJOuS8NF6no7qPKvTipH5LaTArOOC9029tXzqw43mnrXLcCmoPdu4GOKRb3u1kvAN@q11POSRgnbex4NcyNx/MB9sFo0gk7eFCWqHvYlfaTx8v5RuzasgepLsffIzbI@m9O1ijXSrja9xxofhpQxiB2IAtYb5bA/SrzE5ylRvxGXPFCe2QigeJA0/lDT@1KjMgRGoW1@bVCdUWfRigw2B4StsRaxXvJ5LTFL65XFdCWtcfE54bUMWY7Ba6M8Uyj0l9ieQjLN@mvctIzZDBzES8DQSwzMJqLCstElR5r33jjtOjNclFJxigour4E02tvWUeVmMXDGeJRuB@jcmvMhKwlCs4Rq0bxuubKRs72pb65vUuvH0I40lpzUjQnLIhXNg72guocPrcvLqfUvQc@QK3I30gYXnfVjd5iRF/JhdZlZYMkJIPG0TKG7w071@9Gw5gc0MQWfVqbaCkznVr@JBj/RXKcd8ySrVSsCy@mn6@1@behQ96EeBZ02M1/XajXLCSLwJNOA5XHge0x6zShzuZ5NlCLKvE5sGoAfhvroRegh2SyMWNN7UWQtd6e1cdlcZCVV0zRDW7XtGh1p746i42vn/wSvKSsv8No83DzyakOchy3qmVCHMN4e1bOSAhsDUXdQ2PyZiAVAmVEkQb0OiWGIR2evVn999Uo6CMKB2GzpssGl7JRPOvOciEYDqdpJGkEUa6@ki0@HN6UzD0JmzEsnQDnxah4oSaqG1G1waIj1V7@uvrrXTpi9dK/1n57uNdeVtxXrXns/P3TKbBhZXoZx6spkm@DgGbMLB35eTYbZUAOFHXWB3pkXJxxke3pa@ihONDXGayDUpygIoccaKNkpomHhSSG1lwzVsRdCysORSkLICZg21WGdJ2aBLqzURyPFSqLBcBF9meA5KVGBf6o6ioowEW/BxrwENnJp4jZkVxlmp50SHcmKBQo7R1WcO3ukx50HL7mMaDt1rqM2IyYoFKaCZDzKcZRMP1uvXmX4uQI83x92WuFR3@WhEIkro1coDND6UNAwcKW6qZqpFihwnTpUrkYRHShDF5jzKfBtQVkmo2aZ7WptCNXA/RLTGAa3yZCCNARqpnWp3wHaHOrcIbOhKrjXvisy1Y5VVIjYJW5T7XDFtfB3xXI0CCbVJIk8qIe5TESNyb97jKhcAZj9W35nM0ucX8/uyt78kOyqTF0yFDNdkCRgqAJgb@pJJlB5rwCsYlLtQPODunyE59Myaf@FrDiKMhr9oH5Roo/MZtActACx9r3Do8EF9zkegctEqzv3BxL@HhJF/fQ84Ou6g1DHLnjFRwZO8gl@hGLvtQFTPzKVuL7nPsD0jzN22ihsPQKfFE/a8Vc7sGl6U7XbHd9P7wN7OErvDsd3zfHdvoAcgfO25dMG7PCJcORpWmBaVKsqud1r1bEt4UsDGGgqAqR569xpvCYry8vZw40DJjVeh0NW9pSTbdinDS2MgiTANws4oB3WpqhT1N1ZIxUUMC/ZxcfJvTbgMlhLrgE6SpHVp5HZqQJu6d3TE82ZmSCx83XnfMrTlKFjO9pvLjgNiJoqFnAsL49vQTYlV4tr65a7U5zSfN6uJw3LXVlRcEuLc7funZzHF6akU6kdM2G7yE5nekeyUJlu6y0VjN2ljLNpyLG4y8vyM3rDxSD309MYVqhSB88RGKkzj3EfTG3KCNK1SoZibAeTZ@rA4hThoLaQxVQK3ADEet4Qr6lOG8B2j4mcA4mGQSw5b/yM38TNFx36Ix17dNL8IY@Om@DRSbPo0XHzJzx6pKT2U8fTE4BfXZXeBgGkdemk7WqvrMmkPbl9egKPnbxOu1eGKFvPa7OgJ8CsVOK/R02AlC6YesnUK6b@wlTKVYerLlcZVzlXa1x9QMf9zKZ2VVgGpIfM8MFr9B1wo4mLiASFLy4ZeAvbcSwGvuHeMrAA@Mld083S7a0w7y9sxisLqCZRRIPe2OVpeISqV@xorEJoyHAWioU8IYoV4NxMCzsxmHwY@gMZRM1Xj9fSbA51rgr/vGBptL1k9uo/3f7eW1m9L92t3Np3Q10tj35Zta7YAt@VKehmysowaM6YXexGXpjcQgPh8juigD@JZeIZwpdWn0q3YlhAXbL0XTBV9qhJiIgh12wupmfBNMwj9BVkfi13AcVCqWzbvoDkJYOQV2js4WR@rJILhlvzddH2Z2@s80Cbv8pesp09x6R76b55cWoKwC2heEdMxyRInSDim0WIkR485XjTZbbtPD1NXpdD2QBYWg6PJu/Oc3tExN@mytVMmEOacFBwTxax6rdZe8ugdBstm8bJCZ72fazJjqrDgl/ABJZX6xbl9uoOXB247sLVhSuBK4PrG7hyuP7e13W4rcHtLd4v7@ySN3eruFX12dwDm@UouPMRh64ADBW8kIh3kUQZj4FbkmU/KQ45OFSfGnJx6HsnmBpkOPi6sl0c42JMhyFLVIBYZ9Z4blfjpG6VjCVgzMv0QJZJbqULeFVmoXfmoCdSzAHvzgFP5JsFfkPezAIXJZ/D/WYOd0Enc9C4X3MLJgpTJi2CyN58oQFfo7cFPSh0DzOXwggwNYB9D@34ybXHewrWzXSmwk5dHtsTMFZv1mwAOsL6/5qC@WDm5VkKbvIFEQlaLjQ9WNoNoGdGe37gc42fL4bOHNH6iZk@ZkIxjU84k/aEhratGaIvbPEFzWJbDOKSEwd/zx3UVTArg0iBotHOi9u0G7edtHrEJTP1I41DCABf8BBqgYNPEK4W0KWFyYM7v2BJnqz4tbAiq2Vc7vnFRQV@z2mSzhcwKFMyzEBkiK0CpymRmh8E0UtUBMDLZAogz9IRRxYv0REAL9MpgCykI8qJCHcq5AuDqwzmME4ymOKOfC5y8P7gktY/0BaXs4@eaFqhni@sCQpYsPhwpzEd4JEy4oKw@twU4L/V79Lo545LQystGQA9tL02m07ZVd9fXmZzeX1vZkime0QjK5ibFRO6aghOKvmViL4aSD49ie4od8vsEd3jO5/p/6EEgZ6GYS/jiIT3q0iu46/CtCS4CkMeHdAYyhugZ4lObZ7puWIEt8EtNG@zS2RnRXaFGC6KIfoiF/E8o@chxspnFO2K1bB1DBvTvETktq7W4K9u1aEkrN1ZNSgQHduuQ35mHBcCl@yWr6zc2XUs3dLUbvPc4NgkDs8Rz00JK4ZfScp9gX7NBurTdOuamzOsknwXCl/laXHoe4kIhhBv0yd59fd4ZVVRXeXHWcV9jmddA7ofQKqOB8XGg7rnPg6EMVe7dPATQzDsY@y/LSLejQAM24OUgPeaG8eXvJ/YsHdCqmxyLCFOgB6yYfzo8hgikGtGXGvQ@GOvPT6LY8reTFaKONTvILKJ9RMU0US8OSUiPaQD4mCIzC1kuAiLf9sdgWdH3B663PfzI1eCD5/SB6LiQwx9ynjmIn2AmQAn2jAa4GCbqLUIRMpOhYl42BcPRM2OdrNPOYjaov10a0wCt2filqgizZp5tsVXvibBX7zvpbTgJqWF@5B@JknUTsxbNDQJXM9pSFT8FrMOwN0qXomaHiATcUmr9C5fGMxyf4bggP2Sc2vcocUuPYALYHnONHzDDhFPQ8IKHvvdQnGlundWOoVWgZ2N/Cb7gPWNimVAtlBRsV5CjBmC4Rg6/bJ2DC1mU@jURYciAlMZukGwawgPCZe4ALOYzUcZHqzdLDTIZuC1ZQgXI6xLEiw2wPdRArBR8TreHlsy23ML9sjM6WYBzG5qOsMsiYAac@EgilXecTJXQ7/sCHoQNsvKpL1ErXcWhdV8ROLygzIUX8RC68fb7KDh@WwBww/oQBGHBgJd6wPEKFhoPigjDCjQ4bp5L4yN7jD9HBb7XSs9Kb9hck34SJXCzfKyvlMTge4SVc5hKM1E1MRSvLagt6ll@EW/kKFJ6dTtBQGrpuG3LhD@xoJMTVgOiPIA8QiQFVePoZThC2jHq0d1e8kY3WtvqVzfw0MCYMqsqRw6Z7Sc3sJKVJhGnnBVrFlf4dDcidw4zVn41h1aePHicbWP8Wql3/KRXapln3CjHjGt2Q4kxbOglyfFQmuf7l6WJOS0qu5Pczg@9LLwcKPmRXEi7MFSaPYWITWPdPFgcaGNaTKkERBBK9krPkwhoYqZn5M@PqMo2GUKxmLY4lwgtRaEry6E3y6C7VFzpt/AM4Vc7Yhkn8@9bpi8RdAtkENODwlcCD07Nrhy2qtONYiYeifyofGPps6Af/TdR7@5WAM3FI0d@FsD78HQgnpvzhyWP6YHNlTV1ZKhImHxI4C7eIjXhAg3wL7ksTknM@6sb@NbDvElFDaD7rQNTVpDkV7jBucJ5Ld77Su2XubUt/X32hV9bsZxYMZ1cEZcoanDB@Vn3mBU5wUA5TFxoLy2oQ5pkpgUE53pqJ3INzHXqgcvLdpcuMiiO87eflOmK4Yq@O2x4suXL3@BAneFiFcw6nBMaL85f7Zx2MzzHAYEmVwcfDn5dIkZA3q5Qdu1l3S4TTMRfmSw2qRdmp6NEZiY@YcbohOG@A9YYTJo@wHFN3RfmFxtqkI2bIvTOfEPGdLJg6nJifDrC4RHmJEiWhiZvDuqHhIs26fSgwsBTj36OTM8yoxQbONxE/g6BguIGeBRjU2wbjwQh/u3TRDOlt@mEMdiFUAoaHD9JoynYUN911RPAO7dNFw5h3uXw71vFns@2FIDMyRszEm2MTTbmLOTD6cE3@RNn0KkxU66NVBYktSNYHtPmuqUQ1iFs4@XzzNe1C0Vr0XkmWNcZDJh6QsaCF1A3thSlPdNOUucOW0MFQYeVuhWen6@4A0x2gxRCwQySOD20mvxoJPI75t47AKcKPL/wqE/WJNAVBSqLgA0BlX28nLhQc5gYc3OauoG2ees899ipdOS0Ct@V1o5v@hfGe2Vr87Xs1O6cdAIqz3bJrtFunmI9/C9TkbX8yJ8BQHSgQpOWrTO44vIlW@9O3UCAU/A1eQZi0PB6RSb2Tdp@GXzoUfBx7KPEYWri08gsDEh4vHeY/f42anXNzOopufFNumEU4vS0PBnOEsR/97xIvzmcQb5@AO7gTSYfLC26gRsABfxD88IIf8N)
The input is only a small portion of the entire google page, since the TIO-link would become over 30,000 characters long with the entire page.. :/ To test any google search page with this part of the program, follow these steps:

1. Ctrl+U (Show page source)
2. Copy-paste everything into the second TIO's input-field
3. Surround it with leading and trailing `"""` (for multi-line string inputs)

**Explanation:**

```python
’Š¹.ŒŒ/€±?q=ÿ’    # Push dictionary string "google.com/search?q=ÿ"
                  # where the `ÿ` is automatically filled with the (implicit) input
  žZ              # Push builtin string "http://www."
    ì             # Prepend it in front of the string
     .w           # Go to this URL, and get its page as string
       ”€«”       # Push titlecased dictionary string "About"
           ¡      # Split the google page on that titlecased word
            1è    # Only leave the second part (0-based 1st)
              #   # Split that on spaces
               1è # And index into the second part (0-based 1st) to get the amount
                  # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tips (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `’Š¹.ŒŒ/€±?q=ÿ’` is `"google.com/search?q=ÿ"` and `”€«”` is `"About"`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/sEeNLxeq seems to have expired already.

Comment: @Anush yeah, I noticed that just yet as well. Seems like a pastebin admin/bot removed it.. The TIO url is about 350,000 characters long rofl.. :/ I'll change it to a manual explanation on how to get the Google's content and copy it into the program.

Comment: @Anush I've added a portion of the Google's page in the TIO now, and also added some instructions on how to test the entire page.

Comment: Have you tested this locally? Without prepending `www.` to the URL I get a 301 response that looks like [this](https://tio.run/##TY/BjoJAEETvfMWk7zAaL5u1Zwwb2bCJZpMNF49kaG0Th0FoZP16BfXgsboq/aqaq3CoFzcAuGFebDcW8yxdW/QkpWKRJqZzf7wYcKEWqiWWa0OgXsqA0L9oFn9aOi7bjsT0so8/wEZY/BSbzC5mc7UNF6pQPw@on4Sv3/VuTOXz98ioooJJVcH1fgQoLjvlJy/CVOV/2beBqdWn1sMwJIcQDidKXPC6o7J1vDqb/bFjsEwtoU5tEqF@kMbf07zH0js) and the program prints `http-equiv="content-type"`. ( With `www.` I get the mobile German site, but I guess that is client-dependent ;) )

Comment: @ovs Maybe the `.w` command automatically follows 301 redirects? (`wget` follows them by default, for instance.)

Comment: @Arnauld At least not on my system (what I linked above is the ouput of `.w`)

Comment: @ovs Oh, no I hadn't tested this one locally tbh. I remember trying a google search locally once before [in this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205254/52210), but due to the size of the google page, it was a bit too slow. I'm currently on my desktop instead of laptop where I have 05AB1E installed, so I will try this challenge locally upcoming Monday, and possibly add the `www.` if necessary (if it will be able to pull the entire page content this time).

Comment: @ovs Can you confirm it works with the `www.`? If so, I'll add it for now to make it valid.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It does loads search results, but for some reason I got a mobile version which doesn't have the number of results at all. I will try to get the desktop page later. And if you don't specify `lang=en` the language depends on your location, but I guess `05AB1E in an English speaking country` is a language by our definition ;).

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you need to pass an explicit `user-agent` so that Google doesn't return the mobile page (cc @ovs).

Comment: I'm not sure "About" is guaranteed to work given the arbitrary A-Za-z strings that can appear, maybe ">About", "About " or ">About " is?